# What to do with a user making many minor changes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

There is a user who is making minor, aesthetic changes to titles e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4628693
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4628661

I have rejected a couple but he/she doesn't get the hint. Is rejecting the correct approach? And if so how should we notify the editor to stop?

Comment: _Improve_ the changes.

Comment: The first one was super awesome tag removal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rejecting minor edits is the correct approach.

A user making too many suggested edits that are rejected receives an automatic ban and will be invited to review their suggested edits and why they have been rejected.

Note that editing just the title is fine if there are no other (obvious) improvements to be made. If the edit leaves the post body riddled with grammar or spelling mistakes or terrible formatting, reject the edit. If the post body is otherwise fine and the edit improves the title, by all means accept the edit!

Comment: Out of curiosity the majority of *"minor edits"* edits in that [user's activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2842136/alexender?tab=activity) are actually getting through - isn't that indicative of a review system that isn't working?

Comment: @Emissary: The review system for suggested edits is, indeed, somewhat broken. Moderators were given better tools recently to battle some of that brokeness by handing out manual review bans with direct feedback.

Comment: Yes, the review system for suggested edits is [broken](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/bob-malooga?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @devnull: if you find a pattern of edits that should obviously have been rejected, flag an accepted edit, explain your case in the 'other' box and ask a moderator to review. Review bans and suggested edit bans can be applied manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I raised a flag about this 6 days back.  It's _waiting for review_.  (Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied)

Comment: @devnull: Well, the flag queue *is* long and larger tasks like these may sit on the backburner for longer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do I raise a flag for a pattern of edits that should have been rejected..  per this post and my own at [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295308/user-is-making-repeated-trivial-edits-that-dont-fix-all-changes/295311#295311) a user is continuing to have trivial edits approved that folks on meta seem to think shouldn't be.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: still the same way, you flag a post. We'll do our best to handle flags, but there is a big pile of them. We process about 2k flags every 24 hours.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks. just checking, didn't want to add to that pile the wrong way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In line with your answer here, what do you think of this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258610/230506? I'm not expecting you to just agree, it would just be nice to have some feedback from someone who thinks with the same logic my proposal was made with - as far as I can see anyway :).

Comment: @James: I agree with the current answer; there is a grey area here between being too minor and having missed one more thing they could have edited. There are plenty of helpful good edits that would be rejected if your proposal was implemented just because the reviewer saw something else to add.

Comment: @James: that's what the *Improve* option is for; if the reviewer feels something was still missing they can do that right there.

Comment: I do agree, although specifically when there are only a "couple" of missed improvements. People are rejecting because suggested edits are barely scratching the surface of all the potential improvements that could have been made. And your answer advocates that "*Rejecting minor edits is the correct approach.*" and I agree with it. So, why not a more sensible reject reason to educate users? Or do you think as long as the edit was ok, even if missed a lot of potential, we should always use "Improve"? Maybe that's where we disagree?

Comment: @James: no, for a minor edit there is the 'no improvement' option. For a 'medium' edit (one that is helpful but missed something) there is the *Improve* option.

Comment: Ok, but that is my point. The "no improvement" is not accurate, as often their edits were improvements, they just missed a load of other potential improvements as well. Telling users in such cases "your edit is wrong" is not educating them correctly. They should be told "check and do more next time".

Comment: Anyway, didn't want to hijack your post here really. I put all this in the proposal. Seems people  disagree with it anyway. Thanks for the feedback.