# "Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have seen a few posts recently on this meta site that make me wonder about "minor edits":

- [Review ban because of approving burninate tag edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253293/review-ban-because-of-approving-burninate-tag-edits)
- [What is wrong with minor edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits)
- [When an edit only fixes a typo, what should I do as a reviewer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253123/when-an-edit-only-fixes-a-typo-what-should-i-do-as-a-reviewer)

I have read the questions and answers from the above links, and they leave me confused.

The TLDR seems to be that "we" prefer incorrect grammar and wrong spelling, to correct grammar, and good spelling. But that doesn't make sense, and it sounds a bit cynical, so I must be missing an important point.

It seems it is better to have poor quality English on our site. I can only imagine this has something to do with being worried about the "rep-whores" that are commonly talked about on meta.

I have two concerns:

- Is this an issue that we just don't want to give reputation points to someone who improves the quality of the site, but only by a little? So he was helpful, but we believe he should have been more helpful. In which case, then I see why we don't approve edit reviews - we just don't want people to score points.
- If the above is somewhat close to the reason, then is it OK if I correct grammar, spelling, formatting, etc.? Given that I no longer get reputation points for improving posts - does that make it OK to try and add value in that way?

With the new high profile given to the meta site recently, I've started paying more attention to what the experts here think, and I've realise I routinely break a lot of the rules without realising it. So I'm interested in the motivation behind some of the rules I disagree with.

---

### Update

My impression based on this thread, and many others, is that the major costs of a smaller edit are the amount of time it takes for the review queue to be attended to, and the fact of bumping the question up on the home page.

It seems there are some high reputation users on this site who prefer titles to be useful, or who prefer syntax highlighting in the code, or who like tags to be corrected. In some cases, edits of this nature will be dismissed as "too minor" when done by users without enough reputation. However, they will be seen as positive when done by us, the trusted users.

It also appears that the highest voted answer below agrees with these sentiments - so maybe the community as a whole thinks this way (I have accepted is for that reason).

Are these reasonable conclusions to have reached?

Comment: Completely agree. If SO is intended to be a top-quality Q&A site, then we should allow people to correct grammar and spelling mistakes. We don't have to be obsessive about it, but if someone is willing to spend the time for that kind of edit, why not let them?

Comment: @PaulDraper: [Servy points out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253330/4279) several issues with minor edits for grammar.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, and [I point out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/253512#253512) why those issues are not significant, when weighed against the benefits.

Comment: Sometimes a tiny typo makes a huge difference. I wish I never made tiny hypos.

Comment: Even minor formatting changes can raise the "edit too minor" flag (or at least it used to).  Adding the markdown for inline code is just 2 characters, and many times I've found myself at a loss as to how else I could improve the content I was editing.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit without approval, but I also don't like seeing tags and questions that have rampant issues with grammar or spelling - they make the site look bad and make questions harder to answer. Personally I could care less about the rep gained from such edits... perhaps an option could be added to disallow distribution of rep for minor edits? Alternatively, could there be a method of flagging a page as 'needing improvement' so qualified editors can have a look?

Comment: When I "disapprove" an edit as too minor, it's almost invariably because the user is changing the intent of the question.   "Too minor" becomes politer shorthand for "edit is too small, sloppy, and egocentric."   I _always_ let pure grammatical corrections through.

Comment: SO is not used strictly by native English speakers.  Idiosyncrasies in grammar, explanations will be a constant regardless of how much we edit. The only time they _need_ to be edited is when they create ambiguity in the question or answer. If there is no ambiguity, there is no need to change it.

Comment: Typos need to be corrected if not doing so means that the page might not get properly indexed by Google -- I also quickly fix a typo, particularly in the title, if I see it, but I don't go out of my way to hunt them down

Comment: @MitchGoshorn SO is also a tool for teaching, so why not also use it to help teach proper spelling and grammar?

Comment: I believe in minor edits because they contribute to the aggregation of marginal gains. If every edit just improves things by 1%, over time this adds up.

Comment: @Nate I was thinking the same thing.  I would like to add: How about lowering the threshold for edits to be approved for users who forfeit those coveted two points?

Comment: If there are only "minor edits" to be done, then the question is hardly "poor quality", is it? If it is poor quality, then it should be possible to make major improvements to it.

Comment: There's also the issue of formatting changes requiring 5-6 characters added to the post.  If I go through and reformat a code snippet to make it readable, I have to change something else just to put the edit through....irritating

Comment: I think the policy changed as well? While I noticed minor edits have been discouraged in the past, this message is gone. I really do like this. And if I have a look at the review queue (Especially late/first answers) we dont have a problem with reviewing stuff like that, it only might require to lower the reputation requirements for peer review.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147946/is-correcting-a-common-misspelling-too-minor-an-edit) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/why-can-suggested-edits-be-too-minor).

Comment: While removing spelling/grammar mistakes makes the posts unarguably better (by some metric) it is a little harsh to say that when we leave them in, the question/answer is "poor quality". I see a quite some of such edits, that also unnecessarily change formulation or other small totally unrelated things to make it appear "better" in the eyes of the editor without really fixing grammar/spelling; I would rather like to see the effort spent on posts that sound like coming from google translate rather than a philosophical fight over "whence" is a proper word in such and such context.

Comment: What if minor edits were not worth any points, but yet available ? Wouldn't it limit rep-linked abuses while enabling slight improvements ?

Comment: `If there is no ambiguity, there is no need to change it.`- very much an opinion.  Grammar is, on the whole, right or wrong.  There is every reason to change bad spelling/ grammar, especially as it should help non-native speakers.

Comment: I think worse than wrong spelling are code examples with small errors (e.g. returning int instead of int[]). That can really trip someone up and cause the answer to be hard to understand.

Comment: FYI: After reading this I went from Deny to Accept on http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7398900 ... but not sure if that was right though. Seems like the edit was not really necessary at all. I even disagree with the addition of "a" in "a dataurl format".

Comment: I once attempted to correct a user's typo from 'Kock-out' to 'Knock-out'. Wouldnt let me. Was most unfortunate.

Comment: I've been annoyed when a few of my questions have had minor edits done to them, simply to americanise (notice the S not Z in ise) my otherwise completely valid spelling.

Comment: @PaulDraper It is just annoying when a whole edit on your post literally just adds a missing dot after "etc", especially when your questions will become community wiki because of 5 (or most of the) edits are from these types. How will 5 little typo fix become such a community effort that you shouldn't get rep from it?

Comment: @totymedli, well that points to a different problem: community wiki posts. Minor edits or not, that system doesn't make much sense. But that's a whole different topic that I won't cover here.

Comment: @PaulDraper TIL that this rule doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: why not make a "typo edit queue" where edits like this handled. and to avoid point collectors there can be a lower point rate to avoid a abuse of the point system

Comment: I agree with this wholeheartedly, I often find questions or answers where the code isn't properly formatted but I can't fix it because it's "too minor" when in reality it greatly improves the readability of the post

Answer (score 406, accepted):

**Minor edits can be good**

1. SO is intended to be a top-quality Q&A site, meant not just for the OP, but for posterity. Thanks to search engines, questions and answers become authoritative for the whole Internet.
2. Spelling and grammar mistakes, even small ones, make posts more difficult to read, and negatively reflect on their quality as a whole.
3. SO has a very large community, who read and re-read many questions multiple times a day.
4. There is [no shortage](https://stackoverflow.com/review) of reviewers for suggested edits. (Close Votes on the other hand...)

Together, these reasons are compelling for allowing edits, even small ones.

---

**Rejection of @Servy's reasons (which are common objections)**

1. "It consumes a lot of reviewer time." First, the edit queue is short or non-existant. Second, if you wanted, "minor edits" (using our current criteria) could require only one reviewer. They are easy to understand, easy to check, and almost any reviewer can determine their correctness.
2. "It locks the post from editing until the post is reviewed, inhibiting the ability of other users to make more substantial edits." True, though I have *never* encountered this with any edit. Probably because the edit queue most often hovers between five and *zero*.
3. "It draws reviewer time away from other suggested edits, causing them to lock up the posts for longer, and prevent other more substantial edits from being applied sooner." This seems like a repetition of #1 and #2, smashed together.
4. "It bumps the post on the front page, drawing attention to it and consuming the time of readers without much benefit." I'm not sure what "without much benefit" means. If you want to look at new questions (not questions that have been edited recently), look at Unanswered newest.

Addtionally, there seems to be a common logical fallacy that someone who can't correct a single spelling mistake turns to other, more significant edits. I don't think this happens: "Oh, I can't edit the typo in this question I'm reading...I should interrupt what I'm doing and instead go search SO for a worse question."

---

We should allow people to correct grammar and spelling mistakes. We don't have to be obsessive about it, but if someone is willing to spend the time for that kind of edit, let them.

Comment: I agree, any edit which leaves the post in a superior state should be welcomed.  The standard of quality must be high to encourage everyone to contribute their best.  Worth noting that we very much do not have a shortage of suggested edit reviewers.

Comment: No way - a trivially superior state is not excuse for the time wasted in the review queue, the reputation-leaching habits encouraged, and most especially **the unwarranted attention of bumping often pointless questions to the top of the page**.

Comment: You are correct to point out the logical fallacy. If I see a minor error on SE, I will usually just leave it. If I see a minor error on Wikipedia and I have time, I'll often fix it. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Unnecessary bumping and accidental rep-farming can be trivially avoided using a ‘minor edit’ checkbox that prevents the edit from bumping and discredits the +2 rep. As Paul Draper points out, minor edits take less time per review to process, and reviewer time of minor edits could be further reduced by requiring fewer reviews per minor edit. Reviewer time is the only real issue here, but this has to be weighed up against the editor time that is being pushed away from the network.

Comment: @JamesHaigh, true, though I feel the only important part here is the reviewer time. Editor time is IMO not as "transferrable".

Comment: I've never seen the "minor edit" checkbox and will make a point to look for it, however I expect that a lot of these near pointless edits are coming from those who see that, rather than meaningful contribution of solutions, as their path towards gaining reputation and so would be unwilling to use it.  Perhaps approval-required edits should only gain points if a majority of the approving reviewers vote that they should.

Comment: I disagree with #1.  For a computer to automatically determine, reliably, which edits are minor is very, very difficult.  Number of characters changed/deleted/inserted is a very poor metric for significance of changes.  And trusting the low-reputation user to correctly flag minor edits isn't much better.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I 100% agree, and yet we have such a "very poor metric" **right now** used for disallowing edits. I would actually like to get rid of that metric altogether.

Comment: Ahh, maybe giving the "edit is minor" checkbox to the reviewers instead of the editor would be better.  That's rather like Kate's method using "improve, uncheck suggestion was useful", but saves some steps and can be considered in attribution of the edit.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Not “the”, “a” – _a_ ‘minor edit’ checkbox like that of Wikipedia that doesn't currently exist on this site but should. Those who would be unwilling to use it would face more reviewers, but the first reviewer could mark it as minor and this would do two things: reduce the number of further needed reviewers; and remove the incentive for deliberately not flagging the minor edit as minor.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Just seen your comment. What do you think to my suggestion which first gives the option to the suggester, but the reviewer can also check the checkbox, and resultantly reduce the number of reviewers needed as if the suggester had checked it correctly in the the first place?

Comment: @JamesHaigh: That seems good.  Maybe also a slight penalty to the editor if they fail to use that box when they should have.  I'm thinking not directly negative rep, but count against their rep-from-edit cap for the day.  That way it will only affect lazy rep-farmers who are betting on roboreviewers to boost them.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: A slight penalty did cross my mind at first, but I didn't want to punish the occasional accident, then I realised that the penalty isn't necessary to make sure that minor edits are flagged without wasting reviewer time because minor edits still need at least one reviewer and the first reviewer could correct the flag. Your suggestion does make sense though because it targets those editors who are more likely to be deliberately incorrectly flagging edits at high volume to rep-farm, rather than the new user who suggested a correct minor edit but forgot to tick the box.

Comment: I agree with this answer. To elaborate a bit on one aspect, I think requiring higher privilege users to spend more time trying to fix everything in a post is actually detrimental. Telling users that "minor edits" are not allowed means that more often, the post is simply not fixed, rather than someone spending the time to fix everything. Some posts are so bad that it is too time consuming to fix everything all in one swoop, and so people just reject the edit instead. And if I'm required to spend that much time on fixing a post, I'm not spending it in other areas (like possibly the close queue).

Comment: This "minor edit" checkbox idea is sounding better and better to me the more I think about it...

Comment: Elaboration on #4: A grammar edit bumping the question a bit actually does have benefits.  For example, if I can barely decipher what a question is asking due to bad English or a poor question title, I'll probably just skip it and not bother trying to translate what the OP wants *and* solve the problem.  If those mistakes in the question's delivery are fixed, more people might take the time to really look at and answer the question.

Comment: @JeffGohlke: On the other hand, not bumping the question is a "soft" penalty for the OP, which may encourage them to pay more attention to spelling and grammar next time if they wish a speedier answer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. True.  I guess my use-case has more to do with non-native English speakers (people who don't have the skill set or capacity to really write with perfect grammar) rather than your random college kid who is just too lazy to do it, haha.

Comment: This answer completely fails to take into account that for many users, having their answer edited for what seems like no serious reason feels unwelcoming or intrusive. People don't want to be corrected unless it's actually a correction *worth making*. And SO needs to be welcoming to people if it is to survive. It has to make not just reviewers and editors happy, but also those who actually write questions and answers.

Comment: To all those who are suggesting a minor edit checkbox / review option for reviewers: Yes! That is exactly what we need. If a reviewer selects "minor edit," the edit goes through but the editor doesn't get a +2, which is really only "deserved" for a more substantive edit.

Comment: The review queue is probably small because we reject minor edits, sending the message that they are not welcome. If we accepted all edits, it would encourage more and more and the snowball effect could be quite dramatic.

Comment: @JamesHaigh, the comparison you make to wikipedia is interesting, but it's a bit deceptive. Something no one has discussed so far is the issue that unlike on wikipedia, our names are prominently attached to our questions and answers. The reason it feels so easy to make an edit to a wikipedia page is that the page itself isn't attributed to anyone. But here, our names are linked to our words, and so they feel more like our own "turf." When someone steps on that turf, we notice it, and when we want to step on someone else's turf, we think twice. That's part of the mechanism of the site.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think we can ENTIRELY discount the benefit of that "soft" penalty. I don't think you'll disagree with me if I say that less than 10% of askers who require a minor edit will notice if their question gets bumped or not. And regardless I don't consider the bumping an issue either way -- there are PLENTY of ways to filter your search for new questions.

Comment: @jalf I think the very nature of StackOverflow discourages an attitude of "personal turf". If you feel an edit to your post changes it too much, you simply revert the edit. (I've encountered that situation myself.) StackOverflow allows editing other people's answers because we want everyone to contribute to the quality of the site, and a sense of "personal turf" actively hinders the ability to contribute. We want new users to lose that way of thinking, and if they can't, then StackOverflow probably isn't for them. Last, StackOverflow is plenty welcoming; I see no shortage of people.

Comment: Might be worth noting that often, or at least in my case, edits are done on questions that are already *on* the front page, so a "bump" is irrelevant.

Comment: After a couple months of thought, I think a "minor edit" checkbox is a bad idea. The main legitimate argument against minor edits seems to be that the active lists get cluttered; instead of rejecting good changes to the site, that problem should be actively fixed so that minor edits don't pose a problem. However, this isn't something a reviewer or editor should have to think about. The system should automatically decide whether to bump based on heuristics. Certain kinds of changes or certain sizes of changes should cause a bump.

Comment: If someone as the time to hunt down every grammar and spelling mistakes in questions/answers, they have time to correct the other things that needs to be corrected. Asking reviewer to improve all those edits that are missing a few things left and right is not the good solution. If you can't edit as much as possible in a question/answer, don't edit it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's a strawman. We're not talking about edits that "hunt down every grammar and spelling mistake". We're talking about people who notice one or two things wrong while reading and suggest a quick edit that changes one or two things. People with enough rep can just do the edit. Why are we ignoring the useful resource of people who are reading questions and answers? Instead of discarding useful corrections by people actually using the site, why not actually fix the other problems imposed by the reputation or active lists?

Comment: As much as saying that there are "quick" edits. Taking the time to click edit, find and correct the mistakes in the edit text field and writing a summary isn't quick. Why leave the rest of the improvements into the hands of the next person or the reviewer?

Comment: Typo "hole", please edit. :) Was that a pun?

Comment: @Nemo, won't fix; too minor ;)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It is much quicker to spend 2 minutes fixing one or two grammatical or tagging problems you noticed while reading than it is to spend 20 minutes evaluating every portion of the post.

Comment: @jpmc26 Indeed it is and it then leave the burden of fixing the rest to others which I'm don't find useful. It wastes more people time and it should not be needed by reviewers to have to take time to improve the edit even further.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Right, because everyone always has infinite time to spend on StackExchange. Silly me for thinking people might have obligations that prevent them from spending that kind of time every time they see a grammatical error or tag problem. Your argument is invalid. No one is required to spend that kind of time here, and it makes no sense to reject small improvements just because bigger improvements are needed. There is just no legitimate argue in favor of doing that. It's fine to make a small contribution; not every contribution has to be huge.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're missing the point totally.

Comment: Another reason to fix typos is that they can cost non-native English speakers a _lot_ of time.  A typo doesn't hold me up very often, because I already know that "liek" means "like" and "rite" is probably "right".  Someone who occasionally has to look up words or phrases will be slowed by the first one and badly held up by the second, where the typo is _also_ an English word.  That's before you count all the words that are regularly misused even by native English speakers: lie/lay, affect/effect, which/that, to/too/two, compose/comprise, in/into, tenet/tenant, and so on.

Comment: lets open a `typo edit queue`

Comment: I see "clogging up the front page" as the most, or one of the most important concerns regarding minor edits. Is it intractably difficult to limit the number of "bumped" questions on the front page and reserve a certain fraction of slots for new questions?  Aside: I'm not sure I've ever looked at the front page of SO or any SE for more than five minutes total. I navigate by 1. Google and 2. Related questions (I have hot network questions blocked for productivity reasons). If there needs to be a simple "New" tab, then create it.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2022, and the "edit queue most often hovers between five and zero" is no nearly as true as it (maybe) used to be in 2014. These days the queue sits around the increased 500 threshold *every day*, in no small way "thanks" to all those minor edits that supposedly do not cause any disruption to how the site operates.

Answer (score 81):

Personally, I only use the 'too minor' rejection reason as a euphemism for *"I'm not actually convinced that this is an improvement"* or *"Some of your changes make this post better, some make it worse, and I don't care enough to unpick them because none of them matters very much."* Since fairly early in my reviewing days, I've never rejected a genuinely good but minor edit for being too minor.

I've never understood what the purpose of doing so is (or even what edits qualify; there's a total lack of discussion, as far as I've been able to discover, on where the threshold is), and what other reviewers do is totally inconsistent. I've seen major rewrites of broken English into something comprehensible, or code formatting changes needed to make the post remotely readable, both rejected as 'too minor', and had to go and reimplement these changes myself because they were vital if the post was to be salvaged into something useful to anybody. I've also seen suggestions that did nothing but change a word for a synonym accepted. If the plan is to impose a standard threshold of minor-ness at which things get rejected, then on the whole we're just utterly failing.

Additionally, while I realise that minor edits causing post-bumping is a genuine issue, I'm utterly taken aback by the assertion from [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253330/1709587) and [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253329/1709587) that rejecting minor edits is supposed to *save reviewers time*. Frankly, I think it does precisely the opposite. I assumed that the rejection of minor edits was just supposed to ensure that the ease of gaining rep via minor edits didn't end up disincentivizing people from making more substantial edits.

Reviewing a substantial edit - that heavily rewrites a piece of prose, or makes a non-trivial code change - usually takes me at least a minute or two, and requires me to read and understand the entire post being edited. For edits complicated enough that I have to do research to determine the edit's correctness, it's roughly as much of an investment of effort as making the change myself would be. On the other hand, reviewing a bunch of typo fixes can literally be done in 5 to 10 seconds, and - unlike more serious edits - the time cost doesn't scale with the length or complexity of the post being edited.

The *only* thing that used to cost me time when reviewing minor edits - before I gave up on rejecting them - was trying to figure out whether they were 'too minor' or not. As soon as I have to answer that, suddenly I need to think. Does this grammar fix significantly affect readability? Was this typo going to leave people unsure about what was meant? Or are these changes frivolous? I once again need to understand some context, and besides passing judgement on whether the edit is *good* I've got this whole extra layer of judgement I'm supposed to make - with pretty much zero guidance on where the thresholds are - on whether it's done *enough* good, or just a little bit of good. That's a much more demanding call than just going "yep, the grammar was wrong and now it's right. Accept."

And for what? For starters, it seems to me that Kate Gregory and others who reject these edits will never succeed at reducing them by even half of what they are today, even if everybody tries to support them in it. These suggested edits come from low-rep (i.e. relatively new) users, and therefore churn is built into the system - there will always be *new* new users to replace the old new users, and unlike closed questions, rejected suggestions are pretty much invisible to anybody except the suggester and reviewers, so your efforts won't set an example to the next generation. You can't build long-lasting behaviour changes with suggested edit reviews - you can at most hope to influence the user who made the suggestion, and often not even them.

And if the rejecters *did* succeed at making such a drastic reduction? Like Kate, I can only speak for myself, but I'm pretty certain that even if I got the experience to be much quicker at it than I am today, seriously weighing up whether something was 'too minor' would still take several times as long as determining the correctness of a handful of spelling or grammar changes does. At least in my case, you'd need to reduce the number of minor edits by an implausibly large factor before the time it would take me to review them as you'd like me to would be *less* than the time it takes to just check they're correct and click them through. Perhaps others have had a drastically different experience to me, but early on when I was reviewing figuring out whether edits - perfectly valid, correct edits that made posts better - should be rejected as 'too minor' or not was sucking up a large proportion of my reviewing time, and was the most un-fun part of the entire process. Accepting them wastes drastically less of my time and doesn't cause me the same level of stress and doubt.

As a final aside, I find bad English in posts distracting, even if there are only a few instances of it and it's possible to piece together the meaning without much effort. As such, I don't find edits that fix it close-to-worthless as others here seem to.

Comment: Apart from the word 'only', I agree with the first paragraph; I sometimes use 'too minor' to mean 'subjective; not good enough to be accepted unconditionally; not bad enough to be rejected as invalid'.

Comment: It's not the edits being rejected that save reviewer time, it's the disincentive that rejection sets for submitting similar minimal changes to the review queue in the future, that saves reviewer time.

Comment: I also "find bad English in posts distracting" and slower to read and get through. Correct English (US or UK) is just easier to get into my head. That's the root of my question, and why I too find the official reasons hard to reconcile.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand that that is Servy and Kate's intent. My objection is that approving correct but minor edits without regard to how minor they are takes so little time, and having to think about whether they're "minor" takes so much, and the potential proportion of minor edits that we can eliminate by changing the incentives is so small and impermanent, that I don't think it's plausible for rejecting minor edits to save time *on net*.

Comment: @MarkAmery I just overhauled a poorly constructed answer, today, that was "rejected" - the answer remains poorly written and nearly incomprehensible. It is certainly frustrating when that happens. Amen to your post.

Comment: @Thomas hmm, [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4744069) looks like the only one that you could be describing? The reviewers may simply have thought that the original was more clear than your revised version. I've never touched C++ and am not very familiar with its import mechanism, so there may be subtleties that are going over my head that justify the change, but to my naive eyes the original version looks easier to understand. I'm a native English speaker, but just parsing that many-claused sentence you've crafted made my brow furrow in concentration a little.

Comment: @MarkAmery hmmm... No, that one I wasn't to concerned about (forgot I even made the edit). That might mean the other one I posted failed to post - what a relief!

Comment: A couple of years ago, the SO suggested edit review queue was severely understaffed; saving reviewers' time was important. This has changed (probably by moving the rep threshold for the review queue from 10k down to 2k), and I now use “too minor” pretty much in the same way as you.

Answer (score 56):

I ran into a problem where the 6 character limit stopped me from making a code error change.  The OP had something like `uid` in parts of his code, but `id` in another.  I reread it for 5 minutes until I realized he meant `uid`  The post was a year old so there wasn't a point of making a comment, but I just wanted to add that `u` in there - though I didn't want to add fluff in order to make that change.  I wound up doing nothing because it wouldn't let me add one character (however important that was to the question).

Comment: I totally agree. Similar issue is that white chars are not considered as change. So you may spend ten minutes fixing formatting and when you press Save - you see error, that your edit is too short! Very frustrating.

Comment: This is the real big issue, I think. Typos in code, even when it's only 1 character, are extremely meaningful, and can end up wasting a lot of time because readers don't understand the question properly, and answers might address this incorrectly. Requiring additional characters just to fix one fatal typo is unnecessary and harmful.

Comment: For this reason alone, this limitation should have never been implemented.  I had an instance where someone was discussing a variable and typed the wrong one which totally confused everything, but I ended up just leaving it because it wouldn't allow me to make the fix.

Comment: add a comment to the code as well? The limit is sensible, as it prevents people hitting edit, adding a space, or changing a comma for a semi-colon in text, then getting credit for editing something.

Comment: I may have found a way around this.  I just edited someone's code for formatting.  I bet if you unformat/reformat it would register as more than 6 characters.

Comment: But in this particular case that you are describing - could it have been that this error you were trying to correct was the actual root problem of the question? If so editing would only make it harder to answer. As to the character limit and the need to edit minor things sometimes I agree. But I would be carefull in editing falsy code.

Comment: Good point, but in that case no - the error was unrelated to the question (I think something like how to run a particular type of query).

Comment: You can always add a HTML comment...

Answer (score 54):

I am just throwing this out there for a more 'visual' reference.

[Stack Overflow
[image: StackOverflow Edit Queue]](https://stackoverflow.com/review)

[Super User
[image: SuperUser Edit Queue]](https://superuser.com/review)

[Programmers
[image: Programmers Edit Queue]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review)

[Server Fault
[image: ServerFault Edit Queue]](https://serverfault.com/review)

The argument that it's [taking up reviewers' time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253330/510036) is **completely ridiculous**.

Comment: Seems a lot of us lower rep users are taking this argument - I think this is a great graphic to back it up.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier A couple of years ago, the SO suggested edit review queue was severely understaffed; saving reviewers' time was important. This has changed (probably by moving the rep threshold for the review queue from 10k down to 2k). This argument isn't intrinsically ridiculous, but it is no longer applicable. (This argument is too minor; opposition should be substantive objections addressing multiple issues in the suggestion.)

Comment: Suppose those queues where being emptied by AIs who could determine, at a glance, if a review was an audit, and pass them.  They otherwise approved everything.  They reviewed an edit every second, collectively.  Their edit reviews would, however, be without value.  What is the rate at which "bad edits" get through the queue?  Are good reviewers (who are good at catching "bad edits") discouraged by reviewing pointless edit requests?  What is a "bad edit"?  Are people trying to game the queue (approval takes far less time than disapproval) for badges a decent approximation of such a bot?

Answer (score 29):

As a new user, I enjoy the freedom to suggest "minor" edits. Why? Because at this juncture, I am seen as exactly that: a know-nothing, new user not to be taken seriously (despite my experience programming which is not reflected via Stack Overflow in any concrete way). Also, I full-heartedly agree that garbage grammar and syntax makes the site less reputable (**as does bad code syntax**) and for this reason minor edits are to lauded as ensuring Stack Overflow remains a top-quality, reliable source.

Perhaps this is the advantage of being relatively new: we are able and willing to go through an cleanup the trash, flag things, and wager an answer or comment here and there. And who hasn't read an academic journal, recently? Minor edits are what make the academic world go round. In the good ol' days of good writing, *nothing* was published unless walking through a gauntlet of stark criteria, also known as accountable peer review.

I think it is indeed silly that a person can reject revisions because they are believed to be too minor.

Comment: New users aren't necessarily assumed to know nothing. If you know something, the best way to show that is to spend time writing solid answers or posing thoughtful questions. Really good answers get voted up for *years* and will get you much more reputation much faster than spending time on piddly little 2 point edits. Also, as a new user you're not really free to make minor edits, you're only welcome to suggest edits that someone else has to approve.

Comment: @Caleb I know. I was just being dramatic for the sake of drama. However, your point is well made.

Comment: @Caleb nowadays I almost never need to actually ask something on SO because it's 99% has been asked before and answered (maybe not in one question, but reading several questions usually does the trick).

Answer (score 18):

> Is this an issue that we just don't want to give rep to someone who improves the quality of the site, but only by a little?

Not really.  Maybe just a touch, but it's pretty far down on the list of problems with too minor edits.  Here are some much more important issues:

1. It consumes **a lot** of reviewer time. Time that could be better spent doing other things, like fixing the spelling grammar of other posts.  (Imagine how many of these minor edits could be done in the time the 3-5 reviewers spend reviewing that edit.)
2. It locks the post from editing until the post is reviewed, inhibiting the ability of other users to make more substantial edits.
3. It draws reviewer time away from other suggested edits, causing *them* to lock up the posts for longer, and prevent other more substantial edits from being applied sooner.
4. It bumps the post on the front page, drawing attention to it and consuming the time of readers without much benefit.

The biggest problem with users getting rep with very minor edits is that it encourages them to make more of them, thus causing the above problems to happen over and over.  When the users don't get their edits approved, they either learn not to make these edits, thus not causing those problems, or they get edit banned, thus being unable to cause those problems.

> If the above is somewhat close to the reason, then is it OK if I correct grammar, spelling, formatting etc? Given that I no longer get rep for improving posts - does that make it OK to try and add value in that way?

It reduces the harm.  1, 2, and 3 don't apply.  #4 does, but that's still pretty significantly reduced the net harm of the minor edits.  So if you want to fix a few small things when you come across them naturally, that's generally fine, but when you go around actively searching for, say, a single common typo to fix, then you flood the homepage, and that gets disruptive.  In short, fix it when you see it, don't go looking for it.

> seems to be that "we" prefer incorrect grammar and wrong spelling, to correct grammar, and good spelling. But that doesn't make sense, it sounds a bit cynical, so I must be missing an important point.

You're right, it doesn't make sense, and that's not what's going on here.  We *don't* like incorrect grammar and wrong spelling, but *the problems fixed by those minor edits aren't as substantial as the problems caused by the person fixing it*.  When the medicine hurts more than the disease, you don't take it.  That doesn't mean that it's good to be sick.

Comment: Servy, I'm glad we agree today after disagreeing yesterday. I'm not breaking "our" guidelines by doing what I think improves the site - its more linked to the reviewing cycle, and teaching the newer guys how the game works.

Comment: @Servy: pp. 1-3 do not exist if a user have enough rep to edit. p.4 could be dealt programmatically  -- if it is hard to detect minor edits automatically then add a check box: `[x] - minor edit (no bump to front page)`.

Comment: -1. Your point 3 kind of doesn't matter since the suggested edit queue never gets long. Point 2 only really applies to recently posted questions, and could be fixed by just not allowing suggestions until an hour after a post is created. Point 1 I also disagree with; small grammar and formatting changes can be reviewed pretty much at a glance, without even needing to read the entire post, whereas more substantial changes require many minutes to review properly and require that the reviewer understand the post. The reviewer/editor effort ratio is *better* for minor edits, not worse.

Comment: One also could provide the minor edit checkbox only to users with enough reputation (basically creating a "minor edit" priviledge). To avoid someone misusing it, one could say that a certain proportion of minor edits still get bumped (say, about 5% of them), and use of that feature is limited to a certain number of minor edits per day. Also, there could be separate lists of minor edits available to moderators (or even to everyone who can flag posts), so that explicit checking for abusive minor edits could be done. without affecting the front page.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I specifically said, in my answer, that 1-3 don't apply to users with editing privileges, which is why it's not nearly as problematic for such users to make minor edits.  An option for suggesting "minor edits" has been made *many* times before.  It has always been rejected.

Comment: @celtschk If you're going to draw attention to minor edits, and require people to be spending a bunch of time checking them for abuse, then your proposed system isn't succeeding in its attempt to avoid consuming the time of others.  Either that time is spent checking the edits, and thus not spent on other activities, or it's not, and there is the potential for abuse.  You don't get both.

Comment: @Servy: With a separate list, everyone could decide for himself whether he wants to take time checking minor edits (and unlike review, there would be no queue to work up, but just a list). I'd expect actual abuse to be negligible anyway; but the extra list should satisfy also the paranoid. Also the assumption that the time spent on checking minor edits would otherwise have been spent on other activities on the network is just a guess.

Comment: @celtschk What makes you think the abuse would be lower?  The suggested edits queue already sees a fair bit of abuse.  If you provide ways of making it easier for a suggested edit to get through (less reviewers, reviewers who aren't paying as much attention, reviewers who aren't as interested in the editing guidelines, etc.) they'll *absolutely* shove it through that queue.  You'll see spam/vandalism going through that queue, regular edits by people who just want less reviewers for a greater shot at approval, people who just don't know the difference between the two options, etc.

Comment: @Servy: And how many of those are from *high reputation* members? (Ah, I notice now that you speak about "suggested edits". Those who only can suggest edits certainly would not have the necessary reputation to mark changes as minor.)

Comment: @celtschk High rep users don't suggest edits at all.  Their edits do not need to be reviewed.  This is why I stated, in my answer, that it's not nearly as problematic for higher reputation users to be making minor edits.  It can be a problem in a few situations (mass re-tagging, for example, can become disruptive) but it largely is not, when editing naturally.

Comment: @Servy: I didn't say they *suggest* edits. The problem which was noted for high-rep users was that it bumps the question. A minor-edit checkbox could avoid that.

Comment: @celtschk If you add that then yes, you'll see abuse. You'll find spammers given the motivation to get enough reputation to edit posts without anyone being notified, there are cases (granted, somewhat rare, but still) in which people get mad at each other and vandalize each others' posts, there are people that make edits that they think  are minor but are in fact wrong (this is particularly relevant with respect to code; fixing a misspelled word has significant consequences, meriting the attention to the edit, when it's editing code) etc.  You'll also see more abuse if you remove these checks.

Comment: @Servy: Somehow in every single comment you ignore some part of my suggestion. But I've now decided to not waste my time further with arguing about it.

Comment: Your first point makes no sense. Reviewing an edit takes more time than making the edit? I admit I don't know how the review system works, but surely it takes less time if someone else has already found what needs to be fixed about a post, rather than to have the reviewers read all the posts themselves and figure out what needs to be fixed?

Comment: @mcv If there was only *one* reviewer, possibly, but even that isn't often going to be the case for edits this minor.  In many cases the reviewer is going to take the time to go and actually fix up the post, doing everything that the editor *should* have done to begin with.  That can *easily* consume more time.  They'll also be spending time looking through the posts to see what else might need fixing, which, again, can be much more time than the editor if they're only fixing the first thing they saw.  Finally, and most importantly, there are 3-5 reviewers of a post, not just one.

Comment: @Servy So is editing a lost cause, then? If what you say is true, they're going to examine the entire post anyway. That, or it's going to remain unfixed. Both options are apparently undesirable. So how about the reviewer just reviews the edit, and lets the editing to the non-reviewers?

Comment: @mcv Editing isn't a lost cause, but people suggesting edits should be taking the time to make substantive, worthwhile edits, so that they are actually contributing more to the site than they are drawing from it.  When people take the time to really make a good edit, that tends to happen.  When people go around fiddling with tangential tags, or mass-editing a common typo, it doesn't.

Comment: @Servy So small edits are not worthwhile? What if the post is mostly fine, but there's one or two glaring spelling errors. Should those not be fixed? Should the editor invent unnecessary edits to make his edit more substantive? Maybe it would be a better idea to allow reviewers to revoke edit privileges when editors do a particularly sloppy job.

Comment: @mcv Such small edits can simply be made by people who have the ability to edit posts without requiring a detailed review process.  They do the *vast* majority of editing anyway.  You seem to think that all/most edits come from suggested edits.  They don't.  If an editor can find a way of turning an unsubstantive edit into a substantive one by *finding ways to actually improve the post more* then more power to them.  If they're upping their edited character count without actually *improving the post* then they're not helping. If someone has enough edits rejected in a week they get edit banned.

Comment: @Servy: What do you recommend if there is a typo in a post title, and the misspelled word is a potentially useful keyword for searches? One typical example where I was tempted to edit until I got a warning about minor edits was when somebody asked an OpenGL questions about rendering triangles, but wrote "traingals" in the title. It was clear from the context that the question was not about girls on trains (train-gals), but I still thought that it was distracting from the content, and that it could affect searches.

Comment: @RetoKoradi If you can make a case for why a particular edit will have a significant impact, then by all means.  In such a case the edit may well not have been too minor (although on a related note, Google *is* actually smart enough to handle typos in many cases; it's not just doing straight textual contains searches).  Whether a post is minor or not is not about how many characters it edits, it's about how much value is added from the edit.  Capitalizing an uncapitalized word in some contexts is very minor; when it changes a code block from an error to working code, it's not. Context matters.

Comment: I'm wondering how many minor edits would be approved in the amount of time spent on this meta answer.

Comment: 1-3 would be valid if it wasn't the case that the review queue is almost always empty, with people waiting and refreshing in order to perform edits. 4 would be valid if there were no way of detecting minor edits and not bumping.

Comment: @jwg If you start encouraging users to flood the system with hundreds of suggested edits just changing a single misspelled work, then the it would *become* a problem.  As it is, people end up edit banned when they do that.  Those types of edits can be submitted far faster than they can be reviewed.  Throw in 2-3 people concurrently flooding the system and they can *easily* max it out, preventing anyone else from ever using it.  As for not bumping, there *isn't* an easy way to determine if an edit is minor, and if there were, it introduces abuses with vandalism not being bumped.

Comment: I'd like to see the evidence you have that the review queue would be overloaded. It seems likely that there are many potential reviewers who don't even bother to check for reviews as there are always so few available.

Comment: @jwg I've seen *dozens* of people go on an editing spree that find one common misspelling of a word, go into search, look for all instances of it, and suggest edits to fix all of them.  It also happens with tagging issues, common signature words, common introductory words, etc.  Generally these users get edit banned half way through their spree for suggesting too minor edits.  When that's not a valid reason to reject, they won't stop.  I know people will do this *because I've seen it happen, personally, many many times*.  It is not a theory.  It is observed behavior, and not particularly rare.

Comment: I'd like to see the evidence you have that the review queue would be overloaded.

Comment: @jwg I've already provided it.  Clearly seeing as you're someone who isn't even capable of *using* the review system, let alone experienced with it, this may seem weird to you.  To virtually anyone who's done even a moderate amount of edit reviewing, this will be a very familiar sight to see.  When reviewing edits you run into the situation I described every couple of days, and that's with most of them learning it's wrong after the first or second spree.  When they learn that it's allowed, you'd see almost nothing *but* those types of edits.

Comment: Right, except that I *am* capable of using the review system on sister sites. And that if it's possible to ban people for editing like this it would *still* be possible to edit ban them for editing like this even if 'minor' edits are not *always* rejected out of hand. And that if you can identify that an edit is minor as a reason to reject it, you can also identify that it is minor as a reason not to bump it. And that if you think reviewers are colluding with editors to pass vandalism through so it's hidden from .. **what??**

Comment: @jwg Sites that are not SO simply don't have the traffic or attention of SO.  You can't really compare them.  If minor edits should be approved, not rejected, why in the world should someone be banned for submitting 200 minor edits?  To say that they should be banned is to say that those edits are problematic.  If anyone can "approve but not bump" an edit then they could easily do so for problematic content.  The reason that this is a problem is that it's more likely to be found by future googlers who will see it, but not know that they should, or how, to fix it, unlike visibility to regulars.

Comment: @Servy No, not the fact that everything gets approved (which is false, by the way — both problems exist). Bad reviews in [both](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96431) [directions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784) were already a problem when the queue was clogged. It's not clear to me that the extra manpower has caused a decrease in quality (it wouldn't surprise me, but I've yet to see evidence). There is a huge problem with review quality, but the (relatively few) minor edits have nothing to do with that problem.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I did indulge in a bit of hyperbole.  *Everything* doesn't get approved, but in my experiences, about 75-80% of content that should be rejected is accepted.  That's a *huge* margin of error.  Yes, some edits are erroneously rejected, but they make up a fraction of a percent.  Any reviewer may not be a scarce resource, but a *quality* reviewer seems to be.  I also question your assertion that there are very few minor edits.  The number of editors submitting minor edits may not be overwhelming, but when those people are going around submitting hundreds of minor edits a day...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150060/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-o).

Answer (score 16):

The problem is when **only** these minor fixes are made but there are **other** changes to be made. "Too minor" doesn't necessarily mean that the thing fixed was minor but that the change was minor in comparison to what *could have been done*.

So the answer to your first question

> Is this an issue that we just don't want to give rep to someone who improves the quality of the site, but only by a little?

Yes, that's part of it, we want people to fix as much as possible in the post and not just make a single (unlikely problematic) change when there was much more that could have been fixed.

For your second question

> Given that I no longer get rep for improving posts - does that make it OK to try and add value in that way?

They still should improve the post quite a bit since edits can bump the question. We don't want questions getting bumped ahead of others just for capitalizing a letter or two or adding a comma somewhere (unless those changes do greatly impact the meaning of the post to make it more clear)

**Note**

Saying things like "apologies for the downvoting I'll likely get" usually invites downvotes. Just post your question, thought, etc... and let the SE universe do its thing.

Comment: `"Too minor" doesn't necessarily mean that the thing fixed was minor but that the change was minor in comparison to what could have been done.`  Actually, it does.  Read the rejection text: "suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."  It doesn't say that they are fixing everything, but rather that they are substantial.  Many people choose to accept complete, but minor, edits anyway.  This is understandable, but also very confusing for editors/reviewers due to the inconsistency.

Comment: @Servy I will admit that I've been confused on that for awhile myself. But I read a post saying basically what I put so I changed my thinking. For example, if a relevant tag were changed, changing a tag is minor but it has an impact on the post, so it should be approved assuming they didn't find anything else to change. Is that correct? Now, if they capitalized one letter, even if nothing else was wrong, that would be too minor.

Comment: Suggesting an edit has costs.  I discuss them in my answer.  If the benefit of the edit is greater than those costs, it's worth approving it.  When it's not, it isn't.  Sometimes adding an important tag, such as a language tag, to a post, can *greatly* improve it.  Sometime adding just four spaces, so that a code block is formatted as code, *greatly* improves the readability of a post.  Sometimes fixing a single capitalization error causes a code sample to compile instead of error.  Of course, all of those actions can be done in a context to not be very helpful at all.

Comment: @Servy I think your answer is pretty close to perfect, but I think codeMagic brings up an important point that is certainly part of the issue for me.  Formatting a code block is an edit that I'll approve if the post otherwise looks great, but if the post is rife with spelling and grammatical errors, I'll reject it as too minor.  The reasoning is similar to your own: don't waste our time with an edit that fixes only one of several obvious things that need fixing -- but fixing the one and only thing that needs fixing is generally worth doing unless it is very minor.

Comment: I had multiple times the case where there was exactly one character wrong and made the "read experience" annoying. The editor tells you to change "something else" - and then you either WTF+Cancel the action, or you start to edit "something else" only to reach the limit to make it a valid edit. Both ways seem smelly to me.

Comment: @Servy: I agree that fixing capitalization in code isn't a minor edit.  It should be rejected for an entirely different reason -- it dramatically changes the meaning.  That's not something that editors are supposed to do.  They should leave a comment instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt Making such a change is still maintaining the *intentions* of the post's author.  Code (in an answer, not in a question) is not sacrosanct and prohibited from being ever touched.  If the authors intentions are clear, editing the post to say what they *meant* is entirely fine.  Fixing a simple typo, or capitalization error, even in code, is entirely appropriate.  Changing the *logic* of the code, when the authors intentions are opposed to the edit, is the problem.   This is a well established editing guideline.

Comment: This is _the_ reason that small edits are discouraged, and hasn't gotten enough emphasis in this discussion. A lot of new users suggest a flood of small edits to get their +2 without actually doing very much to improve the site, often leaving huge errors in place. The point of having those edits reviewed is to _teach_ new users how to edit posts in a way that actually improves the site in a substantive way.

Comment: This is the fallacious argument given by @JeffAtwood. It is fallacious because it assumes that a post which has a minor (by number of chars) but significant (in meaning) typo also has several other things wrong with it which need fixing. Unfortunately the truth about this issue is that Jeff wedded himself to an impossible position a long time ago, and has made his mind up that it is inadmissible ever to admit that he was wrong about this.

Comment: About the need to correct everything (exaggeration ahead) - you correct what you see with high hopes that you are making things better. And then you are rejected. And it is not always very easy to understand why. On my first ever edit the reviewer took my edits, rejected them, added something small and I felt like he took my glory because he was a snob with reputation. (exaggeration over). Only reading several meta posts you begin to understand why this edit is "good", why other edit is "bad". And it is natural to start with substantial but small edits - you are putting this mechanism to test.

Answer (score 12):

I appeal to keep edits as minimal as possible.

I mean, if you edit a post just to fix a typo mistake, DO NOT be tempted to "improve language style". It can sometimes obscure the intention of the original post and after all it is not a poetry site.

Comment: Good point - that's what I say when making submissions to any repo I control, so why not here too. Keep the commit changes to the point, makes the diff easier.

Answer (score 6):

The one thing that drives me nuts are users who search for a misspelled word and then correct it for 50 posts in a row without correcting anything else from the same posts.

It wouldn't be so bad if the posts/questions they corrected didn't come back all the way up to the front page, but they do. And often times, many of those questions/answers they edit are many years old, and they edit them whether they're still relevant now, or not.

And to me at least, I don't have a problem with minor edits. What I do have a problem with however is the incentive for low reputation users to gain points through edits. Give them a couple of points for editing a post, ok, but let's not go over board with encouraging some people to do many edits in exchange for points.

In my opinion, once people figure out that they can suggest edits to some posts, they'll continue editing posts for the real value of it (instead of doing it only for internet points).

Answer (score 5):

Giving the user the benefit of the doubt, I'm a fan of many of the edits made. They clarify and fix. Plus it's time-consuming work that not a lot of technical folk want to do.

Also, there is a large chance that they are only correcting spelling, grammar, punctuation, and capitalization **because they are a low-rep user that is wary of unknowingly modifying the content of the answer**, so they choose to help out by cleaning stuff up until they know more. I have no problem with that. At all.

If users like this want to mine for rep by cleaning up SO overall, that's fine with me.

Now, it **is** an issue that threads get bumped for "nothing". Perhaps a "This is a minor edit" checkbox is in order?

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of annoying when the only thing wrong with a post is the code is not formatted properly, and whitespace doesn't count against the 6 character limit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so black and white as that. You think the only choices are that a typo remains uncorrected, or that a user who can only suggest edits corrects the typo. This is a false dichotomy, which leads you to the obviously false conclusion that we prefer incorrect grammar and wrong spelling.

I (I can't speak for others) prefer silly typos like "teh" and minor grammar issues that any native speaker can correct to **spending the time of edit-reviewers reviewing edits that fix only those**. This has nothing to do with whether those mistakes should go uncorrected or a suggester should earn rep for something small.

If there is plenty to fix, fix it all. If there is just one tiny typo, your best bet is to ignore it and let a higher-rep user fix it later. If you think the typo is interfering with understanding (not/now is a classic example) leave a comment.

Comment: So rejecting the review, and hoping another high rep user like you or I will come and fix it later - how does that save time? Is this another case of trying to cure the whole population of new guys by rejecting individual attempts?

Comment: Don't reject. Hit improve and uncheck "suggested edit was helpful." Fix anything else you see that needs fixing. Reject can't serve its intended purpose in an ecosystem of roboreviewers. And yes, as Servy explains getting people to stop suggesting these teeny edits (by withholding the reward) is a long game, but the only game in town really.

Comment: Thx Kate, I missed that checkbox last time I took the time for reviews - will be sure to use it next time round.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165719/does-improve-allow-an-edit-reviewer-to-be-a-majority-of-1-and-must-we-start-to

Comment: @KateGregory I'm pretty sure they did make the change to the edit ban system to not include edits rejected through improving though, so while you *do* reject that edit, you don't push the user towards an edit ban.  (I'm not positive about this though; I might just be thinking about cases involving rejections due to conflicted edits.)

Comment: @Servy, given the choice between "I am sure you will not get your dopamine" and "you will probably get your dopamine but the chances of an edit ban have increased fractionally" I will go with the first.

Comment: @KateGregory Yeah, just mentioning it.  If you think that an edit is *so bad* that it's likely to be rejected, even with all of the robo reviewers, I'll risk it though.  Sometimes you can also tell, by looking at your recent history, whether there are more robo or quality reviewers online at that particular moment.  Judgement calls.

Comment: I can't get behind this approach. Your proposed solution to typo-correcting edits (that I've found can be seen to be correct or not in about 5 seconds, unlike more meaningful edits that can take me many minutes) 'wasting' the time of people with edit privileges is to either 1) expect a reviewer to take the time to copy-edit in detail a post he otherwise wouldn't care about, or 2) expect somebody to spend the time to redo the suggester's work later. How does that possibly *reduce* wasted effort? I'm pretty sure I can review 5 typo changes in less time than it takes for me to copy-edit one post.

Comment: @MarkAmery if you're not prepared to copy edit in detail then don't do it. Searching for one common mistake and fixing only that in hundreds of posts, leaving other mistakes untouched, is not helping anyone. I don't care how quickly you can do it. If you're going to use up reviewer time, prevent others from suggesting edits, bump the post to the first page, etc then do all that for a reason, not just to change `teh` to `the`. While it may seem wasteful to reject an individual edit that has already been done, too minor are supposed to be rejected and it should reduce bad suggestions in future.

Comment: I suppose we need some minor edits in the honeypot system.  That might knock down roboreviewers in a big hurry.

Comment: @BenVoigt see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection

Comment: @BenVoigt people who thoughtfully disagree with you on what reasons justify rejecting an edit do not warrant the label 'roboreviewers'. I simply take the view that reviewers shouldn't have to spend time weighing up whether to throw away other people's valid and useful work for the sake of establishing a system of incentives that I: 1) don't think can actually be created and 2) am not sure *should* exist anyway. I resent being labelled as some kind of unscrupulous badge-whore for taking this view.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I'm not using the word for people who thoughtfully anything.  People who dispose of 30 items in the suggested edit queues in 10 seconds are not being thoughtful.  Audits for too minor edits will catch both roboreviewers, and people who thoughtfully made a decision against the actual rules of the site, decided on meta by consensus.  If you disagree with having a "too minor" rejection reason, argue that on meta.  But don't ignore the rules.

Comment: @BenVoigt Tell me if I'm being uncharitable, but it seems to me that the *intent* of your proposal of using minor edits as audits which to catch those who disagree with you; otherwise you're just picking a class of audits that guarantees you the worst ratio of roboreviewers caught to innocents caught in the crossfire. Re: going 'against' the rules decided by 'consensus'; consensus seems, from the votes here, to be against you, and as I said in my answer I have never been able to find any rules on what edits should be rejected as minor. I would welcome links to some.

Comment: @Mark: If you think this represents a change in consensus, then submit a `feature-request` for removal of the "edit is too minor" rejection reason.  Questions tagged `discussion` are non-binding.

Comment: @BenVoigt you continue to talk as though there are existing rules stating that certain edits must be rejected as too minor. As far as I can tell, this isn't the case. Where are these rules, and who created them? Meta is full of *arguments* over what things count as too minor, but I don't know of any definitive rules on it (and both reviewers and answerers to those questions have a broad spectrum of views on what counts). Even the [how to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) page contradicts itself, recommending minor edits and then recommending against them.

Comment: @Mark: I agree there's a deplorable lack of definition about where the line between "too minor" and "ok" is.  But you seem to be saying that there is no line, that no edit is too minor.  That's clearly wrong, because we have a "too minor" close reason.

Comment: @BenVoigt In my answer on this question, and my first comment on this answer, I am indeed arguing the point that *nothing* should count as too minor. However, w.r.t. the question of adding minor edits as audits to the review queue, it seems to me that I don't need to make that aggressive a case - I simply need to point out that there exists no kind of edit, or even example of an edit, that even a rough majority of Meta agree is supposed to fall under the 'too minor' definition. How would you propose finding or generating edits that were fit for the task?

Answer (score 2):

Could the `Too minor edit` be changed to `Did not add any quality to post.`?

Really, what we are trying to avoid is pointless edits but as long as they are an improvement then they are adding quality to the post and the site.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, one reason to have "too minor" as a reason for disapproving an edit is quality control. Edits, like posts, have quality of their own. The "too minor" reason says that your edit has to be above a certain level to be admitted.

Now, for example, in an edit I just came across, someone just changed "openlayers" to "OpenLayers" because Hungarian style is more to his/her liking; or worse, in other cases, people just put a block of error message you post into a code block so that a line is 10 pages wide, what should we do?

Is the edit "Invalid", "Radical Change", "Vandalism" or "Copied Content"?

Obviously, none of the above. There is no proper way to say, that the edit is just "too minor". There is no quality control now except for the extreme cases, unless you are willing to abuse the system and mark those edits as "Invalid" or such. Reviewers are probably prone to choose the lesser of the two evils, and accept "too minor" edits.

One consequence, of course, is to discourage people from making true edits.

Maybe, like Wikipedia, SO should have an checkbox that says "this is a minor edit" on the edit page? This way, minor edits do not contribute as much to rep and the reviewer can anticipate that it's minor change.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253983/change-in-attribution-of-question-editing-by-new-user) yesterday on a similar issue to do with editing and the peer-review process. While I tend to agree that edits for grammar and language are as important to SO as edits on content, it might be useful to distinguish between the types of edits being made. Flags need to be qualified with a reason and why not have something similar for edits? Differentiation could be made on the following:

1. Technical content, clarification, logic
2. Correction of typos in code and examples, code block fixing
3. Language, grammar, text flow
4. Minor typographical corrections, punctuation, etc.

Since most users, and presumably even posters, would not care about the latter three types of edits (even though they benefit from them), I would suggest to have these made "silently", e.g. no mention of them under the OP, but still visible in the revision history. Only the first type of edits would be explicitly mentioned with the OP because they may change the meaning of the OP or the comprehensibility for readers.

The editor self-assigns the type of edits made. Rep can be differentiated based on type, i.e. +10 for type 1, +2 for types 2 and 3 and +0 for type 4. Toss in the appropriate badges for added editor self-esteem. Have a moderator check on editors with unusually high edits of type 1 or limit editing rep to x rep/day, just to keep the repwhores at a distance. Type 1 typically requires more analysis and work than the other types and it is a nice encouragement to contribute to what SO is all about: high-quality Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the main downside of approving a minor edit is that it has side effects like bumping edited questions.  That's what needs to be balanced against the benefits of the edit.

If an entire post is poorly written and the editor fixes the grammar and spelling throughout the post, I will typically vote to approve.  If the editor only fixes one word, I will typically vote against the edit as "too minor".

One thing I wish for is a lighter pink for the background of removed text, so I could more easily read the original and compare it to the edited version of the post.  The current colors seem to me to exaggerate the differences between the two in a way that significantly adds to my reviewing time.

Comment: one word can be a major edit, if it's the right word :)

Answer (score -2):

I think minor edits are frowned upon only if they are performed using suggested edits. Reasons were already given: wasting time of reviewers, locking posts, rep whoring etc.

However, when you gain enough reputation to edit posts without approval, I don't see anything wrong about fixing misspellings and other minor issues.

Typos don't look nice, but they don't make questions or answers any less useful. It's much better to spend energy elsewhere. For example, on answering questions or reviewing.

Overall, the rule is simple: if you feel like wasting your time, make sure to **waste only your time**. In that case, it means earning some rep before starting a futile war against typos.

Comment: This answer is rather opinion-based to me.  Typos (especially in code, as has been pointed out)/ grammar mistakes, confusing style are all useful.  Unfortunately, the design of the system, requiring review, means that I can't avoid 'wasting' someone else's time.  How can I follow a rule to 'waste' only my own time, when someone _must_ review it?

Answer (score -2):

### Edit:

Here's what Jeff Atwood [stated](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) back in '09:

> Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction

### Original post:

As I remember, the original reasons why minor edits were discouraged (feel free to dig through the archives of the SO blog if you want to be sure. I'm just going by my memory) was nothing to do with reviewer time (back then, the reviewer mechanism didn't exist). It was simply that it can come across as harsh, disrespectful and unwelcoming to (new) users. It can seem very intrusive, editing something someone else wrote without their permission, and without first informing them of what you're doing and why.

Having others sneak in and edit what you wrote makes it look like your question wasn't good enough, and might push people towards not asking questions again in the future.

If I wrote something on SO, I am glad to see others substantially improve it, but it is still *my* question or answer, but it does seem disrespectful if others start ticking off typos or bad grammar in it for no other reason than because they can and have nothing better to do.

It's like if you go to a restaurant and pull out a marker to correct a typo on their menu. No one asked you to do that, and while yes, they should get it fixed for their own sake, it just seems petty and disrespectful to unilaterally correct it.

SO has already slid heavily towards favoring and encouraging reviewers and editors, at the cost of making it a less welcoming place for people writing actual *content*. The "don't make minor, trivial edits" rule was a simple guideline to not alienate users by having what they wrote changed under their feet.

Comment: Your menu analogy is not right. Menus are not created with the expectation of being edited, whereas SO questions are. I don't see why typos should remain simply to avoid offending the OP with edits.

Comment: @Duncan not all SO users create their questions with the expectation of being edited either. Compared to forums, mailing lists, newsgroups and whatever else people may come from, others editing your content is not always an expectation. And the reason for avoiding offending the OP is very simple: **You want him to stay on the site**. I'm sorry that *you* don't like it, but it's a simple truth. (Some) people are turned off by others rushing to edit and change what they wrote. Is that a price worth paying for something trivial like changing a "teh" to "the"?

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) by Jeff Atwood explaining why trivial edits should generally be avoided.  [Here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1807/editing-other-users-posts-for-completely-trivial-reasons) is an example of a user feeling alienated by it. Note also that while googling for this, literally *half* the search results were people complaining about how SO sucks [these](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow) [days](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/)

Comment: We have [a help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) dedicated to this topic. One of the first few sentences is "*If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*". TBH, I'm not overly bothered about retaining every user who walks through the door. If they are particularly offended by well-intentioned edits that improve the quality of the site, perhaps this *isn't* the site for them.

Comment: I suppose our debate here hinges on just how trivial we are talking about. I don't welcome a one-word change from "its" to "it's". But I'm happy to correct several typos and grammatical errors in a post.

Comment: @Duncan: "edited by other trusted users" is explicitly NOT the topic of the disagreement.  Trusted users don't go through the suggested edits queue.

Comment: @Duncan why don't you welcome a one-word change? You seemed to argue before that there was *nothing* wrong with such trivial edits, that people should expect and welcome and appreciate them. Personally I agree with you: fixing a single typo just for the sake of fixing a typo doesn't really improve the site (and as I said, it may turn users away, which are, like it or not, the lifeblood of SO). Fixing several typos and errors to actually make the post clearer and more readable, that's different, and not what I would call "too minor". It just doesn't seem like what you were arguing before

Comment: Anyway, I pointed to the original rationale behind the recommendation to avoid making "too minor" edits. The help page you mentioned talks about editing *in general*, not about minor nitpicks and people fixing individual typos. Saying "you should expect trusted users to collaboratively edit and improve your posts" does not automatically imply "you should expect *anyone* on the site to fix your every typo or grammar error".

Comment: @BenVoigt I believe that phrase means that trusted users are involved in every edit, whether directly or by approving edits of others.

Comment: @jalf Perhaps we are closer to being in agreement than I originally thought. I thought your original answer was suggesting that most typo/grammar corrections are unwelcome. But it sounds now like neither of us want to see one or two minor corrections in a post, but both would welcome a general tidy up of misspellings and grammatical errors.