# Change in attribution of question editing by "new" user?

Tags: discussion

As a relatively new user on SO I still have a lowly station among the more established users, as is evidenced by my measly sub-1,000 rep. Not exactly being a repwhore, I do enjoy my increasing abilities in this community and so I happily answer, vote, comment and... edit other people's questions.

I accept that there is a peer-review process to weed out the chaff and thanks to the combined selfless efforts of the established residents that is also typically a rather quick process. What I do not understand, however, is that my substantive edits are not mine anymore after the peer-review makes minor changes.

As happened in [one of my edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530045/make-a-trigger-stop-inserting-same-data-on-different-tables) recently, the peer-reviewer made some minor English grammar corrections that I had not cared about to edit, the post was perfectly readable the way I left it. Following the initial discussion following this here meta post, I decided to make some further edits, all English-language stuff and nothing related to substance. And voila!, the edit is mine again and +2 rep to boot (another 600 or so edits and I can peer-review myself!).

I would strongly suggest to change the peer-review process to give the credit to the original editor when there were substantive edits. Seeing my edits appear under a different name certainly is no incentive to keep on improving questions. I suggest to always attribute edits to the editor and have the peer-reviewer do a separate edit of the post if the observed residual buh-buh is too gross for this community to digest. Or have the peer-reviewer decide on whether the edits were substantive (attribute it to the editor) or merely linguistic improvements (do not even bother to mention that in the post - this is not a school for English for Computer engineers).

Comment: have you got an example? Maybe your suggested edits have been improved or someone else has edited the post ( see revision history ) and that's why your name is not displayed.

Comment: Ok. My bad. I never knew there was a revision history but did find it.   And indeed, I just got "overwritten by another user

Comment: But this does bring the issue to what to edit. My edits were making the original description more readable and to have proper code formatting. The second editor merely made typographical improvements on the English language. Is that something that should be edited too, beyond making the text readable?

Comment: it's quite difficult to find a proper FAQ indicating what a good edit is. It comes with experience I guess. but you're right, your edit was great! the second person's edit was not so good but still an edit.. once youre over 2K you can make any sort of edits you want as SE treats you as a [trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @mehow: Thanks for the thumbs-up. With my newfound knowledge I have re-worded the post above.

Comment: "*my measly sub-1,000 rep*" Hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha (yes, I realize this is old, but it's still funny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4753612) has actually been approved but the last reviewer decided to improve the post as seen in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23530045/revisions).

This means your name was there as the person who improved the post but people with 2K+ rep points can edit posts without going into the suggested edits review queue.

The name displayed on an edited post is always the last editor's display name.

Also, you have been given the 2+ rep points for your suggested edit as seen in your profile

[image]

---

See, on [another one of your suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602722/which-geo-implementation-to-use-for-millions-of-points) that has been approved your name is still displayed on the original post as the last person who edited the post as no-one else has improved the post after you.

Comment: Sometimes an indicator that someone else is typing an answer would be handy... :)

Comment: @Stijn yep I agree but it does not hurt to have 2 answers +1 to you

Comment: Oh my, all the stuff you can dig up about me!! What else can you come up with?

Comment: hehe @Patrick anything [publicly visible](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @mehow: One day I'll have a look at your dirty laundry {;P

Comment: @Patrick cracking! ;)

Answer (score 4):

[This suggested edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4753612) was approved and further improved by one of the reviewers.

In the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23530045/revisions) you can see that two revisions were created, your suggested edit and the edit by the reviewer.

So you are correctly attributed, it's just that your edit is no longer the most recent edit.

Comment: I am still a bit baffled by the fact that a peer-reviewer can "claim" the edits like this. Of course, I know, anyone can go into the revision history and see that I did my editing and then someone else - geez, the peer-reviewer himself - did some further edits. But that is just not how it should work. I can go back and change another few words into a more fluent, stylish, modern English and re-claim my name under the OP, but that is just not the way I want to go. See my amended post above.

Comment: @Patrick That's just how editing works in general, it's not specific to suggested edits. Only the most recent editor is displayed in the regular view, not all editors.

Comment: @Patrick, I've never thought of the edit indicator on a post as an attribution, more an indication that if you notice something wrong/strange you need to check the revision history to see who is to blame and what the appropriate action is e.g. a rollback vs an edit/comment.

Comment: @Patrick, it might be worth noting that this "claim" is only about the latest name the appears from the history. This user was well above the threshold to gain any points from editing. There is indeed a reputation threshold (2000, I think) after which editing doesn't bring you any reputation at all (which effectively doesn't give us any incentive to edit, as a side-effect). This user wouldn't have gained +2 like you did.