# What is the most searched word on meta by 1 rep users?

Tags: support, search, new-users, statistics

I know that many beginners do not reach meta. However, many who experience downvotes or poorly received first questions may end up here.

It is impossible to determine from the outside what they search for. Is there a way internally to query or ascertain what the most commonly used word is when a 1 reputation uses the search feature on meta?

It may help with figuring out what type of help new users most frequently need and also how to possibly deliver it to them via naming convention.

Comment: Probably "ban"...

Comment: Hypothesis: They don't search. They go straight to the "Ask Question" button to ask their programming question only to be denied because they have less than 5 rep.

Comment: not sure if data-explorer can retrieve this info, anyone know?

Comment: @Coffee No that's not something that would be available in Data Explorer.

Comment: Thanks animuson,  hmm I think that with users' permission, we might be able to gather some data. Stack can make an addon for Chrome/FF that sucks search data and sends back to Stack.   But I think , in the end, it would simply correlate with the question titles  - i.e a greater number of dupes signifies a greater number of searches. so ya... "ban" , and "downvotes"

Comment: @Coffee - Users that begin to advance their reputation are potentially going to continue to do so. Some users completely misunderstand the way the site works and that was the curiosity here. Perhaps there is value in the <100 as well though.

Comment: if you go by titles it would be one of these, I am sure: {problem, error, help, urgent, need}

Comment: Moderators can see a list of common search terms, but we can't see any breakdown by users or their reputation.

Comment: @Bill Huh, the list for this Meta seems to be filled with a lot of "xxx.com" and equivalent search terms. That's kind of weird...

Comment: @animuson Yeah, I was going to ask if anyone knew what that was all about. Some kind of 'bot looing for example URLs to edit maybe?

Comment: @Bill Perhaps a lot of people trying to find [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255166/changing-all-instances-of-xxx-com-to-example-com-in-edits) because "xxx.com" is a blacklisted URL on Stack Overflow? Or a lot of people being very disappointed at what they find when they click through to our site.

Comment: @animuson That question has a lot more views than I'd expect for a meta question. It's probably a top search engine hit. But probably not what people are looking for.

Comment: @animuson I would have guessed it's [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255337/1288), but he's only ever done one revision on Meta. I wonder if someone else saw that post and started doing the same here?

Answer (score 38):

I bet the answer to this is: "They don't search".

I state this because I don't normally do it myself (I do look at the suggestions near the title bar when asking a question though, so don't go bashing me.)

Comment: Boo for not searching. Kudos for being honest about it :) Note that until the fuzzying algorithm is done, Google is often a better search tool.

Comment: Just a heads up, Sklivvz and I are still working on improving search. We have already made some (minor) changes and anticipate some major changes in the next few weeks. Unfortunately I cannot reveal details at this time (observer bias, don't want to bias you in our testing!). However, if people are interested when it's all said and done we might do a blog post. :)

Comment: @Haney: please do, blog posts on the intricacies, and internals, of the site are fascinating.

Comment: @Haney Seconding the motion to let us know when its done. I read the initial meta question that mentioned you were going to be working on it, and would love to try it out when its ready!

Answer (score 15):

When I was a brand new user I remember coming on here to figure out why so many people were so aggressive on this site.
I found this: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)
I suspect most new users are searching for the same thing.

Honestly I still don't understand why an old discussion isn't allowed to resurface.  This place has an interesting and rather intimidating culture.

Comment: Feel free to resurface the discussion, but you need to *add something constructive*. Just re-hashing all the old stuff doesn't really help anybody, and its easy for such "discussions" to turn into rants. Ideally, you would have a real *suggestion* about how we could improve the culture.

Comment: Fair enough.   Maybe there could be a "no stupid questions" stack exchange community for programmers.  I know I would use it LOL.   Anyway, I've just learned to accept it and I try to only ask well-researched questions, but sometimes I still get caught on something simple or "dumb".  Now that I've been around longer: I understand this is a place for professionals and I understand it more, but when I was brand new I was pretty confused about why there was so much question quality criticism/concern.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a question being "well-researched" and one being "super complex". True, most simple problems can be solved with minimal research, but in the cases where they can't (or the solution is well-hidden) they can still be posed in a well-researched way. Many new users seem to share your confusion about the quality standards, which would be fixed if they read the FAQ/Meta/Help, but they are new so they don't do that, and it tends to not end well :(

Comment: yeah, I get it now.  It was mostly a problem when I was new, although I am still scared to ask "too many questions".  The problem is that University teaches computer theory but not a whole lot of good programming practice. As such I get caught on syntax things even though I understand memory & the stack, etc (I can program in assembly pretty well).  APIs can be useful but sometimes aren't much help. Especially when I started I couldn't understand a library reference guide or an API for my life.  BTW by a "no stupid questions" community I really meant a place where stupid questions are allowed.

Comment: I have wondered whether questions could be separated out a bit into newbie and more expert questions. Sometimes people who have little experience in something don't know how to ask well - they don't know the right terms, say things unclearly, or don't find existing answers because they don't know the right things to search for. Some people are happy to spend time clarifying the question and then answering it, and other novices will find those Q&As helpful. I think it's a shame there's nowhere for that and that the reaction they do get might put them off the site or even the topic.

Comment: That question/discussion was shutdown and locked because it turned into a brutal and never-ending flamewar. Basically everyone who was ever on the receiving end of some sort of "negative" reaction started complaining there. The problem is that the two sides are so at odds with each other that every single time the discussion comes up, a flamewar ensues...

Comment: How would you define a question as stupid? What is stupid for one person may not be for someone else. And that has nothing to do with experience, different people = different understanding. SO, matter of fact all SE sites have a bunch of tools to deal with questions that don't meet the standards. Anyone that is rude instead of using those tools is not really being professional. Having a lot of experience or being really smart doesn't give you free pass to be rude. But we are all humans, and sometimes the really smart make mistakes too.

Comment: Also we are all newbies in subject matters that we have never worked on before. And if you make questions of those subject matters you are bound to create a question that is stupid for an expert. I would like people would remember that before they start patronizing you. I am also worried like you when I post a question that someone is going to come hunt me because is stupid :P

Comment: @Dzyann I think the real trick is showing that you aren't using SO as your *first* source of research. For example, I'm not much a web dev, so if I run into a problem I google it and find the likely appropriate function. Then I run into an issue with it, google *that* and when I find no results ask a well-written question about it. There's a big difference between doing that and **starting** by asking "How do I get part of a string in Javascript?" One is completely lazy, the other shows effort and a bit of starting knowledge. The problem is people doing the former, and not the latter.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree with you. But sometimes people think you didn't research when you did. For example, I am not native English Speaker and many times I search for something and I don't find it. I ask a friend from the US to search for me and he gets a bunch of hits. If you find a duplicate, fixing it is as easy as flagging it. People don't normally complain that others are rude because of using the site mechanics, but because other people seem to have the need to be mean making colorful comments and what not.

Comment: @Dzyann And such behavior (rude comments) is totally inappropriate. People *do* tend to complain about downvotes/question bans though. I also wish there was a way around the "search language barrier".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree with you. But what I don't get is, what is the purpose of downvoting 10 times instead of flagging to close? If something is that bad it should be closed. But flagging is harder I guess?

Comment: @Dzyann Alternatively, the downvoters may have not had close vote privileges. Assuming it actually got closed, that means you had 5 <3K users DV (and maybe flag to close, you wouldn't know) and 5 >3K users DV and vote to close. Sometimes people will downvote a question even *after* its closed if they feel it is of poor enough quality. "Pile-on" downvotes have been discussed, and they are definitely a problem (of course, they aren't for the truly terrible/spam posts).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET to be pedantic - it should be that "you aren't [asking a question on] SO as your *first* source of research". I've had to ask several  "stupid questions" - the problem not being that they were stupid so much as I didn't have the prior knowledge to even know what to look for. So I said as much - "I've looked for foo, buzz, quux, and spam but I couldn't find anything! What do I need to look for?" and then the answer could've been, "Try searching for bar" - but is typically more helpful than that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i agree with you, overall it is a complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of them probably use Google to search, so your query would have to be expanded to examine the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) string history that comes when they click from the search engine into Stack Overflow.  This could get complicated, given that people do not always log in to Stack Overflow right away, or in a given session.

Comment: I have the rather strong opinion that no one searches meta from google.

Comment: I search meta from google.  However, to support your assertion, it is not clear that 1 rep users are familiar enough with the site to do the same. Cheers.

Comment: You must have very good google-fu :)