# Should I change xyz.com to example.com in the code of a question?

Tags: support

I am unable to submit edits unrelated to the occurrence of xyz.com that appears in the question's provided code. If xyz.com is blocked, then I am not sure how the question was submitted as-is in the first place. In order to submit other revisions, should I change the URL? My question is really about whether it's OK to edit that part of somebody's posted code (my concern is that editing code may affect the results described in the question, though probably not in this exact case)?

Comment: Related but slightly different due to the NSFW context of the sample URL: [Changing all instances of “xxx.com” to “example.com” in edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255166/changing-all-instances-of-xxx-com-to-example-com-in-edits/255168#255168)

Comment: I am not sure what to make of your first sentence, "I am unable to submit edits unrelated to the occurrence of xyz.com that appears in the question's provided code."  What do you mean?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think he means that it is rejecting all edits, because it contains that domain, even though he did not add it.

Comment: I edited a tag, minor change to title case, etc. and unable to submit those changes due to the URL warning which I was not intending to address.

Comment: That is correct, Alexander.

Comment: @sss4r ah ok, thanks for the clarification.  Most likely the question was posted before "xyz,com" was blacklisted.  So change it to example.com.  You aren't really "changing" the code since you are replacing one sample URL for another

Comment: I would recommend mentioning the reason for the URL change in the edit summary, so that reviewers will know why you changed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In all cases your edit should fix everything in the post. This includes (but is not limited to):

- the word *problem* in title *(is blocked by the quality filter)*
- title starts with a tag *(use the tags instead)*
- salutations *(remove as they are noise)*
- Thanks in advanced (and milder forms) *(remove as they are noise)*
- taglines *(remove as they are noise)*
- blocked urls *(use example.com)*
- grammar, spelling, capitalize I's
- layout *(correct use of code-blocks, paragraphs, lists, code-snippets)*
- add/remove any tags (not) relevant to the question.

In general, if someone after you is able to do another edit to improve the post, you failed (and if you're below 2,000 reputation you're wasting 3 reviews and the time from 3 reviewers). I state it this blunt because we should edit for quality, not for the reputation.

Comment: Including blocked URLs as they appear in code? How was that code submitted in the first place?

Comment: @sss4r presumably it preceded the blacklist, but without a link to the specific question it's hard to say.

Comment: At any rate, thanks for your assistance.