# What is the purpose of modifying the example domain in data example?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

The revision changes instances of `domain.com` to `domain.example` in the sample data provided by the Question's author.

Does this change follow some guideline or objective for Stack Overflow quality maintainers? There appears to be no reason cited.

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39139107/3

Comment: Related: [Should I change xyz.com to example.com in the code of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295694) and [Changing all instances of "xxx.com" to "example.com" in edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255166), with the difference being that in those cases, the example domains used linked to malicious or undesirable domains.

Comment: I’d understand a change from domain.com to example.com more than the change to domain.example. The initial conversation about using example.com is on MSE [Help users create dummy links that are not to unrelated commercial sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186529/1099857) (including the blacklisting of links to domain.com)

Comment: Related on Webmasters Stack Exchange meta: [Example domain cleanup](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/example-domain-cleanup)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of example domain edits recently. When using an example URL, the domain should be an approved example domain such as:

- `example.com`
- `example.net`
- `mysite.example`
- `pageA.example`

See these Wikipedia articles and RFCs that explain how the domains are reserved and approved for example usage:

- `example.com` - [RFC 2606, section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-3) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)
- `.example` - [RFC 2606, section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-2) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example)

Using a real domain name is not desired because it can:

- Bestow unwarranted SEO benefit to the domain, especially when linked, but possibly even just through a mention.
- Cause problems for the domain when it gets unwanted requests from code that uses it as an example or when web crawlers find and hit the bogus URLs.

Stack Overflow actually prohibits new and edited posts from containing many incorrectly used example domains such as "mysite" or "domain" with a real top level domain suffix. I believe that this regular expression is in place that prevents a post from being submitted if the regular expression matches:

`https?://(www\.)?(domain|xxx|xyz|abc|site|mysite|mydomain)\.(com|org|net)(?![a-z0-9\-]+|\.[a-z0-9]+)`

To Henry Ecker's point, I have revamped [my editing tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/9440/auto-editor-a-user-script-for-automatically-correcting-common-errors) to prefer to use `example.com` over `mysite.example` if there is just one example domain used in the post. In the cases where two or more example domain are needed for comparison it often makes more sense to use the `.example` TLD like:

- `siteA.example`
- `siteB.example`

or

- `myserver.example`
- `myhost.example`
- `mydns.example`

Comment: Is there any source that this is the regex used by SO?

Comment: @HashimAziz I'm a moderator on Webmasters and I can see that this is the regex that is used there. I don't know for sure that it is used network-wide, but I believe that it is at least used on the technical focused stacks.  A Stack Overflow moderator would be able to visit https://stackoverflow.com/admin/blocklist and verify that it is used here.