# Is this edit suggestion a bad joke or offensive behaviour?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, offensive

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13546223

The editor changed zzz.com to **xxx.com** (also the bold).

IMO, this is offensive behavour (isn't xxx.com a porn site? idk).

Should I reject and edit to make sure it doesn't pass the queue since the last two reviewers did just approve (looks like bad behaviour from the reviewers?).

What should I do in such a situation?

Comment: My favorite part of the edit is how it exactly replicates the placeholder text for the summary, "improved formatting"

Comment: I went for "Improve", and fixed the remaining flaws... In hindsight, "reject and edit" may have been better.

Comment: @Cerbrus ..."Improve" is also an option. You did have a point that the editor fixed the formatting. (Of course, if it had been a language where indentation has meaning, like Python, it might have been a different story).

Comment: He just made the text match the code snippet.  Offensive, well, no.  Nice clean-cut guy, obviously never visited that site.  Readers, well, idk :)

Comment: @HansPassant: Even after the edit, there's still both "xxx" and "zzz" in there, I just noticed...

Comment: Since `xxx.com` was already in the text, this looks like an honest error. There's no reason to assume it was malicious or offensive.

Comment: This is why people should just use `example.com`. =)

Comment: Related: [Changing all instances of “xxx.com” to “example.com” in edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255166/changing-all-instances-of-xxx-com-to-example-com-in-edits).  Frankly, we should be changing "fake" URL's to example.com to eliminate these types of concerns.

Comment: You sure are easily offended

Comment: No, but I think xxx.com shouldnt be used since it can be mistaken ans misleading also for companies

Comment: I also think it was a innocent mistake. xxx is frequently used as a placeholder for something, like usernames, passwords, and websites. But I didn't even consider that it could be a porn site until now. Also as someone already mentioned, xxx.com was already there before the edit. They probably wanted to make it consistent.

Comment: I buy all my comically large jugs of moonshine from xxx.com.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The edit also fixes indentation / formatting in the code.

I've [chosen "Improve edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39286683/revisions), removed the mention of the site from the first line, and fixed remaining errors.

Comment: I'm not sure wheter Improve edit or reject edit is better, because one way, the user gets rewarded for doing bad stuff, the other way, he fixed formatting, so it might be ok.

Comment: The edit fixed a critical mistake (unformatted `}`). That's why I chose accept.

Comment: @Mafii I don't think the editor meant harm, as both domain names occurred in the original post.

Comment: meh, why don't we use example.com, since the domain isn't that important anyways.

Comment: @Braiam Apparently because they want 2 example domains. They could use `example.com` and `example.org`, of course... but the difference between those is easy to overlook in a code snippet.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think it was either. The example contained both zzz and xxx, as pointed out by S.L. Barth, and if I had to guess I'd say the editor just got confused, saw the xxx, missed the zzz, assumed the OP made a mistake and tried to be helpful.

I think that it's a general sign of a problem on a higher level that your assumption was that it must be either a bad joke, *or* offensive, but not any other possibility. It's probably better for the community over all if folks take a second to try and understand why things happen rather than immediately getting offended at the drop of a hat.

Besides, xxx.com is still in the example snippet itself; it's inconsistent to me that you did not also find that offensive somehow.

Anyway I've edited the post to use [reserved example domain names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606); regardless of a readers' sensitivity, those domain names *are* the appropriate ones to use in this case anyway. This is generally the type of action that should be taken if you find yourself offended by misguided example domains in the future.

Comment: +1 -> *I think that it's a general sign of a problem on a higher level that your assumption was that it must be either a bad joke, or offensive, but not any other possibility.*

Answer (score 3):

You should reject it, and if you have the time to do Reject & Edit, please do - there is more to fix here.

The question contains both the "xxx.com" and "zzz.com" adresses, but upon reading it, it seems to me that the OP really meant "zzz.com" here.

Officially, we should just Reject bad edits, and let the review process handle the rest. In practice, Reject & Edit is sometimes required to stop a bad edit from getting robo-approved.

Comment: _there is more to fix here:_ Yes, for example, at least the "Please suggest." should be removed.

Comment: Where do you draw the line for when to reject-and-edit but still copy *some* parts of the edit?  SO obviously doesn't automate the process for you, to make it harder to take credit for someone else's editing work, but there have been other cases where I felt like it was justified (to make sure the editor gets the message that their edit had major flaws, e.g. putting `Win95` in code formatting.)

Comment: ["Everyone misses something sooner or later, @Jonathan. The question is, does the suggestion make a substantive enough improvement that simply discarding it would be a waste, or is it so trivial / pointless / unhelpful that throwing it away is no great loss."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#comment783992_238039) The edit is fairly substantial (come on, who cares about missing a salutation), so Reject & Edit would be the wrong choice here -- Improve would fit.

Comment: @Peter Personally, for improve vs. reject and edit, I simply draw the line at a practical level rather than a philosophical one: Given the improvements I intend to make I just pick whichever option creates the least amount of work for me. I have faith that more often than not this also ends up reflecting the philosophically correct decision, so I just don't spend much time thinking about it from that perspective.