# What should be done about porn links in questions?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, rude-or-abusive

What would be preferable steps to take when someone posts links to porn videos in a question?

I mean, I already flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45522801/1693593) more than 3 hours ago using the option "in need of moderator intervention" assuming that would be taken care of quickly. I wrote "Porn link..." in the description which I think should suffice (?). Then I log back in later and see the post is still around (at the moment of this writing).

I seem to be the only one down-voting the post at this point in time, and of course, in that respect voting to close would not be very effective.

Me thinking, at least for the sake of the minors visiting the site.

Comment: Mod flags can take a while, they have a lot to handle. Personally I find it not so urgent because it's not actively linked... but you can always edit the reference out. (Edit: ah, no, it shows up when you run the snippet... that's not ok. Editing it out now.)

Comment: While this is a decent question that could stay without the link, I do this for things where users post API keys. Edit the post, then flag the post for a mod, in your comments, ask post edit history to be cleared.Gone from page view, and gone from history, while the question can still stand. Anything trying to repro just need to use their own mp4 here, i.e, edit the url to `http://www.example.com/video.mp4`.

Comment: *A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.* comes to mind.

Comment: Minors, the significant portion of users who view the site at work, anyone who just doesn't want to see that sort of thing. Honestly, I find it really bizarre that this showed up in an otherwise normal question. I opened this post expecting it to be about spam or vandalism. Instead it's someone who just felt like including porn in their question.

Comment: Related: [Changing all instances of “xxx.com” to “example.com” in edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255166/changing-all-instances-of-xxx-com-to-example-com-in-edits)

Answer (score 47):

Adult content in code snippets is not ok.

But given that it was clearly not done maliciously, it doesn't necessarily need moderator intervention. You could just handle this yourself - edit out the link and leave a comment, asking the OP to provide a link to a more acceptable video (or even edit one in yourself if you feel like it).

Don't see what else a moderator could/would do.

There's arguably no call to remove the link from the revision history in this case, which would need a developer anyway and is done only in very very rare urgent cases.

Comment: Mods *can* scrape history, but we do that to only remove sensitive info.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of a tricky one. As K3N says, a custom mod flag would really be necessary, because the porn was so easy to miss. On the other hand, we get a lot of custom mod flags, and they take a long time to process, which means the content would be visible for a lot longer than is desirable. The best way to handle this is to edit the offending content out *immediately*. If you go through their profile and see that there's a history of this, then you should *also* flag for mod attention with a custom flag. We promise we'll get to it when we get to it. :-)

Comment: Now also I could just see the edit history and fetch the porn link. Even better, rollback the edit and voila ... then how come *it doesn't necessarily need moderator intervention.*?

Comment: @Rahul  I don't see how that link, hidden in the editing history, could ever end up doing harm to someone given that there is a zillion megatons of porn available 24/7 through your friendly neighbourhood search engine.

Comment: @Pekka웃, well that's true but in essence it's simply not ethical to add a porn link to the question

Comment: @Rahul agreed. That's why we edit out the link and tell the OP that it's not acceptable. If they do it *repeatedly*, that's a different matter. That is very likely grounds for an infinite suspension.

Answer (score -25):

I'd recommend booting the user from the site, or suspending for a period of time. Once people start posting porn links, it's not difficult to imagine that underage content would be posted as well and in that case, Stack Overflow would become legally liable for the content. Nobody wants that. So, I know it sounds draconian, but from a liability point of view, lawyers need to see that concrete and effective action was taken.

Just my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I think you're right about that, a sensible user will not do it, and although sex can be a wonderful thing, SO not the place for that. I believe it was a troll

Comment: Going from 1 person seemingly innocent posting a question with a link to loads to people posting underage content is quite the jump...

Comment: @Ian: The question wasn't what we should do about what one person has already done in the past. The question was" What would be preferable steps to take when someone posts links to porn videos in a question?"   OP mentions nothing about a seemingly innocent person or even that this should be based around 'a good guy.' I read it as a blanket question about how to safely moderate the site for the future, especially since there are no age restrictions on SO. 
If people are posting porn links, malicious spammers aren't far behind.

Comment: I actually do agree with a temporary ban in these specific cases. This is not a case of for example treating the site like a forum or your personal helpdesk; if that happens then giving people the benefit of the doubt that they will better their ways after small content-oriented moderation actions is fine. But if you manage to post a link to pron or something else that is not for all ages and minds, you're either testing boundaries or are incredibly careless. Either way an immediate temp ban to think about your actions seems a very reasonable response to me.

Comment: @Andrew I was replying to the answer

Comment: @Ian, then how is someone innocently posting porn?

Comment: @Andrew It's a technical question that relates to video, and the video in question happens to be pornagraphic.  It's not "innocent" in that it's an accident that they linked to porn (although someone *could* post the wrong link by accident) but rather that they intentionally posted porn because they wanted to ask a programming question about it, not because they were spamming links for money or just trying to troll people.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it @Servy . Spot on as to what I meant.