# How to handle NSFW profile links?

Tags: discussion

[This user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8312766/t33n) profile link is very [NSFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NSFW#Adjective). What should I do when I find things like this?

I tried looking for a chat room to bring it up in, but didn't know what room to look for.

I also tried looking for guidance here on meta, but wasn't able to find anything with what search terms my filter doesn't block. (Ironic it didn't catch the profile link.)

Comment: Well, avoid clicking on them at work for starters.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah, you're telling me. No company filter is bullet proof, I guess. =P

Comment: I'd say flag one of the OP's post with a custom mod flag explaining the situation. If the OP has not posts yet, flag a random one with a custom mod flag and point them to the offense profile.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks, done.

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285204/flag-user-profile

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Users can manually edit porn links out of questions, but only a moderator can modify another user's profile.

Comment: And yet 4 hours later, it's still there...

Comment: Our average handling time on flags is slightly more than 4 hours, @SandPiper. Custom flags like this take a bit longer than, say, "spam" flags. It is gone now. We appreciate the patience. :-)

Comment: @Steven I would agree, except this post is not and has never been closed as a duplicate of any question that talked about posts. Both duplicate targets talk about user profiles, exactly as this question does. The only place porn links in questions are mentioned is Christian Gollhardt's answer.

Comment: nsfw profile of a user named "t33n". And I'm 12 hours late. WHY DID YOU NOT SEND ME AN EMERGENCY FAX?!?!

Answer (score 7):

Related: [What should be done about porn links in questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354544/what-should-be-done-about-porn-links-in-questions)

> Adult Content is not ok on Stack Overflow.

Since you are not able to edit the profile of another user, you should flag a post of this user for moderators attention and explain that the profile link has adult content.

Comment: What can be done if a user does not have any posts though?

Comment: Not sure, maybe flag one of your own posts for moderators attention with a link to the user profile. @Justastudent

Comment: Good idea, @Christian, might be worth including in the answer.