# How to handle good edits to unsalvageable posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, edits

Not based on any post or edit in particular.

A lot of bad posts have lesser issues that can be corrected with editing, such as grammar, poorly worded titles, poor tagging and lack of code formatting. Hence, there are also lots of edits that fix these issues. They are mostly obvious improvements to the posts, but no amount of grammar clean-up can save a post that's off-topic or very unclear.

I can sort of see the point of fixing the post as much as possible, but it's still ultimately unproductive as the posts are going to get closed/deleted soon anyway. I believe encouraging users to focus on posts that can be helped would be a better idea. In addition, as far as I know edits bump posts, which isn't exactly what I'd want to do with a poor post. Which leaves us with the question...

**Should grammar, formatting and similar edits to clearly unsalvageable posts be accepted or rejected when reviewing?**

Comment: It would be really confusing to reject a good edit and I see no improvement to do so. And if a new user for instance at least learns to format the next question properly, something was accomplished.

Comment: @juergend, I think I listed the benefits in my question: it discourages people from wasting their time editing posts beyond our help and doesn't bump posts that just should be closed.

Comment: Speaking of bumping - most edits to poor questions are made the minute they are posted.

Comment: If the post is not salvageable I typically reject with a custom message saying that the post should be closed.

Comment: But when the post gets deleted, the editor looses his rep. Don't you think that this is enough of a deterrent?

Comment: The very definition of an unsalvageable post means that good edits to such a post are at worst impossible, and at best pointless.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227320/how-should-i-handle-an-edit-review-on-a-post-i-am-going-to-flag-for-deletion/227321#227321)

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Is "don't polish turds" a valid edit rejection reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155961) The terminology comes from http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77683/

Comment: I'll often edit a post to be able to read it (poor code formatting) - when I've done that I'll still save it even if it's then apparent it's not a useful question - if nothing else it makes evaluating whether to VTC faster/easier for others. If I didn't have the rep I'd still do so, as there's no guidance not to (e.g. a warning: this post has 3 close votes. Are you about to waste your time?)

Answer (score 15):

You'd be amazed at how many posts *can* be salvaged, if someone cares enough to *re-write them almost entirely*.

Of course, most folks don't want to do that. But sometimes several editors can muster the effort between them. If they want to give it a shot, and their efforts aren't without some benefit to the post, then might as well let them...

Note that if they fail and the post is deleted, credit for the edits gets deleted with it.

Comment: Now, the fundamental question: is it worth even trying? Popular answer: no.

Comment: Well, that's a personal decision. I'd encourage folks to spend time on areas where it'll do the most good, but to each their own.

Answer (score 7):

I think an edit should be judged on its own merit. Did it improve the post? If it did, it should be approved. Seeing other people correctly edit your questions (and even answers) serve as a good lesson in *how to write* Q&As here.

Comment: Not every edit that improves the post should be approved. Too minor edits are a valid reason to reject.

Comment: @kviiri Minor edits don't really improve the post, or we wouldn't reject such edits.

Comment: What do you mean "don't really improve"? I think fixing any typo, for example, improves a post, but it's still a too minor edit if it neglects fixing other flaws in the post such as unformatted code.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253331/3198973

Comment: Well yeah, that's exactly my point. We don't want edits, **even ones that improve posts**, that still leave behind huge flaws. Which is exactly why I'm asking this.

Comment: I would argue that an edit that leaves behind huge issues **does not** improve the post. We're arguing semantics here @kviiri.

Comment: So you mean unsalvageable posts shouldn't be edited as they can't be improved to meet the site's standards?

Comment: No. I mean judge the edit based on its own merit.