# What to do about unsalvageable questions in the Suggested Edits review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

The Suggested Edits Review queue is for a large part filled with unsalvageable questions of the type "Do my work", "Fix my code" or questions that make you think Google is on strike. Mostly the Suggested Edit is not bad, but by far not good enough to make the questions even remotely acceptable. I have read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256078/how-to-handle-good-edits-to-unsalvageable-posts) that clearly states that the edits should be judged on their own merit and that the editor will lose the +2 rep (s)he gained if the question is closed or deleted.

However, that doesn't stop the low-rep users from editing, probably because some bad questions slip trough the system and don't get deleted or just because they don't know (I didn't). And I think this is wasting a lot of time of reviewers.

My questions are:
**Does anyone know how many questions (percentage) get closed/deleted after review?

Shouldn't we try to block at least a part of this flow?**

Comment: "Do my work", "Fix my code", and "Google is on strike" are reasons to downvote a question, not to close it. (Unless it also fits one of close reasons, such as being a duplicate). This isn't what "unsalvageable" means. There's a difference between "I don't want to answer this" and "it's impossible to answer this".

Comment: The same rules as always apply: don't polish turds. If the edits aren't improving anything substantial, and the post is doomed, then reject them. It is unclear to me what you are actually asking here. Are you just trying to ascertain the extent of the damage, in preparation of announcing your clever solution? Why bury the lead? What do you propose to do differently?

Comment: @CodyGray I asked the question because I thought the 'damage' would be much bigger than 5% (although deleted questions were left out of the SEDE query, so there is an uncertainty) and I couldn't think of a clever solution myself. No hidden agenda there! And I learned from the answer/comments: not approve to easy, certainly not when the question is closed.

Comment: Discovering that you are wasting your life in review is the next natural stage of SO usage.  The company has figured out a while ago that the odds that somebody comes back to ask yet another crappy question are the lowest when *nobody* responds to the previous question.  That's not good for business, so these review queues are a counter-measure.  They count on them being able to dump just about any box of Legos and volunteers forever showing up to clean up.  Workaround is *very* simple, just don't review.  It is your life, you decide how to spend it.

Comment: @RamenChef that question focuses on the edit itself, not the *question*.

Answer (score 13):

> Does anyone know how many questions (percentage) get closed/deleted after review?

A [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/) might be able to answer this. At least for closed questions; for deleted questions it will be harder. [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/604155/number-of-suggested-edits-on-questions) shows a little over 7500 questions with approved suggested edits in a week; according to [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/604145/questions-which-were-closed-after-a-suggested-edit-was-approved), about 5% of these were on questions which were later closed.

> Shouldn't we try to block at least a part of this flow?

If you encounter an unsalvageable question during a Suggested Edits review, *by all means* open the question in another window and flag it for closure. (This will not remove the edit from the queue, though.) The previous data shows this doesn't happen too often, so unless you have a very elegant solution, it's not worth trying.

Comment: I'm afraid flagging it for closure doesn't help, I've just encountered a closed question that is still in the SE review queue (perhaps that is a solution, removing those?).

Comment: Well, *sometimes* a closed question can be salvaged by a suggested edit.

Comment: Yeah, but the emphasis on sometimes is justly. I'm talking about the unsalvageable ones, which are many.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the question is closed, approving the suggested edit will push the question into the reopen queue. This will only happen once, so if the suggested edit doesn't make the question on-topic then everyone involved is robbing the OP of their one best chance of getting the question reopened.

Comment: @TinyGiant Now I'm confused. While reviewing, I don't see if a question is closed or not. So if I follow the advise of Shog9 (moderator!) in the linked meta-answer, and approve the edit, this robs the OP of his change of getting it reopened. That can't be intented, is it?!

Comment: @RHA it isn't intended but it is a side effect. If you're already stepping out of the queue to close the question (as per the guidance in this answer), you can see if it is closed or not. then make the appropriate decision. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @TinyGiant as an interesting sidenote, we now have a hat which encourages editing closed questions in order to open them.

Comment: @Glorfindel which is always a good idea anyways, right?