# Edit hunting and possible reputation farming - how should I react?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, edits

Occasionally the suggested edits queue on Stack Overflow gets flooded with edit suggestions by the same user. A few minutes ago there were ~5 suggested edits by the same user who apparently searched for posts with "conect" in the title and corrected them to "connect".
I don't know for sure if they were edit-hunting, but the edited posts were across a wide variety of topics and date ranges.

In one or two of the edits they actually improved formatting and did more than simply correct a typo in the title (which I'm fine with approving), but most of the edits were simply correcting the typo in an otherwise fine question.

**So, my question:** Should the "edit-hunting" nature of the user's suggestions have any bearing on the acceptance or rejection of the edits?

Personally, I'm a bit torn. The rapid succession of edits, all correcting the same issue on multiple posts, suggests to me that the user was attempting to farm reputation. This is a tactic that I imagine is discouraged by the Stack Overflow community.

On the other hand, most of the edits themselves were valid and - individually - probably deserve being approved. Approving the edits, however, seems to imply that the user's actions are acceptable.

Comment: Reject, then weep and accept that the next 3 people will approve. These edit are not made for the greater good.

Comment: Reject, maybe see whether it gets accepted anyway and if it is no borderline-case alert a moderator with a custom flag. Just **be sure to concisely and fully** explain why you flagged and who of the approvers you think failed the turing-test.

Comment: This whole situation seems to be a case of the reputation tail wagging the quality dog. If a tiny, tiny edit makes a question even a little bit better, why not allow it to be approved? Just don't count reputation for trivial edits.

Comment: Somewhat related: [“too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Comment: I'm more and more convinced that edits shouldn't bring reputation. After all, users don't stop editing when it doesn't bring them rep anymore.

Comment: I'd rather people got a bit of rep for minor edits than spelling errors being left on the site. Bear in mind that after a certain score, edits no longer earn rep anyway. That said, it's discouraged to do a set of them in a short time frame, as it pushes a lot of old content to the front page.

Comment: There are some "minor" edits that are worthwhile, but giving rep for edits really begs for abuse -- and we get it.  I ran across one about 5 minutes ago where a tag was deleted, checked the user, saw that he'd done a dozen edits in the past half-hour or so.  In the context of the question the tag sort of made sense, and I'm sure it was picked at random as being something that no one would care about.

Comment: What's wrong with "simply correcting the typo in an otherwise fine question"? Seems like a good thing, to me. The problem would be if it were simply correcting the typo, while the question had several other problems with it that were ignored.

Comment: If a user who doesn't need review makes the edit, it is good (having words spelled correctly, especially in the title, helps searchability).  I'm not sure that such a simple edit warrants a 2 point rep bounty.  If you want some entertainment, search for `javascipt` (about 1500 results on SO this evening).  Note that correcting it would, in some cases, pervert the question; the question hinges on the misspelling.  Granted, such questions could be closed with 'trivial typo', but fixing the misspelling would be a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Obviously, SO's goal is to be a quality content site. Quality content means hard work to some extent, like editing and reviewing. On the other hand, some edits are considered as "too minor" and thus, the reasoning of reviewers is, that even **correct** edits should be rejected, because they are minorish.

Now please stop a moment and think about what we are doing here. We sacrifice correctness and quality to an arbitrary limit of minimum edited characters. But which of the two actions is leading us towards the goal of a quality site, and which is not?

It is not the editors' fault if so many people can't spell "connect" right. So why do you want to punish the editor? Because he recognizes and takes advantage of the arbitrage opportunity to earn 100 points for 50 accepted edits? If that's the main problem, limit the number of points earned through edits per day.

While searching and correcting these things, **these editors try to be a part of the solution.** Earning a few points along the way seems not such a bad thing to me. After all, that's how the gamification aspect of SO works: **One earns reputation and badges (and sometimes funny hats) by doing good things.** That's the whole damn point why we have these things.

If anyone needs to be punished at all, start yelling at those people who make accidental typos, or can barely speak English and still want to ask questions on SO. Of course, that's a bad idea too, for obvious reasons. So we have to somehow deal with the bad quality that comes in and needs to be revised.

If reviewing a lot of similar corrections bothers anyone enough that this person wants to "*do something about it*"—not for a technical reason, but just because it bothers him/her—then it should be questioned, whether or not this person should do those reviews at all?

Bottom line: The last to be blamed is the editor. He has only found an efficient way to locate and fix similar problems quickly. Anybody could have easily done the same.

---

PS: I'm talking about useful edits only. Edits that don't change anything to the better should be rejected, no matter how big or small. Period.

Comment: Overall I agree with you, but if someone edits a post just to fix "connect", while leaving other mistakes behind, it should get rejected as too minor. For SO to get better, we shouldn't be creating piles of pointless work for everyone. If some nutto corrects 9999 posts only to correct the spelling of a single word, there's a risk that people will get fed up with edit reviewing and stop doing it. That's no way to improve the site.

Comment: However there we people pointing out that there is always someone faster to approve this stuff. I don't see this as a problem. If people stop approving these edits because it doesn't justify the work then the editors will stop editing them and next time try to add more value. Simple enough.

Comment: I agree with your main point 100% - I don't care much if someone is editing "to farm rep" or not - good edits should be welcome/encouraged, and there's a cap on edit rep anyway.  The bigger conflict is that tons of trivial edits bump the question to the front page over and over again.  But you can't just suppress that, as part of the reason is that edits need review to ensure they're not problematic...

Comment: My impression is that SO should be a *useful* site.  A good degree of correctness is an important component of utility, but so is a low noise level.  These essentially meaningless edits raise the noise level significantly.

Comment: If there's actually something wrong (even if it's just a typo), and the edit actually fixes it, then ipso facto it is not a "meaningless edit".

Comment: JensG, I like your suggestion: "limit the number of points earned through edits per day". It's a minimalist change that might take a while to impact the behavior of those involved, but I think it would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 56):

I'm of the opinion that spelling - especially in the title - is important.

The best option is to hit the *Improve* button, make the extra required corrections, then make sure you uncheck the *this edit was helpful* box. This way the question gets the attention it needs and the person who suggested the edit doesn't get the credit (rep) for it.

Comment: Good luck with that one; by the time you've improved it, it was already accepted by three other people.  I can't tell you how many times that's happened to me.  I don't care how fast you type, *they're faster*

Comment: @meagar - glad to know I'm not the only one who does that, or at least, used to, before I just gave up on the queue entirely.  Still, I've been beaten to the punch even by doing that.  There's just too many 2K and 3K users who really don't get how the site works.

Comment: These things people are ridiculous and shouldn't be needed. SO needs to bloody fix the rep farming through edits. Until they do, they should disable all rep for editing. We can't have all these weird meta-games going on in the background, they are not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables and user833115: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve

Comment: Honestly not a big fan of that checkbox; if you don't think an edit was helpful, *just reject it*. Leave "improve" for edits that are good but which you can make *better*. That checkbox is an artifact of a time when edits might sit for hours in the queue; there's rarely a good reason to use it these days (at least on Stack Overflow).

Comment: "spelling is important". I agree. "If it is worth writing, it is worth writing right"

Answer (score 27):

If you believe that the edit actually improves the question (I do), just vote to accept it. They did some (trivial) amount of work to improve this site and so they receive (a trivial amount of) reputation for that. I don't see anything wrong with that. And the fact that they did this multiple times in a quick succession doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 20):

No, the "edit-hunting" nature of the user's suggestions should not have any bearing on the acceptance or rejection of the edits.

Don't let "perfect" get in the way of "better". Any improvement—however incremental—is welcome, IMHO. If someone wants to target a specific imperfection, why stop them?

Comment: well, then why do we have the *reject as too minor*?

Comment: Now *THAT* is an excellent question. My goal is excellence, not perfection...perhaps I'm lazy.

Comment: The problem with minor edits is that they still bump a question to the front page, driving other content down. Also they eat up the time of at least 3 reviewers.

Comment: Pulling on a thread...but why does an edit bump a question to the front page? Is the listing sorted by date/time of last activity, and an edit counts as an activity? If so, maybe it shouldn't...

Comment: @JeromyFrench Yes, edits count as activity.  Edits are basically the primary source of activity, along with new answers.  It allows users to recognize that a post has been changed so that they can re-evaluate it.  Not bumping posts when edited is basically the same as removing the entire activity feed and limiting question views to exclusively posted date and search.

Comment: @S.L.Barth AFAIK there has never been a shortage of reviewers, so do not be concerned about that.

Comment: @Tshepang: There's a severe shortage of reviewers who put in effort .

Comment: Has there ever been a suggestion to add a 'minor edit - approve' button to the suggested edits review?  It would (theoretically) approve an edit but would not actually bump it to the first page, and would seemingly resolve the issue of rejecting helpful but minor edits.  I suppose it could be accompanied by a lesser amount of rep gained (say +1)

Comment: @BenVoigt you mean the effort to do quality reviews, as in there's too many robo-reviewers?

Answer (score 5):

Can we trust a search engine to yield up searches for "connect" if, indeed, it is spelled as "conect"?  A good one will, particularly if it's built upon Lucene.  "Connect" and "conect" might coalesce.  But what about "contemplate" and "comtenprate"?  In some languages, there is a natural confusion between "l" and "r", "m" and "n."

Spelling is important. Period. If it's "too minor" now, then what was it when we were all in school? I seem to recall that it wasn't too minor then.

**We should also bear in mind that there are many foreign users of SO for whom English is not their native language.  Improper spelling hinders their ability to learn the language properly.**

Answer (score 3):

Given the [not-so-recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543/217863) to the edit review queue, I think the best option for a lot of these "rep farming" edits is the shiny new **"Reject and Improve"** feature.

If the editor is only searching for one word spelling corrections, or other minor errors, and leaving other obvious problems untouched; clicking **"Reject and Improve"** will deny the inattentive editor their precious unicorn dollars and will allow you to correct the rest of the problems with the post.

Answer (score 0):

Reject as too minor. Unless the user is fixing other issues in the post, it qualifies for a reject.

Comment: It'll still go through, there are enough robo-reviewers to basically ensure this

Answer (score 0):

I am curious what would happen if no awards were given for edits and everything was made just for the quality of the site.
Would the "hunters" continue to hunt down posts to track typos or format code.
Furthermore the whole down voting thing is not doing any good,if a question,post is inadequate then it would be better to get transferred to another part of the site e.g. " bad quality questions/posts" instead of getting the punishment of down vote .
Even in the dirt you can find diamonds.
Also i do find the correct spelling important but not the reason for offensive behavior

Comment: Or perhaps, instead of giving 2 rep for every suggested edit by a user under 2k reputation, which stops only when the user gets the privilege to edit directly, we could not allow any account to earn more than 250 rep through editing, ever.  Then they'd have to also earn reputation other ways in order to unlock privileges.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Do you know what would really make a difference...if only the posters can down vote and also moderators after carefully inspecting the answers....it seems that we have a modern witch hunt where everyone who managed to gather some points is in pursuit of others either by editing or by down voting.

Comment: that would be terrible. Posters ask questions because they don't understand, and are not in a good position to recognize flawed answers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt maybe....when a poster down votes (if they had the privilege) they should 110% sure that the answer "deserves" a down vote....i bet that you would see a definite decrease in down votes....