# Edit to add example rejected. How can I improve?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I found a particular Q/A combo to be useful though partially incomplete and wanted to improve the existing answer.

Here is the [topic in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315347/invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-incomplete-type-sdl-window) and my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5118258).

The guidelines presented during the edit process (emphasis mine):

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed. We
>   welcome **all constructive edits, but please make them substantial**.
>   Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

The edit was rejected by all three reviewers as "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." I'm fairly certain that the code I added works (copy/paste from my source).

Did I do something wrong? What should I do better next time? Should I have created my own answer for future readers?

Comment: Somewhere else on meta (sorry don't have a link) I read that you are not supposed to do substantial edits, that is edits, that change the question / answer in a major way. This contradiction to the text you quoted always left me puzzled.

Comment: @zespri The **substantial** piece applies to the quality of edits: if you're going to change a couple letters of the post, it may not be worth the edit. However, if I understand you correctly, you're referring to the policy whereby an edit to a post should leave the meaning of the post intact because the OP should always be respected. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/)'s a discussion on whether it's better to leave posts grammatically incorrect or fix them with supposedly "too minor" edits.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your edit should have been a comment to the existing post. That is to mean it was something not intended by the OP answerer and was an addendum from you. Edits are meant to improve posts while remaining along the lines of the original meaning.

Your edit stepped over that line and that's why your edit was rightly rejected.

If the code example is substantial then one could also create a new answer on the question and reference the previous answer. This can be done with a "to expand upon X's answer" then add you code example.

As [@R](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) said one might not want their name to be attributed to a content direction that was different from what they originally intended. This is why comments are **required** to mind the OP's intent.

Such an example should stand separately. As comments are to be ephemeral, if it's meant to be substantial then it should be placed in a new answer.

Comment: It would be better to include my addendum in a separate answer then? The assumed similarity on my part was because the OP specifically mentioned that "you'll need a custom deleter" but didn't provide an example.

Comment: @vmrob i'm honestly not sure. Maybe others can weigh in, but I think it would depend on how substantial it is. I have seen people start their answer with "to expand upon X's answer" and they have been well received. I'm not sure about this case however

Comment: As long as you properly attribute ideas or code used you can do what you wish with another answer. (Obviously, subject to removal if it breaks the guidelines)

Comment: Seriously? A code example in a comment? You've *got* to be kidding.

Comment: What @secretformula said. This kind of follow-up answer is appropriate here. Editing your code into somebody else's answer is NOT appropriate because if there are bugs, bad style, or other quality issues in the code it reflects badly on the person who wrote the answer (and potentially on their reputation). Personally I don't care about my numeric reputation in this area, but I'm usually quite unhappy to find an edit that makes me look like I'm recommending code that has bugs/issues which I make a point of trying to educate people against.

Comment: @zespri See new edit

Comment: I understand what everyone is saying here and I'm glad the edit was rejected. After commenting, I exposed a typo in the original answer that *entirely* changed the intent of the answer to me. Once that was resolved, it was clear that we had two different interpretations. Creating a new, but different, answer turned out to be the most appropriate way to convey my advice to future readers.

Answer (score 7):

When a casual reviewer sees such a large volume of text being altered and code being added, it is pretty natural for them to reject it outright, without any further consideration. Most of the times, the people reviewing the edit will have no knowledge about the particular domain, and wouldn't be able to tell if the edit was actually good or not. Code changes are generally frowned up on, and are usually rejected unless they're fixing an obvious typo such as a missing semicolon, opening brace etc.

In this case, I think your edit changed the meaning of the post too much, and was substantial enough that it could be posted as an answer on its own. I'd have rejected it too, but perhaps with a more helpful rejection reason like "*This edit changes the meaning of the post too much; please post it as a separate answer.*".

I understand why you'd think it is *not* okay to post incomplete answers, but as *secretformula* notes, partial answers are perfectly alright. To be safe, you can just mention that it is not a complete answer, and is attempting to fix something in another answer. [Similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036553/1438393) [have been](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22911776/1438393) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579890/1438393) [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239246/1438393) and they were well received. The only thing you need to make sure is that the answer should be able to stand on its own — if your answer needs to use some parts of an existing answer, feel free to quote it. It should be okay as long as you provide attribution to the original author. This way, your answer can stand along *even* if the original answer gets deleted.

**TLDR:** If you think it the problem is something minor, leave a comment notifying the original answerer to address the problem. If not, post it as a separate answer (make sure it answers the original question, too).

Comment: `...fixing an obvious typo such as a missing semicolon, opening brace etc.` I have rejected edits of this sort mainly because is this a typo or could be the origin of the problem? Of course one should read and see if you can determine that but personally I feel that these type of edits should be done by the person asking the question. It is easy to point out a typo in a comment.

Comment: @Lynda: I'm talking about answers. Questions should be left as-is.

Comment: Ah, apologies. =>

Comment: One thing I also need to understand (and I'm getting used to it!) is that comments on old answers continue to pick up attention from the original author. I'm not used to that sort of thing!