# Quality Assurance for Edit Approval

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

### Edit

Apparently these edits are too small. Then I have more questions:

- Why does the system allow this?
- Why was this changed and why are there points given out for these edits, if they are in fact too small?

Language tags and framework/library tags are not equal. Adding or removing these tags can change the post audience and even the way it's formatted. Why is this fact completely disregarded in the above "too small" rule?

Not to mention, apparently "code formatting" is a small change. Without proper code formatting, a post is basically useless and unreadable and sometimes may even contain hidden code.

---

I'm quite active on SO and I make a good bit of edits, though I still don't have over 2k repuation. I've noticed that the ONLY time I have edits rejected are when I get 3 users who have sometimes upwards of 3x the number of rejects as accepts.

I know when I look at the review tab, there are QA checks. Do these QA checks exist for edits as well?

```
user1 has approved 382 edit suggestions and rejected 362 edit suggestions
user2 has approved 276 edit suggestions and rejected 425 edit suggestions
user3 has approved 80 edit suggestions and rejected 34 edit suggestions
user4 has approved 660 edit suggestions and rejected 371 edit suggestions
```

No surprise that this edit was rejected by user1, user2, and user4 for `This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.`

The [edit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5295714) was adding a `java` tag to a question that was only tagged with `spring` `maven` and `spring-boot`. Adding the java tag is completely relevant to the question  and will make the question available to thousands more followers. When I look at the user's histories, none of them have any experience with Java at all.

My submitted my edit a second time with a more passive aggressive comment that further explained it `Java is the primary tag for this question. This is a Java question. I added that tag.` and it was approved. The previous comment simply said "added java tag" because I felt that it was self explanatory.

```
user5 has approved 165 edit suggestions and rejected 3 edit suggestions
user6 has approved 386 edit suggestions and rejected 185 edit suggestions
user7 has approved 142 edit suggestions and rejected 11 edit suggestions
```

Comment: Unless the missing Java tag was the *only* thing wrong with the post, rejecting an edit that adds a single missing edit as "too minor" can be considered OK, and even then a tag-only change might still be "too minor".

Comment: I assume you're talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5295714) suggestion?

Comment: @user3580294 Even if it opens it up to a exponentially larger audience? If this is the case, then why did they allow this feature? I believe I remember at one point that adding a single tag was not accepted by the system, therefore could not be rejected by the community. Edit: yes that one. I wasn't sure if it was acceptable to link it directly.

Comment: I'm not in the position to give an authoritative answer to that, unfortunately. Looking at the question, I don't *think* there are too many other things that need to be fixed, so I'm not too sure what the correct thing to do in this case would be. Edit: It probably is OK to link a review directly, especially since the context of the post's contents would be pretty important.

Comment: Also, I think you should focus less on the users reviewing your edits and more on the types of edits you are making. Some people here would think that those reviewers rejecting more edits than they are approving are doing *much* better than the reviewers with their stats the other way around, due to the perceived falling quality of edits and reviewers here. Also, it's not too clear what you want us to do about those "high-reject-rate" users. Is that something you want to prevent?

Comment: @user3580294 I have 158:15 I admit that a few have been rejected fairly, maybe half, but the ones that have not been fall into this question. There has been at least 2 other times where I did not explain what I did in my comment and they only saw the minor edits to fill up the char limit (such as capitlization) where as the rest was putting code into code blocks which can be pretty major, especially when important lines were completely hidden.

Comment: @user3580294 `want us to do about those "high-reject-rate"` Sort of a 2 part question. **1** I don't have 2k so I don't know if QA exists and **2** Yes. I'm not sure what exactly. **3** And I guess this one was added when you mentioned that a single tag is considered too little. When not all tags are created equal. Adding `Java` to this question was non-trivial. Yes it's a single tag, but it's also a very big change to the question's visibility. If I added any of the other 3 to the question, then that would be understandably too little.

Comment: A rather large percentage of your edits, looking through your recent history, are improper edits that *should* have been rejected.  Sadly, there is a gigantic proportion of reviewers that are pretty terrible at reviewing and approve most everything, so your bad edits have been approved.

Comment: @Servy I make a lot of single tag edits. Wasn't this not accepted by the system once upon a time ago? I don't make the tag edits for the points and I actually feel bad for receiving them. I have been here for over 2yrs with 645 active days. It should be pretty obvious the points are not my concern. :)

Comment: @mawburn And the majority of those edits are too minor.  You should be making more substantial edits when you edit a post.  If you know that what you're doing is wrong then *why are you continuing to do it?*

Comment: @Servy Helping out the posts making relevant changes to get the users the answers they deserve. Whether they are considered minor changes  or not. Isn't that the point of it all? Tag changes make a big impact. Points or no points, I would still make the changes.

Comment: @mawburn You'll find that there is no real consensus among users concerning the "too minor" reject reason. Or many other community moderation actions. Such is the nature of the beast.

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at your edit history so I can't tell you whether those edits in general were minor, but the gist of what I've read on Meta is that if you're still in the have-to-have-your-edits-reviewed phase, the edits are expected to be pretty substantial, fixing multiple things in a post. I'll admit, I didn't follow that when I started out, but I do try to let people know when I can at this point. Code formatting *can* be minor, depending on exactly what you're doing, but if you're digging hidden things out, then it's probably OK. (continued)

Comment: @mawburn Not quite certain what you mean by QA, but there *are* audits for suggested edits (which are usually pitifully easy). To be honest, I'm not sure if high reject rates are necessarily a bad thing; it could be just that that user sees bad edits, or has higher standards for what is a "bad" edit. As AirThomas said, not everyone agrees on what's "too minor", especially for cases like this. Yeah, [tag:Java] is pretty darn big, but as I said before I'm not in the position to give you an authoritative answer about that particular part of your question.

Comment: Well this was pointless. I thought SO was about helping users get answers to questions. I guess not. I am 95% sure that the system did not allow these edits at one time. It does now. I have asked that 3 times in this thread and not received a single answer or comment about that. All I get is "your edits are too minor anyway". **If this is the case, the system shouldn't allow it. Like it used to not.** There is a lot of gray area, especially since not only can tags change the audience but the way the system formats the code. A language tag is very different than a library tag.

Comment: Well, not strictly. There are other users who have been around much longer than I have that can elaborate on this more, but at least from what I've heard at times SO should be thought of more as a "repository for programming knowledge", which means that not everyone could (or should) have their questions answered. And unfortunately, I can't tell you why the system changed, because as before, I haven't been around nearly long enough to have experienced the change. Do you know if the limitation applied to those users over 2k rep too? If so, perhaps that was the reason for the change.

Comment: It was always allowed to make tag only edits. In combination with regular text edits, the edit change must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 2k thing, I've mostly been a lurker. I mostly just make small edits to make posts better here and there and report bad posts. Overall, I just enjoy reading and learning from questions.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Unfortunately, I don't get to see those. So, I don't actually know. Thank you for answering the other question, I guess I just remembered it wrong.

Comment: If anything, why are tag only edits awarded points? As I said earlier, I would make them regardless of points. New users do not know how the site works.

Comment: @mawburn Tag only edits have never been disallowed by the system.  Once upon a time you only needed 500 rep to make tag only edits without review, not 2k.  This additional privilege, was revoked due to the volume of inappropriate tag edits by 500-2k rep users.  Now those tag only edits get reviewed, an since the review system rubber stamps most suggested edits regardless of their appropriateness, inappropriate tag edits *still* get made and applied by 500-2k rep users.

Comment: Vandalizing your own question by removing all of the question's content through edits is not appropriate.

Comment: @Servy It is not vandalism. I flagged it for removal. Votes have proven this question to not be acceptable for this site.

Comment: @mawburn Yes, it is vandalism to edit a question to remove all of it's content.  You're certainly welcome to flag it for removal, and in all likelihood that flag will be declined.  The votes indication that the readers primarily don't agree with the position you're taking in your question.  That doesn't mean that the question should be removed.  Keeping it around, so that other can see that the community disagrees with this sentiment, adds value.

Comment: @Servy I don't know if this is asking too much, but you mentioned that "a large majority" of my edits were inappropriate. Could you point out a few? I have felt that most were appropriate, but I admit to making a few mistakes. I would not think that "a large majority" would be considered inappropriate. Many times I have found little else to correct. [I did find your post, which brings a lot into context though](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/253330#253330)

Comment: @Servy [Such as this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24742057/revisions). By the black and white definition of "too minor", it is not right. But in the context of the question, the question has more to do with SQL than PHP or Cron and did not specify which SQL. I only removed Cron because I was already there making the change to add SQL, though I guess in retrospect I guess I should have left it because it doesn't hurt the question.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to figure out what I should be doing and what I shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @mawburn http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5278543 - changed the code in a question, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5278415 - this is not an algorithms question, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5082030 - super minor edit while also leaving other problems with the post, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5094082 - formatting non-code as code, and also not addressing other formatting issues in the post

Comment: @Servy Awesome thank you. I will try to make better judgments in the future. In the first one though... I'm not sure if you're talking about the `====` or the `c:/Desktop/BRUK/utilities/` stuff, but I did not change that. I stepped away for a second and that was included in with my edit for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think looking at the reject rates for your reviewers is a red herring. Your sample size is tiny, and it would be hard to avoid confirmation bias when you're picking observations based on events you've noticed/remembered.

The specific example you give doesn't even look that bad, to me; the first and fourth users you show have more accepts than rejects, so why is it "no surprise" that they rejected your edit? Based purely on the numbers, the expectation is that they would approve.

I think the important message for you to take away from this experience is that the suggested edit summary is not just an afterthought. You tried again, being more explicit about your rationale for tagging, and your edit was approved. Users pay attention to what you put in this box, and if your edit *is* very brief, it's all the more important for you to be explicit.

You saw this as being "passive aggressive" but I would counter that your second comment was simply *sufficiently explicit to convince the reviewers* that the edit was needed, while your first was not. Sounds like a winning strategy to me.