# Retag rejected during review as too minor edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Recently I've edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5646350) that was basically about CSS and site-building. It has the tag [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo). Unfortunately, I happened to read the description of the tag, and here it is:

> Logo is a computer programming language, created mainly for the
>   purposes of education. If you're referencing logos in the sense of
>   "corporate logos", please use the tag graphical-logo instead.

And here is description of the tag [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo):

> Logo images, e.g. corporate logos. To distinguish from the computer
>   programming language [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo).

I was in good mood, and it was quite apparent that I should retag it, to not contaminate the 'logo' section. So I did.

Here is the feedback:

> **Rejected 18 hours ago:**
>
> David Eisenstat reviewed this 18 hours ago: **Reject**
>
> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive
>   improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
>
> Rup reviewed this 18 hours ago: **Reject**
>
> An improvement - thanks - but doesn't need that tag really
>
> couling reviewed this 18 hours ago: **Approve**
>
> Rob reviewed this 18 hours ago: **Reject**
>
> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I understand that [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) is not so major and important, but if some guy tags a question [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), when the question is about some sort of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) ([php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)), none should retag it because it is too minor?

So, I decided to not spend my time and not retag anything since then, till I'm 2k+ user. So let's have one big mess on the site, because retagging is too minor.

Who is right?

Comment: There were other issues with the post: Thanks in advance, the editing markers and indentation of the css that could have been improved. You should have fixed that, too and the edit would not have been minor anymore.

Comment: @martin, thanks for your reply, but hypothetically, if we have a good question that does not need any editing except for retag, should one edit it or not?

Comment: @Mark If there was nothing else in the post that needed fixing, and it was clear that a wrongly applied tag was replaced with a correct one I would approve the edit. I can obviously not speak for everyone else though.

Comment: many would question why grapical-logo exists at all, it is such a minor tag does it really add anything useful?

Comment: Agree that graphical-logo is a tag that's at minimum not appropriate to the question.  There's nothing special in that question that makes it apply to questions about graphical logos.  Removing the logo tag would've been correct.

Comment: Mark, well done for trying. You will see my opinions on this matter are quite unpopular, but I believe that we should be improving this site. Try to keep your chin up, and please keep trying to help.

Comment: Agree with the others:  the logo tag should have been removed, not replaced with another not very useful tag like graphical-logo.

Comment: @Sammaye if such a tag is not meant to exist, shouldn't we remove it so that it doesn't catch out any more people who try to use it and get bashed by the community?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I have thought about whether I should make a burnite request

Comment: @Sammaye I must read some meta on these burninations... haven't participated in any yet, but I'm sure there are still loads of poor tags out there.

Comment: My personal inclination is to reject all pure retagging edits as "too minor", because it's not an efficient use of reviewer time.

Comment: Well that's interesting, I didn't realize that the ability to simply retag a post is gone now. It counts as an edit (suggestion) now.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I thought the rep requirement for immediate acceptance of retag (without going through suggested edit queue) is still lower than for content edits.

Comment: @BenVoigt: IIRC, it was 500 to just do a simple retag and didn't require any review.  Mark is well past 500 currently. That was happening for a while even after suggested edits was implemented. I guess I've just been out of the loop for a long while.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I think that was removed last year, but I don't see why they had to remove it.

Comment: Is it time to suggest burninating the 'graphical-logo' tag? There are 189 questions. It has two followers, and the top users list is a classic demonstration of a pointless tag — only three entries are for more than one question asked or answered.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They were right in this instance.

---

There were multiple other issues with the post. See the edit I've made to the post; https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25369648/4. I've removed [the unnecessary "TIA"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), fixed the code indentation, removed the storyline "Edits", ***and*** fixed the tags.

As I said in a [post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190608/how-do-you-review-mass-tag-edits-by-one-user/190609#190609) (see also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190663/judging-if-a-retag-is-a-minor-edit/190664#190664)):

> The thing to be careful here [when making tag edits] is that the user is fixing all substantial issues in the post. If they're editing blatantly poor posts and only fixing the tags (smearing lipstick on a pig), reject the edit for being "too minor".
>
> If however, there is little else to improve in the post, I'd "approve" it; the edits do need making; the questions are incorrectly tagged.

Don't be put off making these edits in the future; but make them as substantial as possible. Furthermore, in situations where the original tag *could* be perceived as being right at first glance (as in this [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) situation), **explicitly** state your correction in your edit summary; something along the lines of:

> [logo] is for the programming language. [graphical-logo] is for logos. Fixed tags accordingly

Comment: This is a fair argument, but it suggest that the wording of the "too minor" reject reason could be improved.  The current wording implies "the suggested edit does not significantly improve the post".  If we want the same reason to also cover "the suggested edit does not address other substantial issues with the post", that should be clearly stated.  That way, when someone like Mark gets an edit refused, he'll know that the solution is to go back and clean up the post *plus* re-tag it, instead of avoiding re-tag edits altogether.

Comment: @AmeliaBR you're completely right; open up another thread on this?

Comment: It should be noted that it's perfectly fine to retag once you have 2000 reputation (though we do much prefer it if you edit substantively) - one of the major reasons we use 'too minor' for suggested edits is because they're not substantive enough to justify using reviewers' time, so the behavior should be discouraged.

Comment: @djechlin It appears someone already has done that: [Change the wording on the “too minor” suggested edit reject message to indicate that most errors must be corrected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199342/248334), from October 2013.  Nothing much seems to have happened; the only answer suggests that leaving things vague allows greater flexibility, but I don't find that convincing.

Answer (score 8):

I do not believe that retagging is too minor. It adds major value to the question.

To quote from the quote in Matt's answer:

> If however, there is little else to improve in the post, I'd "approve" it; the edits do need making; the questions are incorrectly tagged.

From what I can see, there is little else to improve in that post.

---

For more views on minor edits, good or bad, check out my post here:

- ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site?rq=1)

Comment: Though retagging from no tag to a language tag like PHP would be a decent edit, retagging from one minor tag to one whose existance is questionable on this site could legitimatly be seen as too minor. I mean what value does graphical-logo add to the question?

Comment: A tag edit *can* be a significant change.  It can also be a very minor change.  It depends radically on how the tags are actually changed.  Edit certain tags can radically improve the visibility a question edits, editing other tags can have no affect at all on its visibility.  The majority of tag edits I see end up falling into the latter category, not the former.

Answer (score 4):

Too minor is when you put in too little effort. Too minor is when you don't do enough. Too minor is repainting the titanic while it sinks. Too minor is when I could make a better edit and uncheck "this edit is helpful". Too minor is when you replace a tag with one that should burninated. Too minor is capitalization. Too minor is when if people approve it, I'll look through their profile.

Too minor is this edit.

Comment: +1 just for "Too minor is repainting the titanic while it sinks".

Comment: +1 for "Too minor is when if people approve it, I'll look thru their profile." [This room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58120/please-dont-approve-minor-or-invalid-edits) immediately came to my mind.

Comment: Wouldn't repainting the Titanic while it sinks but more futile than minor ;)

Comment: +1 for making me look thru your profile and getting a yodel out of it...