# Editing tag into a series of questions

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I have been following a low activity tag for some time now. [This tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes) isn't known by most users posting questions as it doesn't have many questions and isn't in the proposal list of tags.

When I bump into a question that applies to this tag, I add it. A few other users do the same **but** doing some more research, I find many other old questions that could do with it. I don't want to bump a series af questions up on the SO interesting tab as it can be annoying and considered as noise.

To avoid that noise I am editing that tag in in series of 2-3 question every once in a while but this is not very effective and I would like to go faster and edit them all at once.

How should I handle this? Should I just edit that tag in? Should I forget about it? Or is there a way to handle this?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270158/retag-is-too-minor-edit