# Is editing an 'unknown' or 'new' tag into older questions bad, or advised?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I came across [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277539/editing-tag-into-a-series-of-questions) recently, which is yet to be answered by any of the community. This may have been down to the age of the actual tag at the time.

It talks about the [css-shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes) tag, and how this tag could be applied to questions in which were asked before the tag had been created.

So, this means that there are questions out there that are suitable for this tag, and may be helpful to 'edit this tag in' to such questions.

Is it advisable/appropriate to:

1. Edit the tag in to these older questions - even though there may be a lot of backdating to do
2. Leave the old question alone - it's done well enough without this tag
3. Something else (?)

With new tags obviously being created (i.e. new technologies, etc), which of the above should we do?

My opinion would be to add this tag in to such questions, as it would bring more awareness to the tag - as well as make it easier to find such questions in the future.

I'd like to think the option of 'leave it alone' isn't very productive, but maybe adding this 'noise' is seen as exactly that - noise?

Comment: I would not actively go hunt for those questions to get them tagged. If I find a post that needs editing and can have a better tag, the date of the post and/or tag creation doesn't matter anymore. So I guess this describes your option 3: something else...

Comment: I wouldn't go looking for old questions just to add the tag to them, as all the questions will be bumped to the front page, and you might end up "reactivating" crap questions which otherwise be autodeleted if no-one edits them. If you happen to come accross a question which would actually benefit from an edit, the go ahead. But IMO edits just to add a tag are not good.

Comment: so it's more like "if you see it, edit it. But don't go looking for it" sorta thing.

Comment: Do you have a rough estimate for the number of questions that you would potentially add this tag to? I don't know if there's a binary answer here. To me, it depends somewhat on the scale. If you add it to a few relatively recent questions, that would seem fine. If you add it to thousands of questions from years ago, I think that would be too much.

Comment: Seems like there should be an option for moderator users to edit a question for the sake of adding tags or other information without bumping it to the top of the list.

Comment: I followed that link to the other question which (now) has a duplicate which lead me back here. Perhaps you'd like make a change there?

Answer (score 25):

I have found no specific guideline for this issue since I asked the question you refer too.

But I believe that going through old questions involves more work than just adding a tag and could follow these steps:

1. Is the question a duplicate : Yes => vote to close, No => step 2
2. Is the question off-topic : Yes => vote to close, No => step 3
3. Is the question as is valuable for future readers Yes => **edit**, retag, upvote No => step 4
4. Can the question be made valuable for future readers : Yes => **Edit**, answer, retag, upvote No => leave it alone, downvote

Obviously the "valuable" part isn't objective and is according to your understanding but it should rule out questions that would [automaticaly be deleted by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/245708). That is also why you should do this only for topics you are aware off.

A good way to know if the question is valuable to other readers is if it is found via a search engine query.

Going through old questions involves a lot "cleaning" but I think it benefits to the related tag and the general quality by removing off-topic, content and making/bumping quality content.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote valuable questions :-)

Comment: good point @Bergi I'll edit that in