# Why can't I consistently retag questions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Note: The following question's title makes it look like it answers my question, but it talks about edit reviewers rejecting "retag" edit suggestions.  That isn't quite what I'm concerned about.

> [Retag rejected during review as too minor edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270158/retag-is-too-minor-edit?rq=1)

I'm very active in the [Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) tag because of my experience with Adobe Flex.  Unfortunately, this tag gets a lot of mistagged questions about bison and the fast lexical parser (flex) or the CSS flexbox model.  When I see these, I always suggest an edit to retag them to the correct tag (flex-lexer for the bison questions, flexbox for CSS).

However, sometimes I can't retag a question; I get the error message telling me that edits must be at least 6 characters.  I haven't been able to figure out any consistency to this behavior.

Why can't I consistently retag questions?  I don't know anything about bison, so I'm not comfortable editing the content of those questions.

Comment: Is it so bad that re-naming [tag:flex] to [tag:flex-adobe] would be in order?

Comment: I don't think so.  First, the volume of mis-tagged questions isn't overwhelming, just noticeable.  Second, `flex` already has `adobe-flex` as a tag synonym.  Third, Flex is actually Apache Flex now -- Adobe handed it off to the Apache foundation in 2011 (it's probably worth a tag synonym for that!).  Fourth, `flex` has referred to the Actionscript framework for a long time -- I don't think the mis-tagged questions warrant renaming the tag to accommodate mistakes by people applying the wrong tags.

Comment: I think that "noticeable" is enough, BTW, I'm advocated of changing the order of that sysnonym.

Comment: And now the other question's title won't confuse it with your case.

Answer (score 5):

If you make *any* change to the body of the question, you'll be required to change at least 6 characters. Even if you also edit tags.

Note that this differs from title edits, which do not have a length restriction and override the restriction on body edits.

Solution: either don't edit *anything* else, or edit as much as you possibly can.

Comment: Sometimes even though I edit **only** the tags, it still complains that I made some other change **even though** the post markdown is **exactly** the same. I can confirm that with a text compare utility. Why is that? This seemed to especially affect old duplicate posts with the duplicate link edited into the post itself.

Comment: I see the same thing as damryfbfnetsi.  Sometimes it works fine, other times it requires 6 characters in the body despite the fact that I'm only editing the tag.