# Suggested edit shows changes which are not mine. Why?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I made an edit to a question; the only changes were to capitalisation and punctuation. When I clicked on the [queued suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6082362) the diff included changes which I had not made.

It would appear that the OP also made changes which my edit somehow overwrote, but I would have expected the software to reject my submission as an edit conflict in that case.

As it happens, the edit was approved although one reviewer rejected it because "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." Quite right, but that certainly wasn't my intention.

Please let's not discuss here whether this sort of minor edit is [worthy or not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/397817).

Why did my suggested edit include changes which weren't mine? How could I have avoided it? Should I roll back my edit?

Comment: So you mean the deletion of the 2nd image and the phrase "error screenshot" are not yours?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Given that the OP's edit introduced both images and not just the one I somehow managed to revert, I'm starting to think I must have just messed up somehow. I propose rolling back to edit 2 of 3 in the meantime but can't see how to do it. EDIT: Appears I lack the necessary privileges http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17042/168807

Comment: Do as follows : Start your editing. When you're about to validate it, select all (the post textbox), copy or cut, then click cancel intead of validating. This brings you back to the topic page. You can now check wether the post have been edited by someone else in the meantime. If so, click edit, paste you draft, make the required changes, then repeat all the above until noone committed an edit. Validate your changes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but you did make those changes, just not on purpose.  Your [continued research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275359/suggested-edit-shows-changes-which-are-not-mine-why?noredirect=1#comment110406_275359) was on the right track.

The OP committed an edit to the post while you were working on your edit, and this happened within 5 minutes of the OP's previous edit.  Since it was within 5 minutes, it is considered to be within the grace period and subsequent edits by the same person are considered part of the same revision.

Once the OP committed his edit, you were now editing an old revision and when you submitted your edit, you effectively rolled back the OP's edit.

Checking the timestamps of the last 2 revisions, your edit was approved at 13:49:29Z.  The OP's previous revision was at 12:59:17Z, which means 50 minutes elapsed between the previous revision and your edit, so this doesn't appear to be a typical grace period edit conflict, however, if you look at the edit approval history, the first approval came at 13:17:07Z.  Given how much time there was between the 4 reviews, your edit probably sat in the queue for at least 15 minutes, which gets us back into the grace period of the previous edit.

There's not much that you can do to prevent this as revisions are not locked when you are editing them, and because a new revision is not created within the grace period, there is no warning message that pops up to tell you that the post was edited.  The only way to avoid this from happening is to not begin editing posts until 5 minutes after the previous edit was submitted.

Comment: That really sucks.  Is there already a proposal to change that?  Given how new comments and edits are visible in other parts of the site, I would certainly expect it to warn me when I am about to overwrite somebody's hard work.

Comment: @tripleee: I agree, this seems like a hole in the system, nobody likes to lose her/his work.

Comment: I posted a feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275398/get-notified-of-edit-conflicts-while-working-on-an-edit

Comment: @tripleee this specific situation may not be completely resolved by your feature request. You should at least spell it out, if you want to include it. This is 100% caused by the grace period. If the OPs second edit did trigger a new revision then there would have been a warning before committing the edit. But because of the grace period, the system actually thinks he was editing the most recent revision

Comment: @psubsee2003 This particular problem, yes.  I link to this question for background, but I imagine this particular scenario is fairly marginal.  I would like to see an improvement to the overall handling in the first place, and then this fringe scenario with the grace period should not be hard to include as well.  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @tripleee you did.  I just think that the grace period situation is unique and may require special handling, which is why I was mentioned you might want to mention that you want grace period edits to trigger a notification as well.

Comment: +1 for "not to begin editing posts until 5 minutes after the previous edit was submitted" - although, "previous edit" might need more precision - you can't wait until 5 minutes after an edit that you did not notice :-) But for new posts it certainly makes sense to wait before editing it because the OP of the post is very likely to review their own post multiple times within the grace period, maybe even correcting the same spelling mistakes.

Comment: @chiccodoro if an edit happens while you are editing, you will be informed upon trying to submit the edit.  It won't let you override the previous edit and the UX is poor (hence tripleee's feature request), but the grace period issue is the only time where you could silently overwrite the current version.