# Grace period and third party edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250789/adding-requstcontextlistener-through-context-addlistener-doesnt-work-but) question and it was rejected (3:2). I was curious why this happend, so I looked into the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11790566) and saw only two changes (between OP's version and my version) not of mine:

[image: diff]

I read about grace period in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275365/5277820) and understood why it is possible that I see those changes. So I looked into [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36250789/1) and saw more than the two changes and knew that OP had changed his question in grace period:

[image: revision 1]

But [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36250789/2) shows a second edit 5 seconds before mine with almost the same changes:

[image: diff revision 2]

Why is my edit not rejected with "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit." and why is OPs version shown in review instead of third party version?

Comment: I can't answer why it wasn't immediately rejected as a conflict, but the review *is* showing the difference between your edit and the third party's edit. They changed `met with` -> `facing`, and your edit is changing it back (since you were using the original version).