# Community♦'s rejection reason when I "Reject and Edit" explicitly contradicts established site policy and is worse than no message at all

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits

I rarely use "Reject and Edit" from the Suggested Edits review queue, but just now I [did it for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7055043) in a while and saw that it generated this rejection message:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

This seems to be complaining that the rejected edit was *too minor*, which is entirely at odds with our [current understanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) that there's no such thing as a "too minor" edit. And it presumes that I've actually fixed "critical issues" after doing a Reject and Edit. In the linked case, I certainly didn't; I rejected an edit that incorrectly attempted to fix the capitalization of a library name, and fixed it correctly instead, but nobody's ability to understand the question hinged on this. The rejection message is confusing and wrong, and given that we're meant to be embracing good-but-minor edits now, I can't really imagine any circumstance in which it would be appropriate.

Should we just scrap the message?

Comment: Well, we need *some* message there. Like a generic: "This is not an acdeptable edit. View \[the revision history\](link here) to see what could have been corrected."

Comment: The revision history may not have any useful information about why the edit was rejected, though, @Deduplicator - perhaps there were things to fix, which the reviewer fixed, and also the edit sucked for a totally unrelated reason. Heck, maybe the reviewer *scaled down* the edit because parts of it were wrong. A message like "This is not an acceptable edit. Viewing [the revision history](link here) may provide a hint as to why the edit was rejected." would be safer. Aside: I approve of making "revision history" into a link; it seems like a wasted opportunity that it currently isn't one.

Comment: I think that message sums up pretty well what 'Reject and Edit' is supposed to be for: either making additional necessary changes which the editor failed to include, or correcting edits which were outright wrong (as in your case).

Comment: @sapi I don't think it sums up the second case at all, and the first case isn't a valid reason for rejecting the edit.

Comment: You are cherry-picking an answer that states that no edit is too minor, but in the case of edits that must be validated, many think that there is such a thing as too minor an edit, whatever one post on meta says.

Comment: I would suggest to make it explicit, something like "A reviewer found your edit not helpful. You can see her own edit in revision history."

Comment: @PascalCuoq some people do indeed believe - for entirely rational reasons, although I don't agree with them - that suggested edits can be too minor, and they voiced that opinion clearly in the thread I linked to and received many upvotes in support. Nonetheless, the overall balance of voting showed that their opinion is no longer the majority one. It is also not official policy - the "too minor" close reason was deliberately removed. It seems inconsistent for the reason given for "Reject and Edit" to implicitly endorse a minority view that the site has gone out of its way to combat.

Answer (score 3):

## This is all about the situation when reject-and-edit was made by OP and not by a reviewer.

In my opinion this message should at least be changed for OP-initiated edits where OP is under 2k reputation (thus, not allowed to review suggested edits).

#### As I see, here's what this message implies:

1. The post has (or had) a critical issue
2. The original edit didn't correct the issue
3. The OP-authored edit **did** correct the issue
4. The OP is more competent in deciding what is a proper correction.

Well, nothing of that is always true. There could be no failure. If the OP is more competent, why would they first ask a question with a critical fault? How do we know that the new edit fixes it?

#### What, in my opinion, is the real information about what has happened:

1. The OP saw the edit and rejected it to make their own edit.
2. It's unknown whether the question is okay or has some fault.
3. It's unknown whether the original edit was good or bad.
4. It's unknown whether the new edit is good or bad.
5. No other reviewers except the OP were involved in making a decision (but there might have been reviews, which is reflected [under the message](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7359491)).

#### What the message should look like:

> The original poster rejected your edit and made their own edit.

Plus, maybe, some manual to further actions:

> If you disagree with the new edit, please explain it in the comments to the question.

Here's why this became interesting to me:  [I met the same situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296202/my-edit-was-interrupted-with-a-reject-and-edit-to-even-worse-question-state/296203#296203) from the side of an editor (not-OP).

Comment: Regarding what the message should look like: The OP isn't the only one who can Reject and Edit a suggested edit. Any reviewer can. So saying _"The original poster rejected your edit and made their own edit."_ could technically be incorrect. In _your_ case, it was the OP that clicked "Reject and Edit" but other reviewers have that option as well.

Comment: @Kendra maybe separate the messages for reviewer and OP? A reviewer is usually an SO member with at least some reputation and experience, thus a competent one. But we cannot say the same about OP.

Comment: I think the Reject and Edit message is fine myself. I was really only pointing out a small flaw in your suggestion. If you wish to suggest that, feel free.

Comment: The OP is a reviewer with no more or less ability to do a "reject and edit" or "improve edit" than any other reviewer. They only have the extra-power to insta-reject/approve for *any* reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator the OP can review edits to their own questions at 1 reputation. For all other edits 2k reputation is required. So a usual reviewer is guaranteed to have some expertize with SO and OP is not. That is the crucial difference.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Would be nice if that was a good metric for moderation ability...