# How to act when I disagree with the rejection of my suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7359491) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055074/how-can-i-move-back-to-element-0-in-an-array-to-reset-a-loop), but the edit was rejected because...

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

I see that this was because the person who rejected it decided to **Reject and Edit** the suggestion. However, the edits made were inconsistent and in my eyes didn't increase the readability of the code in the way my edits would have (and certainly did not correct critical issues with the post either).

In cases like these (where my suggested edit is declined with which I disagree), what is the correct course of action?

- Think that my edit was too minor (did not increase the readability enough to be an edit) and quit making similar edits in the future
- Disagree with the reject and re-edit the post
- Disagree with the reject and just let it go

or perhaps act in some other way (please specify)?

Comment: The reviewer reject your edit and yet make a less substantial change to the question. I would have accepted your edit if I had reviewed it. I wonder what that reviewer was thinking frankly.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau My thoughts exactly! Is it appropriate to re-edit the question after getting rejected once?

Comment: As an aside, code-snippets are flat-out wrong for UnityScript.

Comment: There's a feature-request about that. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286112/community%E2%99%A6s-rejection-reason-when-i-reject-and-edit-is-worse-than-nothing/296204#296204

Comment: [This exact thing just happened to me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30950750). It's frustrating because my edit was, in my eyes, clearly superior in every way (I fixed several grammatical mistakes and copied the asker's code from GitHub so answerers wouldn't have to switch tabs to read it). Oh well.

Comment: eh, that's a good *looking* edit, but it leaves the question in a state that still should be closed. (not quite sure why the reviewer edited it either... :shrug:) Best to open a new question, if you want to discuss your case specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest you just let it go.

I wouldn't bother editing it again if I were you, since what you would change to reflect your first edit wouldn't be much. That kind of case should be quite rare... I would think.

That kind of edit should be fine as any edits that improve a question/answer should be accepted.

You should take some time to read on [the history on the too minor review option that existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor), [why it was removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion) since the community was/is divided on how small edits should be.