# What to do when edit was rejected with a "reject and edit" to even worse question state?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674208/why-iml-files-should-be-added-to-gitignore-what-should-be-placed-in-gitignore), actually consisting of two. One of them was a valid SO question and received an answer shortly. The other doesn't fit the rules and would be closed as too broad.

I [made an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8340027), removing the second question. But the edit was rejected with "reject and edit". The [new edition](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30674208/revisions) of the question looks even worse to me, because now the second, generalized question is in the header. There's also this message:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed

Why? It seems to me that my edit just did correct the most critical issue. **Please explain me, where am I wrong?**

The [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8340027):
[image]

The [new edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30674208/revisions):
[image]

Comment: That was an action taken by the owner of the post, not by actual reviewers.  I forget how this works, but the owner of the post can basically always edit it no matter what.  And they rejected your edit.

Comment: The OP of the post rejected your edit- They did not agree with you removing half of their post, it would seem. If the question is asking more than one question and they are not small very closely related questions... Flag as "Too Broad" and leave it. You shouldn't remove half the post like that- That kind of drastic edit should be left up to the OP.

Comment: @ryanyuyu does this mean that they've seen my suggested edit or it was just auto-rejected?

Comment: @NickVolynkin If it was auto-rejected, it wouldn't have the OP listed- Just Community. It also would've said "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit." So yes, the OP saw your edit and disagreed with it, but still felt they should make an edit. Edit: [An example of an automatically rejected edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5796195)

Comment: @Kendra thank you, I see now. And what does the OP actually mean?

Comment: OP = Original Poster

Comment: found a related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288114/how-to-act-when-i-disagree-with-the-rejection-of-my-suggested-edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Where I was wrong

> Please explain me, where am I wrong?

It was wrong to make such a drastic edit. An appopriate action would be flagging it with `close > too broad`. (Which is what I did later).

#### Here's what actually happened.

1. The OP (original poster) saw the pending edit.
2. They decided to reject it and make their own edit.
3. The message "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post" was a result of a decision of a single user - the OP. It might as well reflect or not reflect the opinion of SO moderators or some group of SO users.

#### Conclusions

In my opinion, a message for OP-initiated edits should be different than that for reviewer-initiated, at least for OPs under 2k reputation. ([I wrote an answer about that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286112/community%E2%99%A6s-rejection-reason-when-i-reject-and-edit-is-worse-than-nothing).)