# Suggested edit rejected by new user

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288114/how-to-act-when-i-disagree-with-the-rejection-of-my-suggested-edit?rq=1) relevant but it is not the same situation as mine. I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13009331) which was rejected by Community saying

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

Later on it was reviewed by the post owner; his reputation is `1` and he choose to `Reject and Edit` or `Reject`. **But**, you can take a look at the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379163/error-sql-server-jdbc-and-intellij) now; it is the same as I suggested except for the formatting of the error message. I used 'Blockquote' to show the error and he used 'Code Sample'. And all other things like grammar, sentence fixing is the same as I suggested; that means my suggestion was worthy.

So I want to know:

1. Why then did he choose `Reject and Edit` instead of `Approve and Edit`?
2. And why did `Community` reject this; are formatting and grammar not 
   critical issues?
3. Why is a post owner with no reputation allowed to review a post single-handedly?

In this case the post was reviewed by `Community` too but I experienced some cases where a post owner can approve or reject single-handedly.

Comment: "Why post owner with no reputation is allowed to review post single handedly." Because he is the author of the question - it is **his** question.

Comment: @DavidPostill this sound more like an answer ?

Comment: @mpromonet It only answers his Q3.

Comment: Q1: Only he (The OP) can know why, Q2: Because it's not a critical issue. and probably the OP rejected it - not the community. And  @DavidPostill comment is the most important, and sums it up perfectly - We shouldn't take ownership of other users posts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The author of a post can single-handledly approve or reject a suggested edit, regardless of his/her reputation (Q3). *Why* he did this (rejecting but effectively applying the edit) is a mystery only the author can answer (Q1). You could try and ask nicely in a comment, but in this case, I'd just try and help somebody else who *is* cooperating. Whenever a reviewer clicks <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd>, it is always the Community ♦ user who casts the Reject vote (Q2); note that Community ♦ *never* reviews a post itself.

In any case, even after the edit, the question is still unsalvageable as it lacks sufficient detail for us to diagnose the problem. It is better to flag those kind of questions, and add a comment asking for more details, instead of editing them.

<sub>Oh, and while the grammar has been improved, I still see some mistakes: 'occur' instead of 'occurs', 'have problem' instead of 'have a problem' ...</sub>