# Suggested edit with disturbing image - is there a way to remove it from the queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, vandalism

I came across a suggested edit in the review queue which was vandalizing the post by adding a disturbing picture. One of those with ghastly faces, just to be clear, with the intent to troll the reviewer who wouldn't expect such a thing while scrolling the post.

I'm not really affected by this kind of stuff, however others may be (I'm not going to link the review for this exact reason).

Since the review needs two people reaching consensus, by just rejecting I'm not going to spare the jump on the chair to the next reviewer.

My question is, is there an action or trick that the first reviewer can employ to pop the post off the review queue, so that others don't have to go through it? I.e. will "Reject and Edit" do it?

- I know that the review needs two people to reach consensus, but in this particular case it seems unnecessary and/or avoidable.
- I'm not looking to discuss counter measures to this kind of shenanigans. It happened and that's all. That's what review is for. Flagging is not an option as the proposer was anonymous anyway.

Comment: I would think that one safety measure would be to signal the next reviewer in the edit description; "Removes objectionable image".  Or something like that.

Comment: See [Is this how reject and edit is supposed to work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332651/11682469)

Comment: @DaveL17 but the first reject/edit reason isn't immediately visible to the second reviewer

Comment: they say that [suggested edits that were rejected as spam or vandalism are not visible to users who don't have an account on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300946/165773)

Comment: @blackgreen I didn't know there wasn't an apparent "Reject and Edit" reason immediately visible to the next reviewer.  Never mind.

Comment: this was actually a very funny suggestion, especially the reason for it :)

Comment: The edit comment says: *"Didn't change anything think I'm getting hacked"*. Either this could be a lie or their account might have actually been taken over by someone. I have seen an incident like this before where a seemingly good user suddenly started vandalizing their posts with offensive language. Their user profile was changed to something along the lines of *"Don't use the same password everywhere"*. Of course, that doesn't excuse them from vandalism and violation of the code of conduct. Btw the image in question isn't really that bad. I have seen people adding pornographic images too.

Comment: Also, the edit seems to be from an anonymous user... basically anyone on the internet. Not sure if moderators can do something about this. Maybe if their IP is found to repeat the offense several times then it might be fed to SpamRam (I guess, not sure if that is how it works)

Comment: perhaps edits which adds images should be banned - I can't think of any situations where such edits are going to be helpful

Comment: @mck - btw, that's an interesting idea. Usually, when an image is important to the question/answer, only the OP can add it due to context. The only useful action suggested edits usually can do with images is inline them (admittedly, not always very useful). I am not sure what the real situation is, but my gut feeling tells me this might be a good feature request

Comment: @Yatin: The irony that I, a moderator (i.e. the kind of role in which I should be prepared to deal with extremely upsetting and even trauma-triggering content from time to time), am one of the few who might actually be frightened by the edit in question (not that I disagree with you, but because faces *do* frighten me more than they might others)...

Comment: Some people really just want to burn the world down, don't they? :-|

Comment: @OlegValter, sometimes editor crop the original image, and resize it, or blur something. That's one other valid case where you change the source image. I already saw a print screen of 2 full hd screen in order to show a greyed checkbox, and the other tab and bookmark exposing private information.

Comment: @DragandDrop - I agree that's a valid case, we are currently discussing the benefits and shortcomings in a standalone feature request. That said, when editors do that, from what I've seen, they *replace* the link, so I think we can accommodate that consistently by checking for number of occurrences of image markdown in the edit body (I am currently working on a query that should determine how many such edits there are)

Comment: Would preventing anonymous and low-rep users from adding images have an overall positive effect?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For such rude/abusive/spam suggested edits, you can recruit the help of the folks who hang out in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

There, you can ask for a second reviewer using a "Review Please" request, which would take the following form:

```
[tag:review-pls] <link to the review page> Vandalism | offensive image added
```

The link can be copied directly from the URL bar you see in your review and the "Vandalism" text can be anything you like – but make it clear and meaningful.

When I have done this in the past, a second reviewer normally offers their help within a few minutes.

Comment: this seems a very good solution, as it doesn't work around the review system, and at the same time allows the problematic edit to be handled by people who know what to expect

Comment: @blackgreen Yeah - the SOCVR regulars aren't easily embarrassed by disturbing images.

Comment: True, SOCVR regulars are more hardened than the average user, but it might still make sense to include "contains offensive image" in the [review-pls] request, just as a heads up.

Comment: @cigien Sure - that would certainly be helpful.

Comment: You can always come to [CharcoalHQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) for help. Spam and R/A is daily occurrence there ;)

Comment: @Yatin true, I have seen stuff in posts that I won't unsee.... ever. Those trolls...

Comment: @10Rep Yeah - there are some *horribly* disturbing [Troll Images](https://d2e111jq13me73.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/styles/review_gallery_carousel_slide_thumbnail_landscape/public/video-thumbnails/trollsmoviebar4.jpg?itok=fFIvoMOX) around. ;-)

Comment: Isn't it `[tag:review-pls] Vandalism | offensive image added <link to the review page> `? If you read LTR, you'll be warned before clicking the link

Comment: "SOCVR regulars are more hardened than the average user" - why on earth would that be the case? [citation needed]

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, one reason is because the Charcoal project routinely sends potential spam and R/A content to SOCVR, so there's at least more exposure to that sort of content than one would get on the main site. I can't speak for how many members click on those links, but I would guess that they're at least more *aware* of the existence of such content than the average user.

Comment: @cigien But does it actually happen often enough (or at all really, OP’s potentially singular experience notwithstanding) to justify the warning? I’ve *never* seen anything like this, *anywhere* on this site. Neither in reviews nor elsewhere. I’ve seen spam and trolling, but never anything even remotely disturbing or offensive (other than insults).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If offensive content is uncommon, that's all the more reason to provide a warning, right? As to the quantity of offensive content (different people are triggered by different levels of offensiveness), there's actually quite a lot of it, and it's a testament to the efficacy of the Charcoal project, and to some extent, chatrooms like SOCVR, that a vast majority of that content is never seen by most regular users, either on the site, or in reviews.

Comment: @cigien Generally useless warnings lead to over-saturation and aren’t taken seriously. Warnings should be relevant for maximal effectiveness. I’m asking if this is a rare event (= provide a warning) or a virtually nonexistent event. Your comment indicates that there’s actually a lot, which to me is surprising (I’m *not* a “regular” user, so I would expect to at least occasionally encounter such content due to my activity reviewing etc.).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, I think I see what you mean. Yes, warnings in the SD reports (generated by the Charcoal project) would be noise, since the whole point is to catch problematic content. For requests posted in SOCVR, a large majority are harmless (i.e. have no offensive content), but sometimes they do, so I would say that in a [review-pls], adding a warning would be nice. And, yes, there is a lot of offensive content, but it's caught and deleted very quickly (often within 30 seconds of the content being posted), so it makes sense that they wouldn't be seen much, even by active users.

Answer (score 15):

You can single-handedly reject an edit by clicking "Reject and Edit" and changing something about the post but this isn’t the right action to take here.

Even though another reviewer will have to see the edit (if it wasn’t reviewed by someone already), you need to **reject it as spam or vandalism**.

This sends the strongest signal to the system that it’s a really bad edit. If you don't do this, the editor will just get more chances to submit bad edits!

Comment: Is there a way to do this while also removing it from the queue? Which is what the OP is actually asking about. Also, does rejecting it as spam/vandalism make any difference when the editor is anonymous? Does it prevent them from making any more suggested edits?

Comment: @cigien - "reject and edit" - instant removal. Upon rereading the answer, I get your question - Laurel, why would "changing something" not be appropriate?

Comment: *the editor will just get more chances to submit bad edits* — the editor was an anonymous user. If it weren't, I would have flagged the post *beside* rejecting it as vandalism.

Comment: @blackgreen - because this is not how the review system currently works - there is no checkbox accompanying the "Improve" option, so the technique is unusable

Comment: @OlegValter yes actually when I glanced over cigien's answer earlier I was surprised about the checkbox. never saw it before

Comment: @blackgreen - yeah, I was also surprized - btw, does anybody have a reference to when it became unavailable (I guess it must've been present at some point if there is a question?)? Let's put a disclaimer there that the info is outdated.

Comment: (The checkbox was never there when I’ve edited. That means that it was probably removed in 2014-2015 — either way a really long time ago)