# Should we prevent edit suggestions from adding images to posts?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

As a follow-up on a discussion on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407087), I'd like to request a new feature to prevent edit suggestions from adding new images.

In general, images are only useful when added by the OP, but not by other users. Preventing the addition of images through edits can screen out unhelpful edits, or spam edits which add bad images.

I'm not sure if I've missed out on some arguments for this, but if I did, my fallback feature request would be to prevent **anonymous** edit suggestions from adding new images.

Comment: I'd like the staff to see if they can draw up some stats for approved/rejected edit suggestions that add or modify image uploads.

Comment: @BoltClock - hmmm, we can check post bodies + review outcomes with SEDE, can't we? I can give it a shot. At a first glance, I like the proposal because I too don't see a valid case where an image being added through a suggested edit is beneficial, but accept that my gut feeling might not be supported by data.

Comment: This is a literal case of throwing the baby with the bathwater. It took \*counting on head\* 12 years since the addition of suggested edits to someone to suggest something and others to take notice.

Comment: This is the base frame query I am currently going for (note that I only started filtering out edits that simply inline images - that is not a definitive version [something tells me the like operator with % wildcards will kill the performance, so open to any suggestions. Most "added image" SEs are actually about inlining images [comment reposted now that the query is improved].

Comment: ^ we probably can diff the suggested edit Text column with the previous revision text and check if there are additional `i.stack.imgur.com` references, but I am not sure how sound this approach is

Comment: Something also tells me that people might be conflating adding images with *inlining* them - please note that the feature request does not want to forbid all images, just those that **add images not already present in the post as a link**

Comment: Ok, this is the last version I can go for now before diving into optimization venues: brought the results down to only ~5000 probable cases during the whole history of SO (if one removes the likely candidates to be image inline replacements commented as "added image", only ~3000 cases): https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400985/approved-suggested-edits-adding-images-to-posts

Comment: ^ optimized to store patterns in a temp table variable, results verified: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400985/approved-suggested-edits-adding-images-to-posts#messages

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of times where the OP of a question doesn't give a direct link to an image, for example, linking to GitHub for an image.

This is normal for new contributors, and at such situations I would replace the GitHub link with a new imgur generated image link.

Sometimes *(though pretty rare)* users will ask follow-up questions, linking to the previous one. As the previous one has the image, they don't include the image in the follow-up question, which is another reason to suggest edits that add images.

Comment: You listed valid concerns, but wouldn't it be better to defer such edits (potentially problematic) to users with full edit privileges and unburden suggested edits reviewers from double-checking if the image is appropriate in the post, is actually the correct image, etc?

Comment: @OlegValter Hmm, good point :D

Comment: But I was more addressing the *images are only useful when added by the OP, but not by other users*.

Comment: "I was more addressing" - that was also my point in the other Q&A + I am the one who suggested it be made a proper feature request, so I feel duty-bound to respond to criticism of the proposal :) Re: point - well, what we need now is some hard data, agreed with BoltClock. If it turns out there are a lot of suggestions like that approved, then we will certainly miss out on useful edits by forbidding them. But if it is, like, 2 out of 1000, then we can safely choose a lesser evil