# Why was this edit rejected as "did not correct critical issues with the post"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rejected-edits

Please have a look at this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16135272).

The initial edit corrected a grammatical error and removed meaningless sentences,

It was rejected with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43993698/revisions), which only removed one error (and left in "Thanks in advanced").

I believe the first edit (mine) was superior - could someone please explain why not?

From [deleted meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348769/can-we-auto-correct-certain-common-grammar-mistakes):

> We don't want to have "Thanks in advanced" corrected. We want to have it removed

Comment: It was a reject-and-edit, so the choice was made *completely* by the other editor. I would have approved yours, and rejected an edit like theirs if it had shown up in the queue.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused by community comment "...view the revision history to see what should have been changed" and thought it was referencing that other edit.

Comment: It is. The *idea* is that you then get to see what a better edit would look like. In this case... not so much. Meantime, I applied your edit, plus a few tweaks. Of course, the question as-is should be closed, but still.

Comment: I would have rage skip this in review queue and Flag both post and answer.

Comment: I have to agree with Pierre. Your edit was better but it still didn't solve all the problems with the post. Namely, the OP needs to provide more information to make it answerable. You'll sometimes see this referred to as "polishing turds" on Meta. Don't bother doing edits for questions that would still need to be put on hold after your change (or editing closed questions that wouldn't get re-opened after your change). Your time is better spent on fixable questions.

Comment: I find polishing turds acceptable if you are doing something like fixing code formatting problems that make the question *unreadable* in its current state.  Ie, where formatting is so bad that you cannot tell if the post is any good until fixed; the user embedded unguarded `<>` (which vanish with their contents because of our HTML filter?) or messed up code formatting.  I will polish that turd, determine it is a turd after I polished it, then vote to close in that case.  However, this does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: As I've complained at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286112/communitys-rejection-reason-when-i-reject-and-edit-explicitly-contradicts-es, the "did not correct critical issues" reason is bullshit; it explicitly contradicts carefully established site policy for anybody to ever reject an edit on those grounds, and there's absolutely no reason to assume that a review who picks "Reject and Edit" believed there were "critical issues" to fix. After years, though, the site's devs still haven't gotten round to fixing it, even though all it would take is tweaking a single piece of static copy.

Comment: well, I saw that the edit is has no improvement at all, in the same time that I've found a typo 'view able', so I've rejected the edit suggest due to it had no improvement whatsoever , and at the same time fixed the typo @PaulRoub

Comment: @hassan the edit you rejected did remove all useless chatter which is generally considered an improvement as well as correcting the typo. So yours failed to correct most of the issues of the original post.

Comment: @BSMP how could user read OP mind and provide the extra information? User edit was good because it improved the post with the little information he had, you can't reject it because OP needs to add more.

Comment: *how could user read OP mind and provide the extra information?* @Braiam That's exactly my point. They can't provide that extra information, which means their edit can't fix the post. It's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Braiam At least spell consistently! "So you can't fix obvious typos when they are obvious?"

Comment: @wizzwizz4 my point is that there are stuff that we need to fix while we see it, not just on the final version.

Comment: So... a comment illustrating how unpractical was BSMP point was deleted...

Comment: @PaulRoub actually, I would have reject and edited the other instead of simply rejecting. Why miss the opportunity of fixing a post when it's having my attention.

Comment: Wasing time is being brought up here often. I would just like to point out that the title of that review queue is "This is the first question asked by a new user. **Help them learn to use the site** by reviewing their post."

Comment: @user5226582 your comment is about different queue... this question is about "suggested edits".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that was the queue in which I made the initial edit suggestion