# Approve small but correct suggested edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Should I approve suggested edits that are correct, but minor or even trivial (e.g. single spelling errors)?

On the review side it clearly says

> **Approve** edits you know are correct

But on `Help Center > Privileges > edit questions and answers`:

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
>   change a single character. **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged**.

The newest example was this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7675194 which changes only a single letter in the headline, but is correct nevertheless and (minimally) improves the question.

Comment: Does anyone misunderstand "XCode" because of a capitalisation issue?

Comment: @TZHX: Certainly not and I wouldn't have corrected it myself, but the edit is correct, so I see no reason to reject it.

Comment: If they fix one spelling mistake, but miss others, then I will reject.  If they fix all spelling mistakes and there aren't any major grammar/formatting issues, then I approve.  That change though I would reject because is actually misses much more serious issues with the title and tags.

Comment: You could have improved the edit. There are other formatting issues and grammatical errors.

Comment: @OmidHezaveh: Well, as far as the time line is concerned, the linked post is  a duplicate of this one rather than vice versa, but the linked question and answers are of much higher quality, So I'm fine with closing this one as a duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would argue that whilst the edit may be grammatically correct, there is probably a need to discourage such tiny edits for the sake of a minority of users that are editing purely for the sake of point-scoring.

Whilst this is always going to be a problem with any points system, it detracts from the fact that edits are encouraged in order to better the *quality* of the post - and in turn increase the post's value to the SE community. Changing a letter from upper-case to lower-case may be an improvement to the grammar, but does it actually add any *real* value to the post, or improve the readability in any way? More than likely not, in which case I would more than likely reject the edit.

The benefit of unlocking review privileges as you obtain more points is that (hopefully) you've been around enough to understand what the 'expected' standard is, and therefore use your own judgement to apply a 'common sense' check to the edit(s) being reviewed.

Comment: You ask "why do tiny edits"; I ask "why not". Personally, I hate misspellings. As others have pointed out, they may impede discoverability, and they make the site look ugly. If someone wants to fix them, and the "cost" of allowing them to do so is one reviewer pressing the "Accept" button instead of "Reject" button, what is the problem again exactly?

Comment: @torazaburo I add my voice to the 'why not' camp, there is no pool of edits that will get used up.  If it is a possitive edit it is a good edit no matter how small (even if a single letter).  And as for rep farming, do we really still care about that !

Comment: But at what point do the "tiny edits" stop? Do we start correcting paragraphs? Semi-colons? Do we change "organize" to "organise" if the OP is British? - the point I was trying to make is that this is a quirk of community moderation, everyone has a different expectation of what an "improvement" is so I think it's best to approve edits based on what _value_ they add to the post and not what the approver sees fit to eradicate their pet hates.

Answer (score 5):

- Fixing spelling and grammatical errors improves the authenticity of this website. No matter how minor it's!
- The code won't compile with a misspelled **initalize** it won't even compile with **Initialize**. Even though it's just a single letter! It's a mistake and needs to be fixed.
- I've spent my time fixing more than 500 posts, many with single letter typos in headline. I'm proud of it. Those posts are more readable now, both to us and the search engines. And I learned a lot along the way, reading 500 posts on SO!
- I'll start writing more answers at some point for sure. But I think editing questions could be a good starting point for anyone interested in getting into this community!
- Don't forget that the cap of 2000 points is in place to prevent members to get millionaires by this method!
- In [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/253512#253512) you can read more about this issue!