# Updating dead links in answers: edit or comment?

Tags: discussion

I came across a few suggested edits which focus on updating dead links.

Should these edits be approved or rejected? (With the reason: *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."*)

Comment: Why would you reject them if they are good (i.e. actually fix a dead link)?

Comment: Thats a good point. But who would be best to decide the link is good or not? The reviewer or the original author? I see, the Author!!

Comment: If it is not obvious to you whether the replacement is actually good, skip. If it is obvious to you that the replacement is _bad_ (i.e. spam), reject.

Comment: Approve. Let interested people fix the rubbish on this site. (Assuming you take the time to confirm the link is correct)

Comment: Question from the reviewer's standpoint: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303534/1426891

Comment: I don't get whats the point of keeping a dead link on an answer as its not helping anyone and it waste a person time. I can mention that in a comment but people will still see broken link first before looking at comments.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I would not reject an dead link update if it fixed the link.  That said, that only applies if there are no major issues that still need to get fixed in the question/answer and the link is actually dead.

When evaluating if a link looks like a good replacement if the text describing what information the link is going to give me matches what is presented then that is fine.  If the link was changed to a archive.org archive of the website then that is fine too as it is a capture from that point in time.

If you can't easily tell then just skip the review.  There is no harm of not evaluating something you don't know.  If the link is garbage/spam then reject it.  If you can tell it is a bad link and you want to invest the time to find a good one then reject and edit and replace the dead link with a working one.

My main reason for not just leaving this up to the author is what if the author doesn't participate anymore.  Who is going to fix it then?  There should be enough qualified people on here able to fix a dead link where it does not need to be an author only thing.

Comment: + `There should be enough qualified people on here to be able to fix a dead link where it does not need to be an author only thing.`

Comment: One more think also be keep in mind While approve/reject edit links that Original link should be broken or not working otherwise it is conflict with user interest.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName I have added that into the first paragraph.  Thanks.

Comment: "That said, that only applies if there are no major issues that still need to get fixed in the question/answer": That sounds way too broad. If all you mean is, "The post is so bad it should just be closed/deleted instead," then sure. But if the post is valuable in spite of problems and fixing a broken link helps, then by all means, approve it. If you feel like you can fix the other problems in addition, go for it, but don't reject an actual improvement. Could you elaborate on what "major problems" means above? It's really vague as is.

Comment: @jpmc26 If I see an dead link edit to a post like: `I are try to ouput int var to screen.  I try method that here found[dead link].  error give me xxxx and code: [code sample here]` I would reject it as there are many things that need to get fixed least of all the link.  Remember that a question or answer should be able to stand by itself without any links so  just fixing the link would be no improvement what so ever.

Comment: That would fall into the "post is so bad it should just be closed/deleted instead" category, in my opinion. I'm really looking more for clarification in the area in between good and bad. An example: A post uses horrible grammar but can still be read and understood and is sufficiently narrow, and someone submits a link fix. I consider the grammar a "major problem" with the post, but I wouldn't reject the change.

Comment: I guess we disagree on this.  This relatred post has some good discussion on edits: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site

Answer (score 13):

Personally I would approve the update *as long as* it's obviously either:

1. pointing to the exact dead-linked resource in its new home,
2. pointing to an archive.org mirror of the exact dead-linked resource, or
3. deleting (or adding a strikethrough) to the dead link, to avoid readers wasting their time.

All of those three improve the experience of someone trying to gain value from the question or answer while still holding true to the original poster's intent and contribution. Seems pretty reasonable to me. I also agree with Mat's comment and NathanOliver's answer that *if you can't easily tell, just skip it*.

I'm not concerned about bumping it back into the 'recently updated' feed, as the whole reason for the edit is that the question/answer has evidently been *recently viewed and curated*. Though the "major issues" caveat applies, I also wouldn't apply a high bar to "link-only" or "link-heavy" answers, as that's a problem with the answer and not with the edit. Low-quality answers should be flagged or downvoted, and helpful edits should be approved, and those actions don't need to be combined.

Answer (score -20):

I tend to reject vote if that is the only edit being done, but not always. Let me start by reasoning when I would vote it's okay: when it is really clear that a link broke because a site's domain was changed and the new link points to exactly the same resource, or when the link contains a typo - in which case I would vote okay if it is in a recent question, but not if it is in an older question which would bump it back into activity.

But usually when I see broken links being fixed, they link to entirely different resources that might or might not explain the same thing in the same way. Why do I reject those rather than skip? Because a site rule is to make questions and answers not link-only but include the important bits in the question/answer itself. As such a broken link should not be a loss of information. So I can reject with a certain security that its "no improvement whatsoever" or should be posted as a comment. Maybe the edit is an improvement because the target was already link-only, but that too makes it no improvement because the target should be flagged, not edited.

Comment: so you rather want the answer "defective" with a broken link than having it become "recently active"? To me it sounds very strange (or rather even destructive) to even consider this criteria.

Comment: Interesting. I've seen many suggested edits to fix broken links in the past, and almost every single one was correctly fixing the link to point to the same information it used to. I guess we haven't been seeing the same edits.

Comment: @DanGetz perhaps not, I've only been starting recently so you probably have had more time to get a wider sample range. Too bad I get downvotes but no explanations why, I tried to be as precise as possible to hopefully learn what I might be doing right and wrong.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit take note of my reasoning: the question/answer should not become defective because of a broken link, the relevant information should already be present in the question/answer itself.

Comment: @Gimby yes i got that part already, but that's where i digress from your view: for me a defective link is not as good as a working link (unless maybe there *really* should not be a link at all). So for me your statement still translates to "I'd rather have worse content than having it become active". Now let's say the link truly is obsolete. Wouldn't it be better to remove the link altogether than leave a defect one? I would think so. And in this case i think one should do the right thing (decline + remove link) or just skip it altogether (no voting at all)..

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because other reviewers have (like myself and @DanGetz) experienced almost no really bad link fix suggestions and a lot of perfectly legitimate ones.

Comment: Neither agree nor disagree with the post, but I see why many people would disagree by downvoting - your post reads as you would mainly "reject" edit, while most people consider better action to be either "reject and improve" (if *you* feel that links should not be updated inline) or "improve".

Comment: Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong to have seriously downvoted post on meta as it allows people to support different opinions (META votes on answers are really "agree"/"disagree" rather than "your answer is badly written")