# Should I approve edits that simply appear to update a hyperlink?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

In going through the suggested edit review queue, one type of edit that comes up with fair frequency is one which simply edits a hyperlink in an answer (more common) or a question.

My instinct has been to reject such comments (under the heading "Attempt to reply") with the thinking that the proper course of action if a user finds an outdated link is to comment on the post signalling for the author to update the link, presumably after having done due diligence on confirming that the old link has fallen out of favor (website down, outdated, etc.) *and* that the proposed website is a preferred/approved substitute.

Given that I see such suggested edits more than infrequently, I am now reaching out to meta to garner some opinions on whether this is the accepted practice, as I do see *some* arguments in favor of accepting such edits (e.g., alacrity).

So am I correct to reject suggested edits to hyperlinks? Are there any powerful arguments to do the opposite?

Comment: Well, depends IMHO: If the answer was a link only answer, it should be deleted at all, if not, updating the given link (especially if it was dead), should be considered an improvement.

Comment: Regarding your "...with the thinking that the proper course of action if a user finds an outdated link is to comment on the post...", there's a reason SO allows editing other people's answers, so if you as a user are unsure about an updated link, then post as a comment, but if you fix a broken link and don't change the actual content behind it, then I'd say editing is the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps it is also interesting to read up on this topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them/ (fixed hyperlink to start at question instead of an answer)

Comment: Why would you reject a change that improves the answer?

Comment: @DavidWallace obviously that's an oversimplification, as the core issue in this question was basically what to do with such suggested edits in fields in which were blank-slate ignorant (i.e., in which we'd have to invest an inordinate amount of time in order to judge whether indeed an improvement was endowed by the edit). Both answers below address this cogently.

Comment: Well, if you can't tell whether the edit is an improvement or not, then you should obviously SKIP the edit.

Comment: @DavidWallace yes, in (condescending) summary

Comment: Related question, from the editor/commenter's standpoint: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300024/1426891

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You have to take each case on its own merits. When a suggested edit is just updating an hyperlink I'd be thinking to check the following:

1. Is the original link dead or pointing at **completely** incorrect information (i.e. the site's been taken over by someone else)?

   If so then I'd be more inclined to accept the edit.
2. Does the new link point to an incorrect or spam link? in other words is it pointing to the correct information.
3. Does the new link point to a domain that might be owned by the suggester?
4. Are there any obvious referrer tags in the link?

   If so then I'd be thinking to reject the edit and even flag the behaviour to the moderators.

If you're not happy about doing this level of investigation then just skip that review and move onto the next.

Comment: Funny this question comes up just now. Had a [reject](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9285279) for updating a link just two days ago. Should I repeat the edit?

Comment: One other to consider is the un-shortening of URLs. One must be careful, of course, that the person un-shortening the URL is doing it properly, but I feel that it's a legitimate edit.

Comment: @f_puras That's a tough one. You did attempt to fix a broken link. Your corrected link does work, and is an appropriate link in the context of that answer. However, it seems like your corrected link is just going to break again the same way in the not-so-far future.

Comment: @hvd That's right. I failed in finding an alternative which will remain valid. So should the link be removed altogether? Replacing it with e.g. [http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation) does not feel right either...

Comment: @f_puras Agreed that that wouldn't be right. I don't have an answer, sorry. I can understand your edit suggestion, I can understand the rejection, and I don't have a better edit suggestion.

Comment: @hvd No problem, I didn't expect a _That's it!_ answer. Yet maybe this discussion will increase people's awareness for the built-in pitfalls.

Answer (score 86):

Commenting that the link is broken isn't especially helpful, and this community has a long and lovely history of editing others' posts to improve them. That is part of the social contract of posting on Stack Exchange - your content is subject to editing by others, who hopefully seek to improve and maintain it.

Broken hyperlinks are a pervasive problem, especially on posts more than a year or two old. When you encounter them in the edit queue, **verify the updated link actually points to the correct/appropriate target site**, and approve them.  Fixing a broken link is very *helpful*, not harmful. Everything posted here is meant to be long-lived, meaning the community bears responsibility for keeping it in good order.  Sometimes that means downvoting old, obsolete answers, sometimes it means adding new content to old answers, and *often* it means fixing links.

I would never consider it "too minor" an edit, worthy of rejection.

Of course, this is all assuming the edit is that of a link to valid and relevant content. Be especially on the lookout for spam links posted as edits.

Comment: My conundrum with this line of thinking is that I am in no position to evaluate the vast majority of questions/answers posted on SO--as such I'm in no position to evaluate the old nor the new link without investing an inordinate amount of time. Your suggestion, then, is to simply skip such suggested edits?

Comment: @MichaelChirico If you are in doubt as to whether it is valid, yes I suggest you skip it. That should be the action you take on any edit you're unsure of (or anything in the other review queues)