# Is it OK to systematically edit the questions titles like this?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

Should I continue removing tags from titles and reword the questions titles with actual English sentences even if it troubles the OP?

---

I follow mostly Apple-related questions. It includes tags for [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS), [OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29), [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), etc.

There's an annoying trend with these questions, mostly coming from iOS developers: they use many tags in the question's *title*, making it difficult to read when listing the questions by tags.

Even more annoying: many of these persons confuse the programming language (Swift mostly, but sometimes also Objective-C) with the platform (iOS, OS X) or its frameworks ([Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29), Cocoa-Touch, UIKit, ...), or even worse, with the IDE ([Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode)).

So I've developed the habit of editing these questions: I remove the tags from the title and put relevant tags in the tags section.

While I'm at it, I often fix typos and formatting in the question body, and by doing so I'm able to detect what the user is actually asking, and I reword the title to make it more accurate.

---

OP's question title:

> xcode iphone automatically resize image swift

My edit:

> How to automatically resize an image in iOS?

Then I set the tags to "swift", "ios" and "UIImage", and remove the "xcode" tag.

Even if the question is actually not related to the programming language, but rather to the framework, I understand that OP specifically wants an answer example in *this* language instead of a broader framework usage answer, so I let it be in the tags most of the times (I remove the language tag when the question is 100% about the platform and could be answered in many languages or does not require code at all).

---

**Is this Ok? Should I continue doing this? Or should I learn to let go?**

Because I feel like I should actually *enforce* this even more strictly... but of course, sometimes the OP is not happy with these changes and rolls back the edit, so now I'm having serious doubts. Also, when I make several edits of this kind, I'm the one who's polluting the "active" page because all you can see is posts edited by me...

Comment: Turning crap titles into something readable is great. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Only if the questions (or the answers) are worth someone finding.    There is no point giving a bug questions a good title.

Comment: Related: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: *"How to automatically resize an image in iOS?"* Why did you leave the `ios` tag in the title? (And yes, what you're doing, as described, is great and a service to the site.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: In fact, he *added* it (the original tag was [iphone]) ;) If I were to hazard a guess, it's because a title like "How to automatically resize an image?" is so generic that chances are it was already taken.

Comment: @BoltClock: Most likely. :-)

Comment: Is there a post somewhere abo to find bad titles? I.e. All titles with two words or less may be candidates

Comment: @Bobby Titles must be above 15 chars, but still good point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

*"Is this Ok? Should I continue doing this?"*

## Yes.

Information like that belongs in the question's *tags*, not in its *title*.

You needn't go out of your way to edit titles that happen to mention a tag, but if it's just used like keywords, edit them out.

> Examples:
>
> - **Bad**: C# Math Confusion
> - **Good**: Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?
> - **Bad**: [php] session doubt
> - **Good**: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?
> - **Bad**: android if else problems
> - **Good**: Why does str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"?
>
> ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Any specific guidance about editing questions which have been inactive for quite some time? Should we care or not care to bump them back into the active tab? I'm not exactly sure given that it helps to have clean titles in order for duplicate title matches to succeed, but on the other hand pelting a large amount of inactive questions into the active tab just pushes away questions which actually are active.

Comment: I don't really see the problem with those edited questions re-appearing in the "active" tab. As long as the edit improves the question, and fixes as much in it as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not specific enough: I mean in the context of this question, which is about editing out tags from the titles - and I can assume that this is not going to limit to only one, that is the act of cleaning up a large pile of them at once "while you're at it". Of course if there is a lot to improve in a question then you should only be looking for coffee and not reasons to not do it.

Comment: Thank you @Cerbrus for your answer. I have no doubts left and will continue trying to improve this type of questions.

Comment: Personally, I would advice against _actively searching for_ such bad titles, to avoid flooding the "active" tab too much. But whenever you come across a bad title, feel free to edit it.

Comment: Theoretically, editing the titles to be more accurate will improve SEO which will also make questions easier to find from Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo/whatever, which is good for everybody. Flooding the active tab would be worth the benefit IMO.

Comment: @Jakar there's a flipside to this, which is that putting an SEOed title on an irredeemably shitty question will draw more traffic to that question, which is a bad thing and pointlessly wastes people's time. Sometimes trying to save an awful question can actively cause harm, and it's better to leave it to die a quiet death.

Comment: @MarkAmery it could be a good thing to draw traffic to a "shitty" question. Maybe with the increased traffic it'l actually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @KevinB ... at which point Googlers will still have their time wasted by it. Google doesn't care about question score, as far as I know (though I'd be seriously impressed if they somehow did). Question downvotes can be helpful (beyond symbolically punishing people for bad content) in that somebody arriving on the page can rapidly see that the question probably sucks and choose not to waste their time on it, but obviously using that as an argument in favour of Googlers coming across shitty questions is kind of self-contradictory.

Comment: If title is bad and question is not good either (and no views) - consider if it should be closed/downvoted instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't edit VLQ questions indeed, I flag or downvote and/or vote to close. Editing those would be a waste of time for me and, I think, would even cause confusion by going up the active tab and waste other's people time. In my post I talk about when the *titles* are terrible but the questions are, mostly, worth saving.

Comment: I don't know if I should be surprised or relieved there haven't been any crazies saying the "in PHP" in one of your examples is also a title tag and shouldn't be included.

Comment: Not _my_ examples ;-) But yea, kinda relieved here.

Comment: @pnuts: You are conflating keywords with tags. There is a difference between removing a discrete [tag] from the title field, and outright butchering the *title* itself. If the question had a [session] tag would you have changed the title to "How can I redirect users"? How is that a more meaningful title?

Comment: @pnuts: you're taking the definitions too literally. Basically: don't use tags on their own in a tile, but if a word in the title / question happens to be a tag, it's not a big deal.

Comment: I obviously meant "keyword" in the grammatical sense, not the digital technology sense. We're talking about writing titles here.

Comment: @MarkAmery: *"Google doesn't care about question score..."* I wouldn't be so sure about that. SO is clearly very much something Google's search engine team are aware of; questions show up on Google's results within seconds of being posted, for instance. I wouldn't be at all surprised if votes and/or possibly closure were taking into account. But like you, I have no *knowledge* that they do, just that they index SO much more aggressively than most sites. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: They are taken into account, in fact sometimes incorrectly :) I don't have a link handy but I recall seeing a meta post or two about Google labeling closure notices as "top answer" in their search results.

Comment: @BoltClock: And hopefully their SE engineers then \*facepalm\* 'd. :-)

Comment: I am one of those who very often removes language names from title and I just removed *css3* from *How to build delayed loop animation with two different objects consecutively css3?*. CSS3 was already tagged and my opinion was the *css3* didn't really add much value because it didn't even form a proper sentence. Looking at your comment makes me re-think. Would it better then to formulate it as *How to build delayed loop CSS3 animation with two different objects consecutively?* (or something similar, you get the idea) instead of totally removing it @BoltClock

Comment: @Harry: If it doesn't seem to fit the sentence structure, then it's very likely a title tag and I would certainly remove it. You don't have to keep the word in the title, but as the saying goes, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks @BoltClock I have removed language names in a few other cases where the title wasn't bad even with it (ofcourse, I was also making other more meaningful changes to the post in general). Must re-think that.

Comment: @Harry: If there is already a well-written title, but you're finding yourself butchering the title just for the sake of removing some keyword that's already in the tags, it's probably better to just leave it alone. If the word seems to exist separately from the title and removing it doesn't make the title worse or change its meaning in any way, then it's a tag. If the title consists of nothing but tags... then there's no title.

Answer (score -14):

Generally speaking, you are doing a good thing.  However, I would avoid removing language tags, as the tag may be the only indication that the poster wants an answer relevant to that language.  It's extremely rare for the questioner to be willing to learn a new language to solve his problem.

Comment: I always let/set the language tag in the tags section of course, so there's no risk about that. I only remove it altogether if the question is 100% about a framework and not related to a specific language.