# Does the help center suggest including tags in titles?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Whilst leaving another `[ask]` comment suggesting a user reads our guidelines on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting, I noticed the following in the section on titles (emphasis mine)..

> Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, **key APIs**, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

continuing on to give examples

> Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

Now this seems to contradict what is said in the "Should I use tags in titles?" section of the [tagging help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and the ever popular ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

> You should not force a tag into your title. Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for....
>
> ...Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:
>
> - [question title] in [tag]

Have I misinterpreted this or does this need changing?

Comment: It's better than `PHP - How can I redirect users...`.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to systematically edit the questions titles like this?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this)

Answer (score 5):

The idea is not to just dump tags in the question's title:

- *"How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?"*

Versus:

- *"Redirect users to different pages based on session data? [PHP]"*

The first example shows how a "tag" *can* be used, while the second one is how it *shouldn't* be used.

Comment: So you're saying that the difference between these two articles is whether or not the tag is actively included into the question? I can understand that it just doesn't seem to be what is mentioned in my last quote since the "in PHP" can be inferred from the questions tags. I'm not disagreeing with you here, I just sometimes spend some effort in removing this preceeding "in X" along with the rest of my edit