# The search engine seems to encourage adding language tags to titles

Tags: discussion, tags, search, title

I know that we can add programming languages to tags and it is the wrong approach to add the programming language to the question title (it is redundant).

I noticed that most of questions are using the wrong approach and the current search engine is encouraging it.

Lets assume that I am looking for a specific code to replace strings in java. I search this term: `java replace strings`. The search engine gives higher priority to questions with "java" in their title while those questions are following a wrong approach.

I think the search engine should check tags at first and give higher priority to questions with `java` in their tag and not in their title.

Should we change the way that current search engine is working?

Comment: Proper search would probably be `[java] replace strings`

Comment: Tags are very often so wrong that I think they should not be prefered over explicit mentioning of certain areas (programming languages etc.). For instance [objective-c] is meant to be used for the language obj-c but yet you will find it attached to almost every osx/ios programming question. Same for [mysql-workbench], which is used in many generic mysql questions. IMO tags are only good for subscribers to get questions they are interested in prefiltered.

Comment: @MikeLischke So people should edit the filters if they do not apply. I remove them all the time from questions. I did it 3 times today if I remember correctly.

Comment: Tbh I gave up on tag editing. It would be my major task at SO instead of answering questions. There's rarely a question where the assigned tags are correct and IMO there are too many tags anyway.

Comment: @epascarello “proper search” would be whatever’s intuitive and not obviously wrong. It’s the engine’s job to deliver useful results, not the user’s job to conform to entirely arbitrary technical restrictions.

Comment: Personally I never actually search on the site itself, that's what google's for right? Google FYI also appears to prefer the tag in the title (I've not analysed this it's more of a passing impression so feel free to tell me I'm wrong anyone)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It isn't that the programming language shouldn't be in the title at all, it's that the title should still read as a sentence if it's there. People just adding it as a tag in the title is what's discouraged. From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **Bad:** [php] session doubt
>
> **Good:** How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

*I think the search engine should check tags at first and give higher priority to questions with java in their tag and not in their title.*

You'll get the behavior you want if instead of searching for "java replace strings" you use "[java] replace strings" so that the search engine knows to look in the [java] tag and not just look for the text "java".

Your suggestion would require the search engine to treat every word in the query as a tag.

Comment: No: it just require that every word in the title, if it matches a tag, gets more "juice" from the tag match than from a title match

Comment: @Yakk - But then how do you prevent that if you really just want a certain word to be a text search and not a tag? Just because I have the word "interest" in my query doesn't mean questions in the [[interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interest)] tag should get more "juice".

Comment: If you want interest, but not the interest tag, type `interest -[interest]`?  Yes, you lose access to "treat `[interest]` as irreverent but still look for the word `interest`", but boo hoo?

Comment: @Yakk - So instead of "[java] search strings" people have to type in "java search strings -[search] -[strings]"? How is that an improvement?

Comment: how so?  'Java search strings' would prefer things with that in the tags, then those words in the title, and then those in the body.  Why wouldn't you want something tagged as search string java in your search results above "I need to write a program to search for java bean and cheese string producers from a database. The two kinds of sellers have different subtables.  How should I arrange the database? `[sql] [access] [C#]`"

Comment: @BSMP On an unrelated note is the [interest] tag even worthwhile?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - I don't think so. There's no guidance and the only two questions using it are about calculating interest.

Comment: I agree with this, and @Yakk sorry you are complicating search even more.

Comment: Yakk is right, everybody else is wrong. Accusing him of “complicating search even more” is hilariously off the mark: Yakk’s suggestion makes the *search engine implementation* more complicated, but searching itself easier. That’s exactly what computers should do: automate our work. This answer and the comments are essentially saying, to OP, “you’re using search wrong”. That’s a terrible response. Fix the search, not the user.

Comment: To me that language is difficult in itself, maybe theoretically he is right but entering search terms like that could drive anyone insane.

Comment: @JonH The point is *you won't*.  When you search for `java` or `string`, you *probably want things tagged with java and string* (and also things with those words in the title or contents).  In the small corner case where you want to search for the word `string` but not the tag `[string]` you have to do `string -[string]`.  It is possible, but awkward: the common case is easy (where your words matching tags as well as words is helpful), and the uncommon case is hard (where you want the word, but not the tag).  I only mentioned it because BSMP did first: it would rarely be used.

Comment: Telling people how they should search is pointless. They search how they search for everything, it should be intuitive.

Answer (score 12):

I think it would be great if the search box had similar logic to the tag field in a question.  As you type it could try to match a tag - if you want to use the tag in your search just click it to tag-ify the text, otherwise leave the plain text to search as a token in the normal way.

The tag editor for posts only allows valid tags but there's no reason that the search box couldn't accept both tags and text.  The search box could also, for example, auto-tagify tokens enclosed in square braces if they match (to preserve behaviour for those who have square braces, and tags verbatim, burned into their muscle memory).

[image]

For myself, I'm happy to just use square braces in my own searches but a lot of users, I expect, have no idea that they can do this - especially the users that really need to be using the search function.

Answer (score 4):

Another consideration is that duplicate titles are not allowed.  So for example, you can search for "Java exception handling", "Python exception handling", and "C++ exception handling", and without the language name, you cannot differentiate those questions.  If there was some way to allow duplicate question titles (I know there are lots of sensible reasons not to allow them), I would be more in favor of a general rule discouraging language names in titles.  As the site exists today, I think it's actually helpful to have the language in the title for lots of different kinds of questions, and having the search function prioritize those keywords is also helpful.

Comment: No language tags in titles is (was?) the consensus when I asked: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this (of course there's exceptions but they're rather well defined)

Comment: @EricD.: That's a (common?) misunderstanding of the post. Consensus is not forcing tags into titles, and correcting those bad tites.

Comment: @Deduplicator Actually, it's just a poorly phrased comment from me, because what you just said is what I understood then and what I agree with. I apologize for the previous comment, it was written without thinking much about it.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I get pretty sick of titles ending "in language-name" when I've filtered my view to questions tagged with language-name and said language is the only one relevant to the question. I take a more lenient view toward questions that ask how to use an idiom from one language in another.

Comment: @dfeuer: Sure. Imho, those are just on the wrong side of "force tag into title".