# Encourage adding language to the forefront of the title

Tags: discussion, questions, title

OK, this is to stir up some discussion over the conclusion made in
[The search engine seems to encourage adding language tags to titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316990)

I totally agree with the argument that search engines encourage adding language tags to titles, and don't quite agree with the provided answer.

Please consider, that most people do a search, they tend to search from search engines first, instead of directly do searching in Stack Overflow. Encouraging searching within Stack Overflow aside, which is another topic, but currently the fact is most people search from search engines first.

So it appears that the conclusion from the above answer is:

> **Bad:** PHP: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data
>
> **Good:** How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

However, this is where I disagree. Think of the case I'm searching for "*redirect to different pages*" using **Java**, or **C#**, or whatever, then I have to wade through the long title till the end to find what the question is for.

- This is not very friendly to users searching for answers. I know some people will argue that "*you can always find the language at the end*", however, this is not always the case. Nobody can guarantee that.
- What is worse, when the title is this long, the ending part will be trimmed from the search engine prompt, so you have no idea what the question is about from the search engine hit.

The above is what I always bump into when doing searches for `Go` language. Here is a concrete example:

[image: search engine hits]

We can see that,

- For the two hits on the bottom, people would have *no idea* which language the question is about because the title is so long that the ending part are trimmed from the search engine prompt
- For the two hits in the middle, people have to *wade through the long title* to find which language the question is for.
- For the hit on the top, I think that is the recommended way to do, as people would know within a split of a seconds that this is a Go question.

The hit on the top is what I put in as the title, unfortunately, [someone took the "Go:" out from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380054). So the next time people search, they will have no idea which language the top hit is, and they have to open it up to see.

All I'm trying to say is, Let's make it as friendly as it can be to help people searching. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Downvotes on meta are people disagreeing with you, they don't mean it's a bad question. How would you title a question that uses multiple languages and how would you enforce this other than advising people to do it?

Comment: This is something Google should do on their side. Let Google display the language in front(on their search res. page) , if they want .  If we added it to stack though , things would get messy

Comment: What you are asking for is already happening automatically: the most popular tag (IIRC) is added to the question title for search engines  to see. Not sure why they are not showing up for results #2 and #3, I'm guessing their age is the reason. Can't find a reference for all this right now though

Comment: I'm upvoting for good thinking, even though I agree encouraging people to add the language this way is not a good idea. That this is a relevant issue is confirmed by the fact that the team did something to fix it; the OP had no way of knowing this had already been automated at some point in time.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure they did.  They could have done their research, as this has been brought up a number of times.  This isn't some hidden feature.

Comment: @Servy I tried to find a meta post about this, and failed - and I *knew* it existed from being a long-time Meta member. Also, look closely at the search results in the question - would you have guessed that there's an automated feature at work? Really?

Comment: @Pekka웃 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tags+in+title

Comment: @Servy I fail to find any clear indication of this feature in the first couple of search results.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Two of the top five results have the information there or link to canonical sources in the help center or on meta.SE that have the information.  If you read the titles first to specifically look at questions asking basically the same thing as this question (there are several in the first page) you'll find the answer that much more quickly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Really?  clicking on the first link in the first question serves up [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/4342498) which looks pretty clear.

Comment: @NathanOliver but where in that question does it say "we have an automated feature that takes the most relevant tag from each question and puts it in the `<title>` tag to make sure that search engines can see it"?

Answer (score 24):

> Please consider, that most people do a search, they tend to search from search engines first, instead of directly do searching in stackoverflow. Encouraging searching within stackoverflow aside, which is another topic, but currently the fact is most people search from search engines first.

This is exactly why the site already does this for the search engines so we don't have to.

We don't have to, because us readers don't need to see the tag in the title when there's already an entire section devoted to a question's tags — by which time we're already past the SERPs and in the site itself.

> For the two hits on the bottom, people would have no idea which language the question is about because the title is so long that the ending part are trimmed from the search engine prompt

But you make a good point here; in the first question, the "dir" tag is not terribly useful, and ideally should be removed from the question's tag list altogether. What about the second question? It's not entirely clear to me why the question wasn't prefixed with a tag keyword. Does one of its tags already appear within the title? Perhaps.

> For the two hits in the middle, people have to wade through the long title to find which language the question is for.

This probably makes a good case for people in the "titles should never have tag keywords, not even in the form of 'in language X'" camp.

> For the hit on the top, I think that is the recommended way to do, as people would know within a split of a seconds that this is a Go question.

The format is actually that of the third hit, with "sorting -". Except it's tagged [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) because, presumably, "BASH:" already appears in the title. So what we actually have is title with a manual keyword prefix *and* an automatic tag prefix... which illustrates exactly why manual keyword prefixes are discouraged, while simultaneously highlighting a flaw in the automatic feature: it cannot distinguish language tags from any other tag.

Comment: Does that mean that tags should be updated to include a `is_language` flag and that can be used to help the automated process?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Maybe. I'm sure there have been requests for such a feature for other purposes.