# Should the coding language be included in the title?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

For example, see this question: *[How to add a subview that has its own UIViewController in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/objective-c-how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller)*.

- Is it generally recommended to include the language name (here Objective-C) in the title?
- If not, is there something that I should edit along with other things I am editing?

Comment: it's debatable. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often

Comment: @KevinB It's debatable? You mean there is no Standard SO policy?

Comment: i mean, we disagree on the right answer. so, yes, i guess, :p I personally remove tags from the title when done in the way it's done in your example, but that could have just as well been changed to "How to... in Objective C"

Comment: so what's the purpose of having objective-c or ios as a tag? it's like noise. And eventually so probably a sweet spot would be to switch the Objective-C to the end? to make it better English and *not* remove a word?

Comment: I find it better to incorporate the language as part of the question (in the title), rather than using it in the title as if it were a tag. The question of course should still be tagged objective C so that users who follow said tag can easily find it. but there's nothing wrong with it not being there at all either, because it should still be tagged.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a tag, no, tags are redundent in the title. However, there's nothing wrong with something that would have otherwise been a tag to be part of the question that makes up the title.

For example, I don't think Objective-C should remain if it is in this format:

> Objective-C - how to add a subview that has its own UIViewController

However, if it were instead in this format, i'd leave it.

> How to add a subview that has its own UIViewController in Objective-C

I can't comment on how useful it really is in this particular case for Objective-C to be in the title at all because I'm not familiar with this language or how common UIViewController is in other languages.

In either case, the question should of course still be tagged [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) so that those following that language can find it.

Comment: Note, also, that the primary tag is automatically prefixed to the title for SEO purposes. That's why people see it, and why they start doing it manually, because they think they're supposed to.