# Reviewing suggested edit with title edit which already exist in tag

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I am new to reviewing suggested edits I was reviewing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19420633)

Original title

> Winsound not working as expected

Edited title

> Python issue: Winsound not working as expected

user comment is changed title to get more attention

As I have seen OP has already tagged python in the question but including the python issue in title is it really affecting to attention?

How should I proceed for reviewing such edit?

Comment: Reject -> Does not make the question easier to read.

Comment: I would reject -> no improvement whatsoever. No point in adding tag in the title at all. Its unlikely it will get more (positive) attention

Comment: @SurajRao I didn't found answer to the question you referred but from comment of it I did found answer [Is it OK to systematically edit the questions titles like this?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606)