# Why was I suspended from review for clicking on share feedback?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

Today, I was reviewing the “First Questions”. I came across a question that according to me required a few more details. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507321/go-1-18-build-error-on-mac-unix-syscall-darwin-1-13-go253-golinkname-mus) is that question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31440192) is the link to review.

I reviewed that question by clicking on the “Share Feedback” button but suddenly this popped up:

[image: Image of a banner with the message "Review audit failed 7 ins ago: Abhyuday Vaish reviewed 7 mins ago: Share feedback"]

I would like to know why doesn't that question require more details such as which version they were using before, what command they used, `PATH` entered, etc.? The OP just wrote *go build fails with errors like*, along with error lines. Can this be considered a detailed question? As far as I know, one must include detailed information about their problem. Even, one cannot edit posts that include only code.

Now, because of this, I'm banned for 4 days. I'm not complaining, I just want to know the reason why it is/should be considered as “Looks Good”.

Comment: The original question had some additional details, which were removed by the edit of another user. No idea if those were really relevant. Regardless, the audits are basically chosen automatically. The 12 upvotes made it eligible as an audit for a "good" question.

Comment: @Turamarth So, is my ban an error?

Comment: If it was an automatic suspension, it’s unfortunate; and might be reversed by a mod. Nevertheless, take into account that review suspensions  are not imposed because of a single failure.

Comment: Could also be provide useful information: [I do not understand why I failed this audit](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Several of your recent reviews are incorrect even though they weren't audits. Eventually an audit is likely to present you with a post like the ones I've highlighted below, or if not a moderator may look through your history like I did and choose to do something about it such as manually suspending you.

I'd therefore encourage you to spend this timeout to do some more research on what is generally expected in a good question and also what isn't.

If you carry on as you are I suspect you'll continue to run into trouble despite having a reasonable case with the one review you've put forward as evidence to the contrary in your question.

- Why is [this question OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31439224) It contains [links to images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and also contains a tag in the title.
- This question has [tags in the title in brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31439693) so [why is it OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31439693)? See [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this) for more information on that.
- [This question is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31402933) despite ending with [Thank you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and not containing any real steps to reproduce the problem.
- [This question is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31410575) despite saying Thanks in advance... at the end. Is a question about how to configure CMS software on-topic do you think?

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you are trying to say here, and... I kinda know a lot about this stuff. Maybe you could add a sentence or two to the very beginning that introduces the links, something like: "Several of your other recent reviews have been incorrect, even though they were not audits...".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about my mistakes. I will definitely improve on them. :)

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish everyone has to learn. All more experienced people have once been where you are now. And if we don't take the time to teach, how is anyone going to get any better?