# Priority of grammar, spelling and punctuation in questions

Tags: discussion

How much priority should be given to grammar, spelling and punctuation when editing a question? How relevant are those? Should questions and answers be edited because of the sole reason there are spelling/grammatical errors?

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/4751173), point 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spelling, grammar and punctuation are quite important if you want to make yourself understood.

Problems in any of these areas not only puts native English speakers off, but it also puts those whose second (or even third) language is English at a disadvantage as they have an additional layer to decipher.

Fixing spelling and grammatical errors should be the primary focus of edits. While you should look at fixing problems with code formatting, you have to be very careful here - edits to code in questions could, if done incorrectly, render the question meaningless.