# Adding a tag received a "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I've been adding missing tags into questions - most often when a tagged item is mentioned in the question itself, but not listed in the tags.

This has been successful for the first half-dozen times.

This time I received the
"Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Surely some mistake?

Problem arose specifically with:
[how can I set a breakpoint in squeak code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322497/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-squeak-code)

Comment: so you were doing ONLY a tag add on this? Not removing the "hey friend" fluff, correcting the "I knows"? Until you hit 2000 rep, your suggested edits need to be reviewed. Please make SURE you correct everything until no one needs to review your edits :)

Comment: The issue I was raising is specifically that for all cases until now, the simplyAddATag operation was successfully placed in a to-be-reviewed queue.

This simplyAddATag operation was not.

And yes, my edit was only to add a tag - it's specific actionable, and I am sure that it will not be reviewed as wrong.

I'm not sure of the conventions on grammar / syntax / de-personalisation of question text, so I'll wait til I have a better grasp of those community conventions before meddling.

Comment: I get that this is what you were asking about, which is why I posted my note as a comment, not an answer. The convention on suggested edits is to correct EVERYTHING about the post, not just adding one or two tags. In this instance, it's asking for more chars? Remove the s from "knows", remove the greeting at the beginning, changed the "wanner" for "wanted". Correct English, and you'll have WAY MORE than 6 chars

Comment: While that would work in this specific instance, it would not work on many other questions.  Unless the convention is also to make arbitrary 6+ char edits even where none are needed, just to work-round this issue?

Comment: Rare is the post that won't benefit from at least a couple new lines, or some missing punctuation here and there. Not saying it's impossible, but I believe you can always find at least 6 chars to change.

Comment: Posts which have previously been edited for grammar, spelling, etc will be (relatively) free of such things.  So far, I'm seeing about 1 in 7 posts requiring such edits in addition to requiring classification.

Comment: "relatively" isn't 100%, so you can surely do this. I've checked and on both the accepted tag edits on your profile, there is AT LEAST a "thanks" that could've been removed. Thanks is 6 chars ;).

Comment: From the official guidelines:
Be nice.

...Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help.  I'm going to repeat that last: "Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help. "  As in "Never just do Task A.  Always do Task A and also  Task B, too"

Comment: I wasn't being nice? I was patient, I assumed good intentions, I told you what the convention is and I explained why it's done this way. If you can show me how I was rude or insulting, go ahead, but honestly, I don't see it. I told you "Never just add tags, always add tags and remove typos/correct punctuations". I posted the same kind of message 4 times to get my point across (I wasn't patient?) If you have something to discuss about the "minimality" of edits, let's discuss that. If you want to devolve into "he's insulting and not nice", that'll just end in a flame war without a point :).

Comment: Or are you using this to say that you shouldn't remove "thanks" from posts? because if that's what you meant, then no. "hi", "thanks", and anything that isn't directly related to the question is useless noise on the question. This is what the community consensus has always been

Comment: You specifically said "never do solely Task A. Always also do Task B".  This was a demand for additional work.  Demanding work is against the stated guideline.

Comment: Fair enough, but I also tell you "the rules", in a nice, welcoming, patient way. How can I be blamed if the consensus IS that you should edit everything at once? Because you may not realize, but you correcting half a post means that someone in his review queue will "reject and improve" if they aren't robo-reviewers, and then have to edit your edit to make it fully proper. In this case, you are the one demanding extra work.

Comment: In which case, the consensus is going against the stated guideline.  In cases of contradiction, I believe the stated guidelines supervene.

Comment: .... sigh. Then have fun, but don't complain if you hit enough non-robo reviewers who reject your edits and you end up banned from editing. I was trying to help but if you can't see how it's supposed to be done.... I'm done :).

Comment: You may want to read up on meta on the subject (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site/253872#253872)

Comment: Granted there is a lot of debate on this, but more recently seems like we've been pushing for "complete edits" not just trivial ones :). Don't overdo it just to do an edit, but if you do edit a post, please take care of everything

Comment: Pushing for <> have had accepted into official guidelines

Comment: then do what you want man. Again, if people don't robo-review, you may end up getting edit banned because of this. This is a fair warning, take heed of it. The community handles the queues, not the guidelines

Comment: and you may need to think about the "be nice" guideline btw. You're currently the one who sounds stubborn and doesn't want to see what's right in front of him...

Comment: Having read the discussion you cited, the most popular answer on the discussion contradicts your opinion.  Let me repeat that: the most popular answer on the thread you cited to support your opinion, contradicts your opinion.  The guidelines contradict your opinion. Perhaps your opinion is not the widespread consensus of either the site or its founders, but is, instead, a strongly-held opinion of a minority?

Comment: If you want me to be less stubborn, please cite either a Meta discussion which supports your view, or a site guideline which supports your view.

Comment: do you need to repeat to put emphasis, really? you get how pushy and defensive that makes you sound? Again, I've been trying to help. You're the one pushing back. Do what you will at this point, I'm done with that debate. If you open a question for "how come I'm banned from review?" think back to this thread ;). I'm a regular meta stalker. I told you what is the CURRENT consensus. Like it or not, this is how it's currently being done. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/ The blog of the creator of the site enough for you?

Comment: "If you are going to edit a post, make sure you're substantively improving it.¶ Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction."

Comment: The point of StackOverflow is to provide searchable answers of good quality. Tags are therefore substantive improvements.  The example given of something minor was an isolated punctuation edit.

Comment: lol... "find something official" and when I do, you fight back. SURE! you're stubborn because of my sources. I'm done

Comment: @Patrice: You should have gone for the help-center, that might be official enough for OP: [Help Center > Our model > When should I edit posts?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) "*Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.*"

Comment: @Deduplicator would not have changed much, he will again say that tags are substantive (sorry for the passive aggressive first comment, I thought you were the OP :/) NOTE: I'm 100% with you, edits should be more than just a tag, especially when the post isn't pristine like the example in the post here.

Comment: You are correct @Patrice - my response is again that Tags - which determine searchability of answers, are substantial.

Comment: @EuanM the fact I'm correct you would push back with that doesn't mean that you are right in thinking it. No need to reply to this.

Comment: @rene No, this is a bug report about the 6 character limit incorrectly causing an error with tag-only edits and the other question asks why that limit exists.

Comment: @DonaldDuck it is not a bug, it is status-bydesign and the duplicate explains why.

Answer (score 5):

If you change anything in the body of the post, *even if you then change it back*, that message will show up every time you try to submit until you reload the editor or make 6+ characters of edits to the body. So if you're going to make a tag-only edit, make sure to keep it tag-only all the way. (Edits to the title, or title-only edits, do not exhibit this, because any title edits at all allow the edit through.)

With that said, I do recommend usually editing more than just tags. Still, occasionally a tag is all that's really needed or practical, so exercise discretion.

Comment: No other change was made, other than the tag add.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to edit posts, there are quite a few things you can do beyond just adding a missing tag.

Not saying you have to but it may be worthwhile trying some more substantial improvements if it complains about the tag add not being substantial enough.

Things like fixing spelling, punctuation, grammar, capitalisation, formatting, content and many other things. When I find myself editing a post, I try to ensure I do as complete a job as possible. Nothing grates on me more than a question like:

```
i need sum Help with where Im at!
```

Of course, if you're not happy with that level of effort (and no-one will hold that against you; from each according to their desire, and so on), you can just bypass those that complain.

But I urge you to not do that, any extra effort you put in makes it easier for other members of the swarm.

Answer (score -5):

The reason that some single-tag adds are accepted, and some are rejected as having too few characters, seems to be a direct result of how long the tag's name-string is.

Adding the tag 'glass' will result in "Edits must be at least 6 characters"

Adding the synonymous tag 'aero-glass' will be accepted for vetting.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?  I do not see any edits in your profile that prove that this is the current behavior.

Comment: 'smalltalk' tag adds worked.  smalltalk is a 9 character tag.  About 6 of these were successful, consecutively.

When I moved from 'smalltalk' tags to 'squeak' tag adds, they failed.  squeak is a 6 character tag.

Comment: That is hardly conclusive enough to justify an writing an answer.  By writing an answer, you should be nearly 100% confident that the behavior your are describing is correct.  What you have here is potentially a bug and probably should be edited into your question rather than written as an answer.

Comment: I agree that it's potentially a bug.  That's why I tagged it as a `bug`.  Deterministic behaviour on either side of a deterministic limit, such as "6 chars" is all that's required to be reasonably certain - if all other variables are kept equal.  As they were in these cases.