# Is just fixing a typo in the title a valid suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

A user has made [191 suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5510001/myusername?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) in a span of five hours, [most](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349567) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349561) [which](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349557) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349508) [just](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349441) [correction](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349440) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349410) a [typo](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349404) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349356) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349355) [title](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10348999), and around 180 of them have been approved. I have [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349013) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10348930) [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10349564) some I have come across. Is just fixing a typo in the title a valid suggested edit?

Comment: Is there more to be edited in the post(s)?

Comment: In the ones I have seen and rejected and edited they were.

Comment: then to me it's an incomplete suggested edit. I know not everyone on the site sees it this way, but I think a suggested edit, where you ask someone else (more than one actually) to look into your edit, NEEDS to address everything

Comment: I guess he just wants SO to be thankful today that there's even a suggested edit system in place.

Comment: Maybe not everything but at least something a tad more substantial than a typo @Patrice

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to ask yourself one question. Do you feel.. no wait .. not that. The question is whether or not the edit fixes all the problems in the post. If it does, then it's fine. If it doesn't, then feel free to reject (and possibly improve).

Of course there is the edge-case where to overlooked issue is so trivial that it can be forgiven. But that's up to you to weigh.

Answer (score 5):

I believe titles count relatively heavily in searches, so they should be corrected even for typos, more so than the body. If there is more that needs attention, *Accept and Edit*. This story that it wastes the time of five reviewers is nonsense. The suggester draws it to your attention and you fix it - that's only two people, one of whom should be trustworthy enough to handle what the suggester may not be able to.

EXCEPT when the rest of a post is an outright shambles! (Then *Reject*.)

Comment: I don't care so much about "wasting the time of reviewers". What I do care about is educating those who don't have full editing privileges yet. This is the only teaching period we have. So no better time to tell them "when you edit, take care of all that is wrong".

Comment: You're absolutely wonderful then. But I would not at all be surprised if the majority of users went for a simple "hey I got rep, I must have been doing it right then" approach. After all, that's what we're telling them by accepting; well done, have some points. There is nothing there which tells them "but please also look at X, Y and Z"

Comment: I'm not of the "everybody is a winner" and "an A for effort" mentality when it comes to this. I'm afraid we'll disagree there. I wouldn't describing rejecting an edit as "chastising" either though. It's really not a big deal. A simple learning moment.

Answer (score 3):

If there's more to fix, then no, the edit is not sufficient.  Rejecting or rejecting and editing are appropriate actions to take.

If there's an extreme pattern of this behavior from this user - that is, a huge amount of their edits are just edits to the title, leaving the rest of the post, then a custom flag would be appropriate to bring a moderator in on the matter.