# Guidance on fixing posts with typos in the title

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, title, typographical-error

I have recently been trying to clean up some of the egregious typos on Stack Overflow to help make the information more searchable. For example, if someone uses "Javacript" in the title, instead of "JavaScript", the question and answer, though possibly containing useful information, may not appear in the Stack Overflow search results for "JavaScript" (it may appear way down the results list if the correct spelling appears in the text somewhere).

A search on Stack Overflow for "javacript" reveals 92 *pages* of results. And there are approximately 19 gazillion others - "matalab", "pyhton", etc. Kind of like the secret auctions on [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) with misspellings of common items.

I realize that the guidelines for editing state that we should make substantial edits, so I have avoided editing posts that only have one or two typos in the body, or low rated or duplicate posts. However, given the high weight given to search keywords in titles, I think fixing typos in question titles is very important, and useful to Stack Overflow. Not everyone seems to agree.

Lately, I've noticed two reviewers that consistently reject my edit suggestions when I try to fix questions with typos in the titles. I try to review the rest of the post and see if there is anything else that needs editing (the suggested guidance here *[Is just fixing a typo in the title a valid suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311224/is-just-fixing-a-typo-in-the-title-a-valid-suggested-edit)*), and sometimes there just isn't.  Many of these posts have been edited multiple times and *still* have egregious typos in the title.

So are we, as a Community going to accept that some of our questions just have bad titles, and will not show up in the intended search results? I've wasted a lot of time trying to fix some of these posts just to have my edits rejected by these same  reviewers, so I'd like to get some feedback from the community before I spend more time trying to fix these kinds of posts.

Comment: My initial impressions of your suggestions is you're making good edits.  As far as seeing the same reviewers, reviewers can filter suggestions based on tags.  So having the same people reject all the `javacript` errors are probably filtering with the real `javascript` tag.

Comment: The last few rejected edits appear to have been for edits to questions that had a lot of other problems that could have been fixed. Are you asking about edits that get one or two rejections, but are eventually approved? I wouldn't worry about those.

Comment: What is Javascript?  JavaScript, I've heard of:)

Comment: [A somewhat longer list](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2016-01-31.html) (it also includes those two)... Most have been observed in the wild and mostly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is almost no reason to include the name of the language / technology in the title when it is included in the tags (with JavaScript it is always the case). Everyone filters by tags and they are present in the summary along with the title and the first few lines. I would edit it out in almost any case.

Comment: @user1803551: Given a set of posts tagged `javascript`, the posts that rise to the top of a search for "JavaScript" are the ones that contain that word in the title.  Furthermore, I expect more of our search traffic comes from Google than anywhere else, and a high percentage of people searching for information are probably pretty new to the site.   So I don't think you can say "everyone filters by tags".  I presume most people here are proud of the resource that SO has become, and hope to make the site easily accessible to as many as possible.

Comment: Google already caches the tags. It is the site's recommendation to do what I suggest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @gariepy Do not that the name is JavaScript, not [Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34662309/revisions). If you're going to make these edits, please do make them correctly!

Comment: @TylerH: noted  :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The rule is simple: Improve whatever needs improvement.

If the *only* improvement that should be done is in the title, go ahead and edit it, even if it's only one character; However, if the post contains other errors (formation, spelling, bad indentation, etc) you shouldn't only fix that typo in the title, but rather try to edit everything (that what makes the difference when I'm reviewing an edit).

We really shouldn't hesitate about making minimal edits as long as they're the only edits that should be done since any improvement *is* an improvement, and sometimes it might be the only improvement.

Comment: On the other hand, if the *only* edit is to be made in the title, the OP may choose to skip these until he has more than 2K rep points - just to avoid robo-decliners noticing it was the only thing changed.

Comment: I basically agree with you. However, what if someone finds a typo in the title of a post, where he doesn't know enough about the subject matter to also judge the correctness of the remainder of the post (let alone improve it). Should he just let the typo be, because he might miss other needed corrections? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Stibu Well, if you're not sure about a post, leave it for another editor. He'll probably handle it in a better way. But keep in mind that sometimes it's easy format a question even if you're not aware of the language being used.

Comment: @Stibu: If you don't know enough about the post to fix anything but the typo in the title, but know it needs more editing, are you sure fixing the typo is any help to anyone? Probably the title has to be rewritten completely anyway.

Comment: So totally this.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe but at least making the language spelt right is an obvious improvement, _and_ has a chance of making the hypothetical poor title pop up in front of the eyes of those who can fully replace it.