# Deal with typos automatically?

Tags: discussion

Let's consider an example: one can mistype CodeIgniter as CodeI*ng*iter. In fact, not one but [272](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CodeIngiter) guys made such typos at SO (I've fixed something like a dozen a few days ago). Or another one: "fuction" instead of "function", [about 3K posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fuction).

*What harm can this cause?* Let's consider this before discussing any ideas for fixing typos automatically. Aside aesthetics, one can note that

- there's a number of questions with code containing typos ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360648/baffled-by-jquery-error/10360651)). Usually they are flagged and deleted ("off-topic/can't be reproduced" flag) but take an amount of efforts (see also [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319399/3995261))
- sometimes this is exploited by badge hunters who make a number of similar edits which don't help that much and take efforts of reviewers which can be more productive (unfortunately, I haven't saved any links to examples I've seen)
- sometimes this attracts attention of those who review/edit consistently which is probably less harmful but still steals some workhours from community
- this may remove some questions out of search results
- this also may mislead a person who has made a typo in search query themselves (instead of empty results they see those with typos)

*What's the scale of these effects?* Are they of any importance? I'm not sure: it's hard to say without access to stats of reviews and search queries. This is somewhat I'd like to hear from you. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315861/3995261), however, seems to draw some picture here (92 *pages* of results containing Javacript etc).

*Possible solutions*. Questions to consider are: what typos to fix and how to fix them?

Speaking of the first part, I can see some obvious options:

- allow to create tag "misspellings" aside synonyms (like CodeIngiter for CodeIgniter) so that they are autocorrected/suggested to be corrected
- usually *questions* have the corresponding tag so "CodeIngiter" can be automatically found as "CodeIgniter" (tag of the question being asked or answered) with 2 letters switched. This can give false-positives, though: I don't have a witty example at hand, but one can imagine that "lava" may get autocorrected to "java", "CEO" to "SEO" etc
- use something non-tag-based (a special dictionary?) or based on tags that are not necessarily present in the question (the question with `fuction` mentioned above is not tagged `function` but such tag exists)

As for the way of fixing, that could be autosuggestions when creating/editing, autocorrection in the same place or simplified review (0 or 1 reviewer needed to approve the `fuction` → `function` edit which is usually an edit of a title).

Also there can be batch-fixing for obvious problems like the above-mentioned Javacript/JavaScript example. This is something a mod should be able to do, isn't it? This can be suggested and reviewed, too, but probably in Meta since comments are needed (and I've read somewhere that tag synonyms are usually approved only after one posts at Meta anyway). There also can be a simplified reviewing for this (if there's some doubt that this may cause some harm): say, a block saying "this question was automatically corrected, please confirm or refute that the correction is valid" visible to users with say 50+ reputation and the author, with 1 vote being enough and nothing put into review queues.

To me, it seems that autosuggestions would be the best option (so that nothing is wrongly "corrected"); I would think that comparison with all tags would be nice, but obviously that can cause too much load on SO servers (get and compare with all tags for each word with length >4?) unless implemented in a smarter way. Along with batch-correcting + simplified reviews.

Finally, there can be autocorrect suggestions in search fields which may be useful without creating much load to SO.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Is this a feature request?

Comment: Related über-meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23134/implementing-auto-correct-complete-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You're suggesting something be put in place that'll hopefully get things correct without understanding context and likely automatically get things wrong and require correcting vs stuff that requires things correcting which happens anyway?

Comment: Where I work we have a system that is called ['configerator'](https://us.pycon.org/2016/schedule/presentation/2059/). I wouldn't want Stack Overflow to auto-correct that name, it is misspelled **on purpose**.

Comment: @JonClements well, if there's so much doubt, autosuggestions can be used, like I said (not autocorrections)

Comment: @MartijnPieters again, if there's a considerable number of cases where autocorrection causes harm, what do you think about autosuggestions instead?

Comment: Why duplicate the functionality already offered by the browser spellchecker?

Comment: First, most spellcheckers don't know names like `cron` or CodeIgniter so they create noise and are not really helpful. Second, because of this and other things (like poor locale dictionaries or no knowledge of slang) some people (including me) disable them. So they are both not very helpful and not used that widely.

Comment: Ok.... so we should build a full spellchecker without any of these issues? Because unless we have locale dictionary, slang,  name of tools or libraries.....  it'll be as noisy as your spellchecker. Except in this case every mistake it makes is more work for moderation

Comment: @Patrice quite opposite: SO is english-only so you don't have to bother with localisation; names of tools and libraries are already collected as tags; and you usually don't expect slang here. Seems like you haven't read my proposal carefully. But anyway, looks like nobody thinks it deserves any consideration.

Comment: Related: At *17 min 04 secs* in [episode 50 of the (original) Stack Overflow podcast, 2009-04-21](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3) (with [Steve Yegge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Yegge)).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it worth extra advanced infrastructure needed for this feature to work sensibly. Browsers already have spellchecking, so one really need to be very persistent to put misspelled text into a post. And it is easy to correct using existing mechanism (normal editing) for posts that worth it.

SO is probably the worst place to use simple implementations of such feature - since most of sensible words are already taken for some library all new once had to use made up words that will be "auto-corrected" into some other random text. You'd need way more intelligent solution to understand context and guess meaning of each word.

And then there are words like "memoization" which are rarely included in dictionaries. Do you you think "memorize function" and "memoize function" would convey the same meaning in the post? But I bet such edit completely changing the post would be robo-approved (especially if suggested by "SO-provided" infrastructure).

Comment: That's why I've suggested the "misspellings" feature (along to synonyms) and autosuggestion as well as using SO tags as dicitionary (there's a memoization tag). However, you may be right that about all those findrs and flickrs that autosuggestions may be rather irritating.. may depend on implementation, though

Answer (score 1):

While I see the rationale, given that you're able to successfully interpret what is meant by the typo, asking Stack Overflow to come up with an automated system to "fix" this seems unlikely.

Additionally, you could just fix typos as you come across them instead.  You can then mitigate the issues you describe by you doing so.