# Auto-correct bot for common errors

Tags: feature-request, edits, spelling, robots

Wikipedia uses [bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_bots_by_number_of_edits) to do some of the edits and also to correct errors.

I wonder if we can have a similar system and rely on bots here to correct common errors? Then instead of editing posts manually, one can enter the typo and correction to a list that is maintained and has review/edit control.

Examples:

- phython to python
- phyton to python
- im to I'm
- doesnt to doesn't

A [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361566/deal-with-typos-automatically) question is suggesting an AutoSuggest. The proposed solution here relies on a combination of a bot and a list of user-editable typos. The edits on that page are reviewed like any other edits.

Bot edits could be excluded from the activities which mark a post as active, not to bring an old post with only spelling edits to the top of the page. Human-edited posts are always bumped up, irrespective of the nature of the edit.

Comment: We have [Peter Mortensen](https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/24885?page=1&filter=revisions) ...

Comment: thanks @rene, how can we add items to the list of words Peter is working on?

Comment: This should really be handled client-side. Eye halve a spelling checquer, and all that.

Comment: @toolic; not exactly. What I would like is a bot which is looking at a list which is accessible (e.g. as a normal post) and any words which are added to that list has to undergo the same review process as any other edits, but instead of creating 100 of edits, one does a single edit, a single review.

Comment: @CodyGray; took me a second to read your message; I am not proposing a "42" machine which solves everything, one at a time!

Comment: What about where questions are about writing a spellchecker? Or calculating levenshtein distance?

Comment: @U3.1415926 Peter's project is documented [here](http://pmortensen.eu/) and there's a GitHub repo, the list floats around somewhere there, probably.

Answer (score 8):

This idea has good intent, and on its face would be helpful.

It breaks down in the details though.

Edits bump posts onto the active list, and as a result it is *highly* suggested that edits be substantial, and address posts *as a whole*. If you are going to edit a post to remoove a simple spelling error, then the rest of the post also needs to be examined - for grammar errors or (for other weird things that people do. For example, code formatting, removing signatures or signoffs, removing that section about how the dog inspired the question, etc.

Thus, unless the bot is also trained in all the rest of that stuff, it is not really going to work.

Thanks for reeding, feel free to edit this pos into shap!

-Traivs

Comment: This post should be locked as is! :)

Comment: This is one of my favourite answers of yours.

Comment: And as usual unless these edits excluded from "put question to reopen queue" this will totally kill any chances for questions to be re-opened...

Comment: Good point! The counter solution would be not to count bot edits as activity and therefore bot edited posts will not get the bump human edited posts get. I will add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nah.  It would defeat the whole point of the platform being collaboratively editable.

Comment: Wikipedia is collaboratively editable; the bot will not prevent me to edit.

Comment: @U3.1415926:  This ain't Wikipedia, and this is more a philosophical stance more than anything else.  Most of the entry-level edits people make are to typos.  In fact, there aren't many other edits that could be made *besides* typos (save for the occasional code reformatting).  Adding a bot to do that would really make me question why we should bother editing anything at all.

Comment: The question highlighted by @toolic has good statistics of the number of typos, I think the magnitude of the number of typoes, edits, and reviews calls for a bot.

Comment: @U3.1415926:  ...or more people who want to edit... and while the latter is notoriously difficult to actually motivate, it'd do a ton better than just writing something automated to do that for us IMO.  Humans do a better job with context than bots.

Comment: I think I understand your point @Makoto, but I still don't see why one should exclude the other?

Comment: Perhaps the timeframe of 6-8 years (or perhaps decades) on [Community rejected edits displayed as “rejected” is misleading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290903/community-rejected-edits-displayed-as-rejected-is-misleading) hasn't helped getting more editors. At least a bot will not care.