# Mass-edit the typo "depencies"?

Tags: discussion, edits, api

If you [search for "depencies" on stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=depencies%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com), you'll find thousands of posts with typos in the title. Ditto ["depency."](https://www.google.com/search?q=depency%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com) I started manually editing a few pages to fix the typos, but I don't want to manually make 10,000 edits...

Generally, we agree that fixing typos in the title is a good thing: 
[Guidance on fixing posts with typos in the title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315861/guidance-on-fixing-posts-with-typos-in-the-title)

Is it easy to make a mass edit (update the Stack Overflow database, or script the APIs) to fix all occurrences of `[dD]epenc(y|ies)`?

Comment: Will fixing that typo in all those posts be the only fix needed for those questions? Seems like a waste of time to make a script to fix that one typo when it will likely leave other fixes that need to be done to those posts.

Comment: Not to mention bumping all those posts to the home page. It would really make a mess of the post sort

Comment: Editing posts to improve is fine by me, the problem however is that now posts are being bumped to the front page because of a **single character change**. A feature request for some kind of non-bumping edit (like communities http to https edits) would be in order for cases like these I'd say.

Comment: @adriaan - That's a good idea for existing fodder. One downside is, it is reactive rather than proactive. I think a complete remediation would stop the error before it gets posted so someone does not have to come behind and fix it.

Comment: Re *"...manually make 10,000 edits"*: Someone actually [did that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419699/someone-replaced-unity3dmirror-with-unity3dunity3d-mirror#comment921670_419699) in just four days (changing HTTP links to HTTPS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it easy to make a mass edit...

It doesn't matter how easy or hard it is, we still shouldn't do it. Editing shouldn't be automated like this. A script that mass-edits one typo on thousands of posts will not find all of the other issues with those posts that a human editor (most often) will.

Also, many of those "thousands" of edits are duplicates in Google's search results, or are hits where the typo is in the body of a question or in an answer. If you wanted to get rid of this (still, oddly common) typo in *titles*, you'd only have to edit ~115 posts.

- [Posts containing 'title:depencies'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Adepencies): 55 results
- [Posts containing 'title:depency'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Adepency): 60 results

Comment: It is 2018 and automation should be used to fix problems. It is idiotic to suggest a human should spend time doing it manually when a computer can easily do it. Stack Overflow - the cobbler with no shoes.... No wonder this site has so many festering problems...

Comment: @jww A computer can't easily do it *right*. It's idiotic to suggest that it can.

Comment: Furthermore, I think it also skirts the [Stack Exchange API rules](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write), at least a little bit.