# Someone replaced [unity3d][mirror] with [unity3d][unity3d-mirror]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

In the 10k tools, I found a new tag, [unity3d-mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-mirror), with 120 questions.

When looking at these questions, it seems like some user took all questions tagged with both [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror) and replaced [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror) with [unity3d-mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-mirror).

This change affects 120 questions and was made by a single user in a timespan of around 1 h 17 min.

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409152/taking-a-look-in-the-mirror) was about disambiguating [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror) some time ago without any results.

The [tag wiki of [mirror]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mirror/info) states it being about Unity.

It may be related to [the merge of [unet] and [unity3d-unet]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419629/10871900) which was completed on the same day. The user probably thought they could do something similar to [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror).

Is this OK? Did I overlook an MSE discussion post? I want to make sure that people know about this/it is "documented on Meta".

If we keep this change, we should probably also change the tag wiki of [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror).

Comment: "*The tag wiki of [mirror] states it being about Unity.*" and it's used in a lot of non-Unity questions. Which is to be expected because "mirror" is a widely used term and not at all exclusive to Unity. "*This post was about disambiguating mirror some time ago without any results.*" do note that the post was create *before the tag wiki was edited to say it's about Unity*. So, before somebody took it upon themselves to disambiguate the tag, somebody else took it upon themselves to provide tag guidance to a tag which was already ambiguous. Which was wrong.

Comment: Since that bulk-editing, the [mirror]-tag only consists of non-[unity3d] questions.

Comment: Yes, and as you said 55 questions were retagged as [unity3d-mirror]. Which left almost 10 times as much tagged [mirror]. At the time of this comment, there are 548 questions tagged [mirror]. Which suggests to me that the tag wiki was never correct since there is a 10:1 ratio of incorrect to correct usage.

Comment: My fault, the change affected all _120_ questions with both tags (instead of 55). My settings just filtered many of them out. (I edited my post)

Comment: OK, so there was 120 questions tagged [mirror] "correctly" (according to the tag wiki) vs 550 which were tagged incorrectly. That's still *predominantly* "wrongly" tagged questions. Which still suggests to me that the tag wiki was wrong. The ratio is (almost) 4.5:1 in favour of "wrong" questions. Or, put in another way 82% of them were wrong. Therefore 18% were "correct" and retagged. I'd say defining a tag wiki that covers about 1/5th of the questions of that tag was wrong far before somebody tried to correct this.

Comment: I agree with that. Should we keep this change and change the tag wiki as well? What should we do with the other [mirror] questions? They are not really about the same thing although mirroring something seems dominant there. But I guess that's in the scope of [Taking a look in the \[mirror\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409152)

Comment: I'd say that all usages are wrong. Because the tag is not specific enough. Changing the tag wiki was already wrong *and approving the edits* was also wrong. It's a mess all around. Somebody took it upon themselves to clean this whole thing up at least a bit.

Comment: Also, I now see there is a pending edit to the tag description to say it's not about the Unity Networking API. Which is honestly not much better as it defines it too broadly.

Comment: Even if all questions tagged with mirror were about unity, I wouldn't use mirror as a tag.

Comment: "*If we keep this change, we should probably also change the tag wiki of [tag:mirror].*" yes, please. There are already many [*-mirror] tags, possibly some of the questions actually already have their related 'mirror' tag already.

Comment: Re *"made by a single user in a timespan of around 1 h 17 min"*: That is nothing compared to changing links from HTTP to HTTPS  [in nearly 10,000 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=quarter) in a span of about 4 days ([2022-07-13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=2) through [2022-07-17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=533)). It is about the same rate, but the volume is about 75 times higher.

Comment: This is probably a good reason to take [Taking a look in the \[mirror\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409152) back up again

Comment: The user in question _did_ attempt to update the tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt for both tags, but being under 20k had to await approval. I have just updated the tag wikis and excerpts with the pending changes suggested by the user (with some minor adjustments).

Comment: My question was more about whether this was agreed upon/making sure it is documented.

Comment: I'm the one who did it. tags have meaning in themselves, regardless of what someone once *had the gall* to edit the tag wiki to say. "mirror" is too broad, and clearly _not only_ for Unity3D questions. this site (all of stackexchange) frustrates me with its lack of tools for proper housekeeping, and the seeming requirement to debate obvious actions because they go against unreasonable customs. there is a lot more housekeeping I regard as necessary (e.g., [tag:matchtemplate] vs [tag:template-matching]) but I'm actually afraid to even _ask_ because the outcome might be inaction.

Comment: note: I did not simply replace all unity3d+mirror tagging with unity3d-mirror. some unity3d+mirror questions actually aren't about networking but about mirroring (something visible). there is no way to do this other than by reviewing manually.

Comment: Related: [Tag removals must be discussed and documented on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm aware Meta suggestions aren't always heard, but what if there was a checkbox for **"This is a minor edit"** - like on Wikipedia - which would prevent the edited question/answer from displacing new ones on the front page? This would have allowed that person to knuckle down and do the work on http -> https conversions without worrying about pushing new questions off the top of the site.

Comment: @AJM: That is ***definitely*** a reasonable idea. But it has consistently been rejected by the meta crowd over the years. A starting point: *[Mark edit as "minor" to prevent bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64837/mark-edit-as-minor-to-prevent-bumping)* and [its linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/64837?sort=votes).