# How do I make better code syntax correction edits?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/pep8-80-characters-big-strings/), I discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/pep8-80-characters-big-strings/26478928#26478928) which, while it was a valid approach, left critical quotation marks out, which would have caused a syntax error. However, it was just the two quotation marks that needed to fixed, so I didn't reach the 6 character boundary. Unwilling to leave broken code that could be fixed so easily, I read over this question and its answers:

["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

I didn't get any idea of consensus as to how this should be done, but some suggested leaving a comment, so I added an "Edit:" explanation clause and submitted:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11078032

I'm a little frustrated at the fact that it was rejected, but even more so at the reasons the reviewers left. I really don't understand how my edit deviated from the original intent of the answer. Did I make an invalid edit?

**How should I respond to edit reviews like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code edits are almost automatically rejected. You should comment instead and if no action done on the comment in some time (days) - make an edit and add explanation as edit comment to slightly increase chance of acceptance.

In this particular case

- code change looks like it does not match what author suggested. Making incorrect answer correct is not valid edit.
- you've also added completely unrelated text (your edit reason) inline to the post and there is no other way to avoid that than rejecting.

Better approach in this particular case would be to create new answer or link to alternative answer that demonstrate this solution.

Comment: I felt like the answers to that question were largely form answers rather than function, although perhaps that should have tipped me off that that wasn't a question worth editing. I did downvote the question, and thought about reporting it, but I felt like the position of the closing paren added a little to the discussion but another answer would have been overkill.