# Raising rep by flooding the suggested edit queue

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I don't usually wade into the suggested edits queue, but I did so when the orange icon hit 117 today. I noticed a very large number (7 of my 20 reviews) came from a single user who was suggesting [single-word spelling fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12778338) while leaving any other problems with the post untouched.

When I first looked, this user had 322 rep. While I was Rejecting-and-Editing posts, robo-reviewers continued to approve edits. An hour later, the same user has 388 rep, with only four total upvotes across 12 questions and answers.

As has been pointed out on meta before, making this kind of trivial edit without addressing other post issues is always frowned upon, because it bumps a large number of posts needlessly. It is worse when done by an under-2000 rep user, because it wastes a lot of reviewers' time. And in this case, it seems to be primarily for the purpose of gaining rep quickly.

While this is clearly undesirable behavior, I'm not sure what I can do to combat it. Rejecting the review is useless, as it means the edits will be approved 3-1 instead of 3-0. Reject-and-edit is effective, but it is time consuming and even then it still bumps the post to the top of the front page - one of the outcomes we'd like to avoid.

Ultimately, one person can only review so many edits in a day. It seems like a moderator flag might be appropriate, but I don't think I can raise one on a suggested edit. Does Stack Overflow have an official way to handle this situation? If not, shouldn't we get one?

Comment: _"Reject-and-edit is effective, but time consuming."_ But probbaly the right action to take. Well, that's the drawback with working on queues, it consumes time doing it correctly.

Comment: The problem is a half dozen rejections can't stem the tide when a user can post 50 suggested edits in that time and get 30+ of them approved.

Comment: Well, I have to agree with @Glorfindel's answer at least.

Comment: I have handled 20 suggested edits by rejecting most of them and [mentioned](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31295293#31295293) the edits in the SOCVR room.

Comment: @Glorfindel do you run a script that automatically changes "period-space-space" to "period-space" when you edit a post?  Or are you just that hardcore?  ;-)

Comment: @RyanBemrose that would be hardcore ...

Comment: Often, the most effective way is to find an edit that was approved and post a nice comment with constructive guidance for the user. Moderator flags and Meta posts can be reserved for cases where the comment is ignored. (Editors of a post can be `@`-pinged.)

Comment: I'm really starting to warm up to the idea of rate-limiting reputation gain from suggested edits. Capping at 20 points a day or something like that might remove some of the incentive for shotgunning edits like this.

Comment: @BradLarson - Ooh, that is a good idea!

Comment: @RyanBemrose: I think the problem is not stemming the tide. Reviews don't automatically get approved after all. The problem is with reviewers who *approve* such reviews.

Comment: One might argue that a misspelling of a keyword in the title is not minor at all, even it is just one word. Improving this area could make a significant impact on the site, particularly when you consider how poor the SO search functionality performs. Google might be smart enough to get "android" from "andoid", but SO is not... And there are a ton of them - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=andoid.

Comment: @BradLarson Rate limiting would be a good idea, because right now it is super easy to "power up" new accounts by botting spelling fixes. It would be easy to grief the site, or a particular tag, by doing this 2-3 times, and just downvoting every new question, for example.

Comment: I noticed this behaviour too and rejected a few, skipped some and, fixed some (maybe one or two before realizing it would be time-consuming) - glad this question was asked and I am also in agreement with @Glorfindel 's approach - might take that next time around

Comment: @BradLarson: _"rate-limiting reputation gain from suggested edits"_ -- isn't it already rate-limited in a way, given that there's a maximum number of edits per day a person can perform? Assuming the reputation granted per edit is fundamentally the right value, it seems to me that putting additional rate-limitations on would be counter-productive, as it would unnecessarily punish users hitting the limit even though they are making good, useful edits. If something about the design will change, I'd focus more on tying reputation gain to significance of change, or even introduce voting on edits.

Comment: _"it seems to be primarily for the purpose of gaining rep quickly"_ -- while I agree with the overall concern about the high rate of edits from the single user, I would suggest not being so quick to judge motive. It's entirely possible that this user feels they are simply contributing what they can. After all, it is nice to have good spelling in titles and posts, both for readability and searchability. They may just not realize that the large volume of minor edits without fixing other issues in the posts is frowned upon.

Comment: Amusing... Never thought of this hacky way to increase rep... http://stackoverflow.com/users/4134562/avi-k?tab=reputation

Comment: I am getting a feeling that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascipt) is the mechanism that person used to make these edits. We can verify that by posting a question where `javascipt` is a valid spelling. e.g. _"how to detect minor typing mistakes in vim, like javascipt"_ If that person corrects the spelling, then it is a flooding mechanism... ;-)

Comment: @BradLarson can we do like this that reviewer can only do 20 edit, so editor will edit 15 to 20 edit per day and they will get rep but after 20 if they are editing, they can but won't get any rep like no rep after 2000. Stopping them after 20 will be bad as then there will be no much edited question and SO will full of bad managed questions.

Comment: Related: [Rate-limit suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits) on MSE.

Comment: I have the same question but for users who only make a single retag and thats it...

Comment: @BradWerth  the programming language usually doesn't need to be in the title to begin with. That's the real problem here

Comment: It has [never ever made any sense that per-diem reviews are limited while suggestions are not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits#comment304768_116509).

Comment: -1 rep when an edit rejected. Anyone?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra It's been proposed before, and IIRC it was declined. The rep farmers won't be stopped by the occcasional -1 when the majority of their sloppy edits get approved. But the serious editor who gets rejected wrongly (it _does_ happen) will feel discouraged.

Comment: why not making an additional queue for small typo edits with small impact. i hate typos in questions and answers, because it looks like poor qualitiy

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, if <s>the review system worked as designed</s> at least *some* of the reviewers would be paying attention, this editor would be blocked from editing rather quickly. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337), that would already happen if more than 25% of his edits would be rejected.

I would raise a custom flag on a post (the one you linked would be a good example, except that you tidied it up yourself), explain the situation (an editor going on an edit-spree and some reviewers who are not paying attention) and let the mods decide who they want to punish.

Yes, [minor edits are good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site), but a small spelling correction in a two-year-old question is just a waste of reviewers' time. And it also needlessly bumps the question to the homepage.

Comment: Notice that javascript is spelled as JavaScript which wasn't in any of the edits I rejected. So it wasn't even a correction ...

Comment: I see no problem with a minor edit, when a) it's the only thing wrong with the post, and b) it's one-off.  A low-rep user flooding minor edits is not okay IMO, even if each one individually is righteous.

Comment: I think edit box already has limitation for editing data, if your edit is passing limitation and is valid, then it should be accepted independent from age of question.

Comment: A bigger problem with a small spelling correction in a two-year-old question is that it launches the question back onto my homepage (assuming it's in one of my favorite tags). I then click on the question, only to discover that it already has an answer and wasn't ever in need of my attention. To be sure, this isn't the fault of the reviewer, it's just a design flaw of the site. But still, making hundreds of these edits a day is a serious problem, considering that it effectively launches a DoS attack on the home pages of *all* users, not just the reviewers.

Comment: +1 for the minor edits are good link.

Comment: How many rejections (via rejects or via reject-and-edits) in a row does it take for a user to get banned, I wonder

Comment: @CodyGray I agree; I think title-only edits shouldn't bump the question to the front page.

Comment: @TylerH [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337).

Comment: @Glorfindel cheers

Comment: @CodyGray today I stumbled upon a [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers/26496#26496) explaining why edits bump a question.

Comment: Indeed, such was the logic years ago when the site was first designed. But we now have much better tools for auditing user actions and detecting/stopping abuse. Also, in the early days with Jeff's design, people like himself and other trusted community managers could do mass retags *without* bumping posts. That made it unnecessary for the average community member to do this. Problem is, the community team has stopped doing that, preferring to leave all retags and other maintenance to the community. Which is fine, scaling and self-sufficiency and all that, but the tooling must keep up.

Answer (score 38):

I've contacted the user in question and asked them to stop making huge numbers of minor edits. Let me know if they continue.

I'll let the edits that are already in the queue be reviewed naturally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would one know when one was contacted by a mod? Is there an inbox on StackExchange or individual sites, or would a user just get an e-mail?

Comment: @Tas All of the above. You'd know.

Comment: @Undo , and how?

Comment: You can use chat I think.

Comment: @Tas  user will get email and also a message in message box as every user has message box. I too get message from mod but it will only opt out when you will get message.

Comment: @Undo please check this  user too. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4281815/yaz?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1

Comment: He is only editing non stop while even he is not reading the question or content. I have rejected so many wrong edits of him but seems its like flood.. please check.

Comment: @Leothelion Don't have time to figure that out right now, mind throwing a flag on one of their posts

Comment: @Undo if you don't mind i have question. This [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4281815/yaz?tab=reputation) got 236 rep in one day by only editing(worst) and i flagged but nothing happens.. isn't it wrong? that user is still editing like hell..check his all actions.

Comment: @Leothelion Did the flag get declined?  If not, just wait -- the mods haven't handled that flag yet.  They get a *lot* of flags, so it often takes a few days before anything happens.

Comment: @NobodyNada how can i see that flag as that is not coming in my flags. So not sure what happened to those flags.

Comment: Wow..seriously i think this is the one of most dangerous issue in SO. Again a new [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3013253/belkebir?tab=reputation) who din solve anything but got 600 rep by editing the questions with worst editing. MODS please do something or else there will be a lot fake id with 500 to 600 rep and will increase rep of main id by uv their answer. I have flagged but can't see what happened to them but getting users like this always. Almost my 20 reviews is wasting on them.

Comment: @Leothelion What do you mean by "that is not coming in my flags?"  Is it not in [your flags](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3373905)?  If not, then the system doesn't think you even flagged the post -- try flagging again.

Answer (score 28):

bluefeet brought this up on a call earlier today, and we got to talking about the various problems we're still facing with suggested edits:

- Scores of tiny edits take time away from reviewers and fill the queue
- From a reputation-earning perspective, making comprehensive edits is counter-productive; given an hour of time to spare, 60 fast, simple edits earns you more than 30 slow, extensive edits.
- From a learning perspective, making a dozen good-faith edits and then getting banned after they're reviewed is pretty harsh; ideally, [they'd be educated on their first bad edit when going to make the second one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).
- From a community-management perspective, having editing perceived as a liability hurts good editors.

So we had this idea... What if you *couldn't* suggest an edit if your last suggested-edit was still waiting for review? Or if your last edit was rejected in the past, say, 5 minutes?

Similar ideas have been suggested before, by [Chris Frederick in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116636/limit-the-number-of-suggested-edits-that-a-user-can-make-in-a-day) and [Martijn Pieters / psubsee2003 in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits). So let's take a look at what effects such a rate-limit might have...

[This query counts the number of edits that would've been blocked (or delayed)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503652/how-many-edits-and-editors-wouldve-been-blocked-if-we-rate-limited-pending-sug?LookbackDays=365&MaxPendingEdits=4) for each affected editor *if* we just blocked edits when more than *n* were currently pending in the queue. You can play with the various parameters there, and drill down into each editor's edits to see which ones would've been affected. You can also fix bugs in my query if so inclined... But if nothing else, eyeball the edits to see the effects this would have.

I'm seeing a lot of spelling corrections and code formatting that'd be delayed, particularly spelling corrections of the sort you lament here. **A couple of weeks later** [this is implemented as a straight limit on the number of in-flight edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202).

Comment: I was just thinking of that limitation when I finished reading your bullet points. I like the idea. Maybe not limit the users to *one*, though... two or three?

Comment: is this throttling supposed to be only at SO or network wide?

Comment: One way I could see stopping these correction edits from being slowed down is if the edit is found naturally(We open the pending edit from the answer or question) then 1 approver is all that is needed as we went there to do the edit already.  This may help speed up the process but also allow users to be limited so they cannot spam a bunch of bad edits.

Comment: I see higher rep users make these changes all the time, so I've been known to do so as well because I was under the impression that's what we wanted. Is it bad in both cases, cause even if a high rep user makes the change it's going to bump the post to the front page? Or is it only bad in the case of having <2k rep and you're wasting reviewers time? Perhaps there should be a privilege unlocked if you have a high percentage of accepted reviews with a big enough number to allow automatic edits?

Comment: Been playing with the query. I see a lot of users whose editing work needed some guidance. I've often rejected things with a custom reason, hoping their next edit would be something I could Approve. Implementing this form of throttling would help a lot.