# Allow edit reviewers to vote for too minor while still accepting the edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

### Advantage:

Work has been done (someone edited lttile things) and it's good, however, SO doesn't encourage too minor edits, since they bloat the review queue.

If there would be a button in the review queue that lets the edit pass, however not give the user any rep, and set the review state to accepted - too minor.

This encourages little edits, however, lets them pass if they are in the queue anyways.

This would, over time, allow older posts to slowly improve in grammar/style without flooding the queue.

I doubt that this will encourage the too minor edits, however, it allows to fix little errors that would've simply been rejected nowdays (as too minor, e.g. grammar in only few parts or fixing just single mistakes instead of bigger problems).

What do you think?

Comment: Idea from this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site?lq=1 and one comment underneath it