# Increase suggested edit approval votes to three if there is a disapproval vote

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-audits

I've noticed in the course of my reviews, that a lot of trivial edits are making it through the approve queue because of the new "only 2 votes required" rule that was put into place.

I'd like to request a new feature:

> If a suggested edit has 1 reject vote on it, require at least 3 approval votes total to approve.

This will allow bots [like editmonitor](https://github.com/ProgramFOX/SO-EditMonitor) that were once helpful at detecting approvals with 2 reject votes to continue to alert us about potentially bad edits getting approved, as well as locate/educate users with consistent trivial/bad edits.

Comment: I've actually been surprised at how well the change to two reviewers has gone. I expected significantly more problems than we've seen with that. This sounds like a reasonable proposal to deal with some problematic cases.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Implement a "tennis rule" for suggested edit approval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219916/implement-a-tennis-rule-for-approving-suggested-edits)

Comment: Tennis rule has it's downsides though: Edits can be placed into a never ending match of reject/approve for the middleground edits.

Comment: @FrankerZ Infinite back-and-forth is easy to fix by just having an upper limit.

Comment: "Spacing Changes" -- Wait, it's not recommended suggest edits to fix code indentation? [Even when it looks like it's just a bad copy/paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26773692/revisions) Are you guys going to update [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/321006) with that information?

Comment: @jrh If the spacing changes effect a code block of a substantial amount that can improve readability significantly, I'm inclined to accept those. Simply changing/altering a small block of code to reduce one tab is a waste of an edit.

Comment: This could introduce a dependency on the order of reviews, and the "quality" of the initial two reviewers.  An edit that would get a (good, good, bad) review (with a theoretically 3rd reviewer) would be approved, while if the reviewers looked at it in a different order (good, bad, good) it would still be in limbo.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm There's already a dependency on the order of reviews - (approve, approve, decline, decline) gets approved, (decline, decline, approve, approve) gets declined. There will be one for any reasonably-sized sample. At least this way we gather more data if the data we have doesn't clearly point in any direction.

Comment: @jrh FWIW, I'd absolutely approve the edit you've linked to. Broken indentation is ugly, that edit fixes the ugliness, and it's easily possible for even the slowest, most hesitant reviewer to see that the edit is an improvement in under 20 seconds (a quick reviewer might need less than 2); it's not like edits of that kind are going to waste reviewer time.

Comment: Like Mark I don't think I've ever rejected an indent/code line wrap fix only edit.  If other fixes are needed, I'll add them too prior to approval.  I may leave an @ message for the editor suggesting that they should fix other minor problems (eg spelling/punctuation) as well; but only for people who appear to either be doing mass edits or whose profile implies being a native English speaker.

Comment: @MarkAmery good to know. Figured I'd make sure just to be safe. The space between "too minor" and "deviates too far" seems to be small if not nonexistent these days. It kind of wore me out over time and I don't really do suggested edits anymore as a result; it just seemed kind of futile after a while when things that [seem to follow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16452729) [all applicable guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15235969) get one or two reject votes with no consistency as to why.

Comment: @jrh As far as I'm concerned, edits shouldn't ever be being rejected for being minor; we argued about this at length as a community years ago, and the pro-minor-edits camp [won the popular vote spectacularly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/1709587). Unfortunately, there's nothing to keep those who disagree from reviewing according to their own views. I agree that the situation sucks for sub-2k editors; no suggested edit is *ever* safe, because some reviewers' notion of "too radical" overlaps with *other* reviewers' notion of "too minor".

Comment: @MarkAmery Yeah, I'm familiar with the "too minor" battle, IMO the meta campaign did not work. Maybe hand picked audits designed to ban reviewers who stretch "no improvement whatsoever" to mean "too minor" will make a difference at this point, but if SO as a community supports the idea that "flawed posts need to stay that way forever because it takes reviewer effort to improve them", that's a bigger problem, and I don't know what the answer is to that; I don't understand that point of view myself, it contradicts the "encyclopedic" goals of this site, in my opinion.

Comment: @jrh targeted audits don't work because you can always click edit and approve or edit and reject instead.

Comment: @TylerH would it help if hypothetically both "Reject and edit" and "Reject" caused an audit failure in that case?

Comment: @FrankerZ The purpose of the rule in tennis is to avoid matches being decided on a fluke. Same principle applies here. You don't want this decision to be based on a mere accident of timing. There should certainly be a majority of at least two approvers or disapprovers.