# Should edit rejection reasons be updated to encourage rejecting minor/trivial edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I think it is an ongoing problem that too many trivial edits which don't fully address the issues in a post are proposed. Related to this is that many of these trivial edits are accepted by reviewers.

Currently, the edit rejection reasons don't make it obvious that edits which don't substantially improve a post should be rejected:

> - ##### Reject
>
> This edit fails to improve the post.

[image]

Suggests that only edits which entirely fail to improve the post should be rejected.

Similarly, on the next level:

> ##### No Improvement
>
> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

[image]

The only relevant radio button implies that it should be clicked only if the edit fails to improve the quality of the post in any way, not only if it fails to *substantially* improve the quality of the post.

Should we have a stricter reason for rejecting such as 'This edit fails to substantially improve the post', to make it more obvious that trivial edits should be rejected?

Comment: If the edit is trivial (fixes a single typographical error for example), but doesn't address the rest of the problems (noise, formatting, other errors), then reject it as "No Improvement", as it *has* failed to improve the post. A single correction to what should be many isn't an improvement as the post is still in a poor condition. Much like putting a piece of paper of a hole in the wall isn't an "improvement" if there are still 5 other holes in that same wall.

Comment: @Larnu I can’t say I agree. Even a trivial edit improves the post, just not very much. Either way, I think it needs to be much more clear, since I suspect that many new reviewers wouldn’t see it in the same way as you have described.

Comment: The problem with this is that, actually, our guidance and the company's understanding differs quite significantly on that matter. The "no improvement" rejection reason used to be different to include the wording for rejecting edits that are not substantial enough and was explicitly changed to this very vague wording.

Comment: I don't see how fixing a single problem in the post improves it, when the rest of an unreadable mess, @user438383 .

Comment: The prompt when editting also backs this up. *"because community members review edits, please try to make the post **substantially better** than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks."* emphasis mine. A single typographical fix isn't *substantially better*.

Comment: @Larnu I think user438383 and you are on the same side on that matter - what the above comment (at least in how I read it) is saying is that it does, *technically*, improve *something* about the post, just not in a manner that is a good way of spending reviewer time on or use up a valuable queue slot in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps, then, the rejection reason instead needs to read "... does not *substantially* improve..."

Comment: would actually love to see it say that, @Larnu.

Comment: Though, *if* a change to the wording is wanted, that should be a separate [[meta-tag:feature-request]].

Comment: I do wonder if there should be some kind of "better" logic for allowing submissions as well though, @OlegValteriswithUkraine . For example, a suggested edit that just changes the tags shouldn't be accepted; either OP needs to fix them or the edit should be doing *more* that just adding/removing tags. There's a reason you don't get the "edit tags" feature until you get the "Edits are applied immediately" privilege. Though I suspect users will start making pointless changes to the content of the post to get around the restriction because *derp*.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, something is definitely needed. I dunno, maybe split the queue into substantial edits and non-substantial? Leave the first capped and allow the latter to grow as it pleases - even if those edits will be sitting in the queue for months, it would be not an issue to us as they are unsubstantial in the first place. Plus we would finally be able to make suggested edits for tag wikis to be reviewed in less than a month. I am not sure it's a good idea but that's something. I also like the idea of preventing tag-only suggested edits from submission (although I share your concern too).

Comment: Apart from that then a non-substantial edit would block anyone from performing a substantial edit on the post, @OlegValteriswithUkraine . Which, if those takes months to get through, would be a real pain in the...

Comment: Yeah, that's the biggest issue that can arise from it, @Larnu. I'd imagine it to be solved by how Git treats asynchronously made changes: such a pending edit should not block other edits from being made to the post (apart from other insubstantial edits probably), and upon review launch a check whether the edit can be cleanly applied. If it can, the edit can be approved, if it can't the reviewer has to resolve a merge conflict (or the author of the edit, I am not sure about that) before approving.

Comment: We used to have this. It was removed because we decided that minor edits are OK. This is a knowledge base; any improvements are welcome.

Comment: @CodyGray really? That's not the impression I have got from reading meta.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on Meta. See the linked duplicates, perhaps, for more relevant reading? (Now, the caveat is, if the post is still literally an unreadable mess after the edit, then that's not an edit that is "too minor"; that's one that is completely pointless and ineffective. It should be rejected for no improvement whatsoever. But that's very different from edits that are merely polishing because there's almost nothing left to improve. Also, one reason why Meta previously was concerned about "too minor" edits was [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340), but that's fixed.)

Comment: If that *is* the case, @CodyGray , then things that recommend that users make substantial edits should be removed. There are clearly conflicts here. Does this also now mean that an edit that leaves 1 typographical error, but leaves others and noise in situ is "ok"...?

Comment: What "things" are you talking about, @Larnu? Also (and this is something I see misunderstood all the time, and it really frustrates me)…there is a huge difference between ***guidance*** (you should make your edits substantial; you should put in effort to solve the problem yourself) and ***rejection reasons***. Anyway, yes, an edit that e.g. removes greeting/salutation/signature from a post *without* fixing a typo is worthwhile and should probably be approved (or improved!). Similarly, a post that formats code, taking a post from unreadable to readable, without fixing anything else is a net +.

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough, I've learnt something new then and will change my reviewing style. Sometimes it's hard to parse what should/shouldn't be done from reading meta, I agree....

Comment: Yeah, you aren't supposed to have to read Meta. You're supposed to look at the rejection (or close) reasons presented to you, and see if the thing you're looking at can be rejected/closed for any of those reasons. If not (i.e., if none of the reasons apply), then you don't reject it or close it. People inventing custom rejection/close reasons because of something they have a foggy memory of reading somewhere once on Meta is a significant anti-pattern. Meta is for proposing and discussing changes. To that extent, your proposal here is just fine & proper, but happens to be a duplicate.

Comment: The aforementioned banner, when editing, probably could be referred to as guidance, @CodyGray (though if small edits are "ok" I would suggest it should go), however [Edit Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) states *"**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."* (Emphasis source). This reads less as guidance and more as a *rule*, due to the emphasis used.

Comment: "Discouraged" is literally the hallmark of a phrase that attempts to provide guidance, not a rule. If it were a rule, it would say "forbidden" or "not allowed" or something definite. And, like I said: look at the rejection reasons. If you think that the edit is truly making no improvement whatsoever to the post, well, I'm pretty sure there's a rejection reason for that. But that's somewhat different from "this is a very minor improvement".

Comment: And emphasis is literally the hallmark of "do not do this", @CodyGray .

Comment: Eh, no. Emphasis means "pay attention to this; this is important guidance for editors". Note that that page is not even attempting to provide guidance to reviewers; it's targeted at editors.

Comment: *"If you think that the edit is truly making no improvement whatsoever to the post"* Then my opinion of "This edit address one typographical error of many, and isn't an improvement" will be what I continue to apply.

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand how you square the circle from "this fixes a typographical error" to "*no improvement whatsoever*". (Examples of cases where "no improvement whatsoever" might apply are "this fixes a typographical error but introduces another one", or "this fixes a typographical error but breaks the formatting", or "this does nothing but change from British to American English spellings".)

Comment: It's difficult for me to see how you see that a single typographical error fix is an improvement when there's still 10's of typos, bad grammar and noise... If you want to go down that route, you might as well submit 10 edits for 10 typographical errors and farm 20 rep.

Comment: If you fix a bug in code, but there are still other bugs, does that bug fix not improve the code? Seriously, this is obvious stuff, so I'm going to assume that you're intentionally choosing to interpret the reason in a way that is consistent with that you *wish* it said, rather than what it actually *does* say.

Comment: If I asked someone to fix some buggy code and then sent it "fixed" with 1/10 bug fixes in it, I would reject that, yes.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't the guidance for editors, it's the guidance for reviewers, @CodyGray . If we, as reviewers, can't apply the guidance for editors, then what guidance should we follow?

Comment: *No one asked anyone to fix anything!* Someone submitted a PR to your repository that fixed only one bug out of many. You're going to reject that PR because they didn't fix all of the problems? This is stupid. You cannot honestly believe this.

Comment: I can only agree to disagree with you here, @CodyGray .

Comment: I agree with you in principle, codygray, but in practice the guidance for the longest time has been if the suggested edit only does one minor fix when there's a lot of other things to fix, the way forward is to reject it, with or without edit.

Comment: Granted, there exists a lot of reviewer guidance that was written when we had a "too minor" rejection reason. We do not have a "too minor" rejection reason anymore. It's not hard to figure out what that means. When the "too minor" rejection reason was first introduced, there was no "Improve" button. There is now an "Improve" button. Again, I feel like people who manage to write code that works can figure out how to make sense out of this. But maybe my standards are too high. I continually find it frustrating that people invent their own rules and arbitrary standards.

Comment: And we, as reviewers, find it frustrating that someone has spent less than a second making a change to a post and us, as a reviewer, have to (by your standards) spend a couple minutes fixing the rest, and yet we, as the reviewer, get nothing bur they get 2 reputation. Now, don't get me wrong, I don't care about my reputation, but rewarding someone for no effort, and expecting reviewers to put it in is a poor stance, @CodyGray .

Comment: No one said you have to fix the rest, @Larnu. As with close reasons, you're running aground here because you're worried about how much effort someone puts in. Stop worrying about how much effort other people put in.

Comment: Why would I *not* fix the rest, @CodyGray ? Why would I, as a reviewer, not improve the post when it's a mess?

Comment: You can choose to fix it if you like, but that has nothing to do with anything being discussed here. You cannot use "I don't want to spend my time fixing the rest of the things" as a rejection reason. That's not the editor's fault. That's just your choice to do or not to do something.

Comment: I disagree that it's not the editors fault that they didn't address the rest of the problems; I have no idea how you can think any other way. I suppose were back to I can only agree to disagree with you. Perhaps I'll raise my own post address my concerns/confusion about your responses here at a later point. For now, I'll avoid the edit review queue again (just after I'd finally recently decided to visit it again).

Comment: @CodyGray that's strange to hear from you, actually. The community guidance was and, IIRC, still is that edits that do not fix other problems with the post are bad edits (meaning they go against the guidelines for making good edits) which is certainly grounds for rejection. Even with the current wording, "superfluous" supports the idea of such edits (like "fixing" grammar in an unsalvageable post) being generally a waste of everyone's time. I do understand that the argument for wasting reviewer time should probably be avoided as the content should be assessed by its merits alone, but [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] the content is precisely what's in question for such edits. Granted, there is no need to reject *incomplete* edits just for being, well, incomplete - we are only human, after all. But when an edit misses glaring issues with a given post focusing instead on adding a couple of commas, I'd say such an edit is a textbook "unnecessary" one. P.S. in the [1/2] part, the opening statement should read "hear that" :)

Comment: The irony that the accepted answer on ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) states that one of the reasons that minor edits are ok is because the suggested edit queue is always empty is somewhat laughable now; when the opposite is true and it is rarely not full.

Comment: Very good point, @Larnu, I added a comment there after reading yours. I think we seriously need to rethink the "they don't cause any disruptions so should not be rejected" position.

Comment: I took five more for the team. None were anywhere near to be accepted outright (improvements needed). Two were acceptable (but, e.g., missing jeopardy compliance and not removing the part where Stack Overflow was used as a forum). One was rejected (it  removed syntax highlighting (worked fine in that ***particular*** case), introduced a grammatical error, and changed "I" to "i"(!!!)). One was accepted (with improvements) that only made an image inline, without fixing the spelling mistake that was in plain sight in the image and didn't make the image description, well, more descriptive.

Comment: cont' - One was accepted (with improvements) that only added a link (maybe I shouldn't have), didn't fix the more than five spelling mistakes, and didn't fix the weird syntax highlighting.

Comment: I agree with Larnu (*"...frustrating that someone has spent less than a second making a change to a post and us, as a reviewer, have to ... spend a couple of minutes fixing the rest"*). Better stay away from the edit suggestion queue altogether when less than 20% of the required work has been done for the average edit suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a superpower, like the dupe hammer, to the effect of *"Your edit suggestion is nowhere near comprehensive enough. Please review this checklist and resubmit your improved edit suggestion."* (Yes, *"Reject and edit"* works like one, but it could be considered abuse.) Suspension from submitting to the edit suggestion queue would only require a *very* small number of these edit suggestion hammers.

Comment: (It is a limited sample size, but there seems to be a new trend among the minimum-effort users to submit link-only changes (adding a link or changing an existing link). Perhaps they got too many of their formatting-only changes rejected?)